# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 01/2015 - 07/2018 )

Tags: discussion, re-open, big-list, undeletion

The purpose of this thread is to help focus the attention of the community on posts that may require exceptional handling. This includes requests for reopen and undeletion votes. A request should be posted as an answer below.

Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure). That should be done in a separate linked thread. The goal is to keep this meta thread free of tension, so that everyone feels comfortable posting here. Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community.

To inform readers of the current (and past) states of the targeted post, please prepend tags such as:

> **Reopened, reclosed** or
>
> **Undeleted**

at the start of the answer when a change of status occurs. (This also makes it easier to browse through the list by creating a visual difference for posts that still require action.)

Beware that "short" requests such as "request reopening of " may be automatically converted to comments by the SE software, so you may need to write more (e.g. why you think that the question should be reopened or undeleted).

Notice that the first edit after the question was put on-hold pushes the question into reopen review queue, if the edit was done withing 5 days of closure. So does a reopen vote. It is reasonable to wait until the review is finished before posting here. (If the review has already been finished, it is shown on the [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/how-to-see-questions-time-line) of the question.)

---

(description copied from the [old thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6424/204298))

As has been proposed in chat (and seconded by a couple of users), it seems that it is time to create a *new* thread for reopen and undeletion requests.  The old thread (as of now) has **over** $200$ answers, and it is really hard to scroll through the mass of old and/or possibly outdated answers--voting is a mess, too.  (It's especially problematic for 10k users who can see the deleted posts.)

Comment: There is now a separate meta thread about this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19045/whether-when-and-why-to-have-a-new-reopen-and-undelete-request-thread?lq=1

Comment: Take note that the posts can be [sorted by activity](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio?answertab=active#tab-top) so new and active reopen-requests show at the top.

Comment: 181 answers??? Is this a SE record for the most number of answers?

Comment: @Pritt: There are currently 211 here counting the deleted ones.  The [old thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-10-2012-12-2014) has 230.  Here's one on Stack Overflow with 518 (undeleted): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered

Comment: @PrittBalagopal it has gone up to $213$ now :)

Comment: This is related and needs to be re-opened: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846746/79069, please vote up/reopen! Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

> **Mod-deleted**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68398/statistics-help) has recently been *un*deleted. I have to admit that I'm stunned.

There is nothing good about this Q&A: the question**s** consist a homework dump from a timed online quiz; they have apparently been copy-pasted here without any effort done to even format them correctly (the sentence "Answer both parts for full credit" is especially bad, I half expected to find "Calculators forbidden" in there); there is a multitude of unrelated questions instead of a clear, detailed, focused question; the title is uninformative (something that takes 20s to fix, but no-one seems to care about that); the "answer" does not even address any of the questions and instead consists of a different problem that A.N. devised and then answered.

Is this what math.SE is for? This thread is for Q&As that require exceptional handling, so I'm asking for this question to be *re-deleted*. The Q&A will not help any future visitors, it probably didn't even help the OP.

---

**Arthur Fischer's note.**

> That question was a wreck from the beginning, and probably should have been closed within hours (if not minutes) of its being posted back in 2011. Way too many separate, specific questions to make for a valuable reference going forward. I don't think any amount of effort would be sufficient to polish that turd.
>
> Gerry Myerson's original edit, though well-intentioned, made the question **worse**, IMHO. It did allow for André Nicolas's answer to match the question, but now instead of simply a "truckload" of separate questions, we have an additional "ask your own similar question and answer it".  This takes too broad to another level.
>
> Daniel Fischer, robjohn, Jyrki Lahtonen, Michael Greinecker and myself have discussed this question, and we really couldn't find much redeeming value in it. Were the answer of superlative quality, myself or another mod would have locked the question (undeleted) for "historical significance". At this point the only thing historically significant about the question is the delete-undelete war. We all wanted it to end, and now it has.

Comment: I purged the comment thread. Sorry that I didn't act earlier. The goal should possibly be to prevent these skirmishes from escalating. I appreciate Gerry's effort in editing the question, but it does look like the question was beyond repair.

Answer (score 13):

> **[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1162751/revisions)**

I would like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162751/how-do-i-differentiate-sin1-x) to be undeleted. It was voluntarily removed by the author although a correct answer was given. Given the [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26643/dotman14)'s history on MSE, it seems the user asks questions, gets answers, and then deletes the questions. I do not think this should be permitted, as some user in the future may have the same question as the OP, but a valid answer will not be present due to a senseless deletion.

Comment: It's customary that the bold bit is the current state of the question - as it said "Undeleted" before, users encountering this post might have thought it had already been undeleted and hence not cast undelete votes. I have changed it to "Deleted" so that people will recognize that action is desired.

Comment: @Meelo Ah, thanks for the pointer. Haven't used meta really at all until now. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Meelo actually, if you look at the other requests (on this thread and the previous one), you'll see that the *change* of status is recorded, not the original status. It makes it easier to browse through the list by making a visual difference between requests for which nothing has changed (and thus still require action), and those for which something has changed (usually the issue has been resolved).

Answer (score 10):

> **Reclosed**

Please consider re-closing this question : [Is it to the students' advantage to learn the language of infinitesimals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648838/is-it-to-the-students-advantage-to-learn-the-language-of-infinitesimals)

On the one hand, the question is primarily about pedagogy, which would be a better fit for a different SE site. But, more importantly, the question is essentially a request to engage in a discussion about whether there is an "advantage" to teaching infinitesimals. This is a perfect example of a question that is primarily opinion based, and arguably "subjective and argumentative" as the former close reason said.

This kind of subjective discussion is certainly healthy for the field of mathematics, but it is not what we want on this site. The [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) puts it clearly: *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.*

Comment: IMO this wasn't a question at all but an opportunity for the OP to use the site as a soapbox.

Answer (score 7):

> **Reopened**

Request for reopening: [What would change in mathematics if we knew $\pi+e$ is rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730117/what-would-change-in-mathematics-if-we-knew-pie-is-rational)

It was closed as unclear last March.  I edited it to try to make it clear, and there are comments that (to me) show that the question can be answered reasonably.  I voted to reopen, then it went through review and left with 3 selecting "leave closed."

Answer (score 6):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105074/uncounatability-and-finite-index) was closed as "off topic". It was originally just a statement of a problem, but not the OP has [added some more detail and motivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1105074/revisions). So I believe that it should be reopened.

Answer (score 6):

[REOPENED]

[Linear Transformation on $\mathbb{R}^6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123699/linear-transformation-on-mathbbr6/1123713) was closed for missing context (also by me) because the OP showed no work. This was changed in a comment to my answer. I have copied the relevant comment (of the OP) into the question body to salvage it. Maybe someone TeXifies the image? (Can't be bothered right now)

Comment: It can be a good idea to wait a bit before posting here. Sometimes the reopen review "just works." If not you could still post here.

Comment: @quid Thanks, will do next time.

Comment: It already had a recent review history though @quid so I'm not sure what would happen. I agree it would be good to wait a while to see.  But there was a useless edit 11 hours ago that put it in the review queue, which it left with 3 selecting Leave Closed.  After that, would a reopen vote put it back in the queue?

Comment: @JonasMeyer  reopen votes (in contrast to edits) place a question into review also another time (except there are active reopen votes on it that already triggered a review). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572 at the end.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to have shown up in the review queue, so my guess based on what quid says is that the earlier spot on the queue was initiated by a reopen vote instead of that edit that was around the same time.  Turns out posting here was a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 6):

> **Reopened**

Request to reopen this question:

[If the map induces identity on all homotopic groups then it is homotopic to identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124713/if-the-map-induces-identity-on-all-homotopic-groups-then-it-is-homotopic-to-iden)

It appears that the question was closed because the closers did not read it carefully: At least the first close vote stemmed from the incorrect assumption that the question was about the proof of Whitehead's theorem. Even in its original form the question was about something else.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798888/properties-of-hom-mathbbz-mathbbq-mathbbq) was marked as a duplicate of an identical one by the same user. But the duplicate has been deleted, leaving a question marked as duplicate of a deleted question.

Can we either reopen this one, or undelete the other one? I don't care too much either way, those 2 rep points (because of the downvote) aren't the end of the world.

Comment: Fishy stuff: 1. User posts twice the same question 14 minutes apart. 2. The same day, mod deletes latter version. 3. Seven months later (=yesterday), user deletes *earlier* version.

Comment: Not necessarily fishy, @Did. The earlier version was downvoted at some time and never upvoted. If that was shortly before the deletion, you have an un-fishy explanation for the deletion: get back two reps.

Answer (score 5):

> **Deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted "unilaterally" by a mod**

Request for reopening: [Probability of first player rolling double six first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587870/probability-of-first-player-rolling-double-six-first)

It was closed as "missing context or other details," but there were significant thoughts and attempts shown.  The original formatting would make it easy to overlook the attempts at first.  I have edited to try to make it clearer.  I waited out the reopen review queue, and waited for it to leave the front page after my edits, before posting here.

Answer (score 5):

> <s>Deleted by Community</s> **Undeleted**

I would like this question to be undeleted: [Why is there more room in a square room than there is in a rectangular room?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082474/why-is-there-more-room-in-a-square-room-than-there-is-in-a-rectangular-room-when)

I believe it was deleted as a consequence of having a negative score when the owner's account was deleted, but I think Rahul's answer is a gem worth saving - and the other answers are substantial contributions too. The question is actually pretty good too (though it is hard to see this without first seeing the answers), and I edited it to be a bit less aggressive in tone.

Comment: "The question is actually pretty good too (though it is hard to see this without first seeing the answers)": so the answers are good, the question isn't. A question doesn't get to -4 for no reason...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what drew your attention to that question a good month after it was deleted? You hadn't posted an answer there, it's not among your "favorites", how did you become aware of it being deleted?

Comment: @DanielFischer I happened to discover the "earned bounties" tab on my profile and was looking through old answers of mine, noticed a comment I left on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1083147/) other answer (to a question I'd earned a bounty on), clicked the link, and saw that it was deleted, and that that was sad.

Comment: Ah, strategic commenting ;)

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

Request for reopening: [Norm of the product of an isometry and a bounded operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171839/), closed as unclear, was originally unclear, but no longer is.

Answer (score 5):

> **Undeleted - Redeleted - Re-undeleted - Locked**

[Inequality $\prod\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}(1+(\frac{1}{2})^r)<\frac 52$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110242/inequality-prod-limits-r-1-infty1-frac12r-frac-52) was a good question with a couple of decent answers. I think it should be undeleted. Although a bit slim, the OP did state that they had tried induction (and I used induction in one of my approaches, so it is possible). The OP made a strange last minute edit, changing the upper limit of the product to $-\infty$, but I have changed it back to $\infty$.

I should note that I have answered this question.

Comment: I deleted the comments. Sorry about resorting to a blunt instrument in resolving the matter, but the comment exchange took a turn for worse. Very mildly so - only one flag so far - but I'm nipping this one in the bud. Largely because the discussion was no longer relevant to the topic of this un/delete request,

Answer (score 5):

> **Undeleted**

[Why is $(-1)!!=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1167650) was deleted. While the question has no context, it does not seem like a homework question, and $(-1)!!$ is probably not that obvious to the neophyte.  It is true that the answer can be found on Wikipedia if one knows to look for "Double Factorial", but again, that may not be obvious to the beginner.

Furthermore, this just seems like a question to which we should have the answer here. So unless this question is a duplicate, I think it should be undeleted.

I should note that I have answered this question.

Answer (score 5):

> **Undeleted**

Please vote for the undeletion of [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194636/atiyah-macdonald-5-4). The OP deleted it right after I've posted an answer which I consider useful for other users, knowing that Atiyah and Macdonald is one of the most studied books as an introduction to CA and AG.

Answer (score 5):

> **[Reopened, closed again](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1239248/revisions)** (off-topic/missing context), **deleted** and **undeleted** and **reopened**

Please vote to reopen this question: [Let $I = \{a +\sqrt2b \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt2] : a$ and $b$ are both multiple of $5\}$. Show that $I$ is a maximal ideal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1239248)

It was closed as a duplicate, but it isn't: in the linked post the ideal $5\mathbb Z[i]$ is not maximal, while $5\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ it is, so there is a clear difference between the two rings, and the questions themselves.

Comment: Since the question has been abandoned and has two good answers, I took the liberty to add some context and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

I suggest to reopen [Translate this proof from German to English](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278723/translate-this-proof-from-german-to-english)

The question was edited so that now the contents of the image is typed as text.

This question already was [in the reopen review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/411415) and the result of the review was *"Leave Closed"*. But if I read the timestamps correctly, it was before this edit.

There were several discussions about [translation-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-request)s and it seems that such questions are allowed on this site.

Comment: Um, I thought editing a closed question to include the answer in it (which is what Brian M. Scott did) [was a no-no](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19494/editing-closed-questions-to-add-answers)?

Comment: I agree that editing an answer into the question is not good. But I think that this is a separate issue from whether the first half of the edit (i.e., edit of the question, not adding the answer) improved the post enough to be reopened. I have [pinged the user who made that edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278723/translate-this-proof-from-german-to-english#comment2605448_1278723) and asked him to move this to an answer. But for the time being I suppose it is best to leave the answer there, so that somebody else does not waste their effort on the same translation.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I agree in principle. However, in the current case at least the question was also improved by typing it up. And, from a purely practical point of view it seems considerably simpler to do it like this. Thus, I consider it as more understandable in this special case.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

This [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359009/how-to-count-the-real-roots-of-a-quartic-equation), about how many real roots a (real) quartic equation has, was closed as "off-topic" qua not about mathematics.

The OP is not a native English speaker, but based on clarifying comments, I have undertaken to rewrite the Question, disposing of distracting elements that may have induced much of the votes to close earlier.

Please consider voting to reopen.  The OP mentions discriminants, which is one of several possible approaches, and in my opinion shows sufficient context for the Question to be taken seriously by the Community.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

How about we reopen the following?

[Is there a non-trivial countably transitive linear order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1381697/462)

The question asks about an interesting, unusual object. As the comments show, several "typical" candidates fail (for easy reasons), and to find an example is really not entirely straightforward.

The problem is tagged "set theory" and "order theory" but it should just as well have the "model theory" tag (as the given answer illustrates). Reopening it should give us the chance to see additional examples. I myself am curious to learn what the "modest mouse" is.

(The poster has edited the question recently, adding some relevant background.)

Comment: I found this in the re-open review queue and cast the final vote to re-open it. The original question was a PSQ, but it has been edited since then.

Answer (score 5):

> **Reopened**

This Question [Two disjoint closed sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that there does not exist (positive) $\varepsilon$ with $d(A,B) \gt \varepsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639784/two-disjoint-closed-sets-a-b-subset-mathbbr-such-that-there-does-not-exis) was mistakenly marked as a duplicate due to my overlooking the requirement that $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  The faux duplicate concerns two closed subsets of the plane.

Little help?

Answer (score 5):

> **Undeleted**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699078/does-sum-x-in-mathbbzne-xtmx-sqrt-frac-pin-detm-sum-x/) was deleted right after OP saw my answer. I just want to have the answer for myself as I used some time to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Yes, this should be undeleted. I will flag the question.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1776194/revisions)**

I think that [Why do people accept the axiom of choice given the well ordering principle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776194/why-do-people-accept-the-axiom-of-choice-given-the-well-ordering-principle) should be reopened.

It's a valid question, and I recall at least two undergraduate classmates that felt the same way back in our sophomore and senior years. It's a clear enough question to anyone who has heard it before, which is how Noah and myself knew to answer it (I can't speak for Noah's understanding, but I immediately knew what's the question).

Answer (score 4):

> **Reopened, marked as duplicate**

Please vote for reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752265/prime-ideals-of-the-ring-of-integers-lying-over-p-mathbbz#comment3576808_1752265). As I've mentioned into the comments, it is a duplicate, but it's also closed for a wrong reason, that is, "*unclear what you're asking*": I think it's pretty clear what the OP is asking!

Comment: That question had a bit of bad luck. Since it was closed, five reopen votes aged away.

Answer (score 4):

> **Reopened**

Please consider reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2008917/11619). The original version was dismally unclear. The first revision (not much better) came after it was put on hold, so that window of opportunity for getting it reopened came and went.

I edited it recently to make it clear what is being asked (reverse engineering the notation was not difficult for me, but I do have a tiny bit of experience with that). Arguably the question is still not good (lack of context?), so I quite understand, if you want to leave it closed. At least it should now be clear what is asked.

Answer (score 4):

**Re-opened**

Requesting more opinions about [this closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2075681/11619). If I got it right the votes to close it as unclear were partly (if not solely) motivated by the unusual notation for the Legendre symbol. User Did fixed that, but that was too little too late.

Initially there were also comments from users who missed the fact that the question was not about the usual alternating variant of the harmonic series but rather a variant were the signs follow a periodic pattern of length seven. I made an edit trying to make the pattern of signs clear. Since then the question has received two votes to reopen.

**Disclaimer:** I answered because IMHO the question was quite clear with the Legendre symbol explained in the accompanying text. Arguably we would like to see more context. You be the judge (new user to whom English is not the first language). My answer came well before the question was closed, so the reopening is for the benefit of those users who want to see Did evaluate the series as a definite integral involving a rational function :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Undeleted, Deleted again, Currently Undeleted, now mod-deleted.

I'd like to have [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656605/probability-mass-function-problem-y-x2) undeleted. The question owner has deleted it for some reason *after* I provided the solution (which he upvoted and accepted) for seemingly no reason.

**EDIT:** This user has once again deleted the question for no good reason after I responded to a comment on that question by @JohnMa...

Comment: You could flag the question for moderator attention. Moderators don't like it when people delete their own questions after getting answers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, I didn't know I could do that for deleted questions. Thank you!

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm not sure you can. But if you can't, you could flag some other question....

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just tried it and it seems to have worked. Hopefully it actually flagged the question and a mod sees it...

Comment: Yeah, I flagged.

Answer (score 4):

**Undeleted**

---

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685022/applying-a-formula-like-mathbbe-x-vert-sigma-mathcalf-mathcalg) has been deleted by its author. However, I don't see anything wrong with the question; the statement of the problem is well posed and understandable, as well as there is some context.

Furthermore, one user has already posted an answer although it has not received any upvotes yet, I don't think it should be wasted.

Comment: Indeed a good question, with context and all (and a good answer as well...).

Answer (score 4):

> **Undeleted**, **reopened**, **reclosed**, **re-reopened**

I would like to see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512339/one-equation-four-variables-how-to-solve) undeleted. It received three upvotes and four reopen votes and several good answers. There is a reasonable amount of work shown by the asker, and it is mathematically interesting.

There is a [related meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28071/why-is-this-question-closed) <del>(10k+ only)</del>.

Comment: The question lacks key context, most notably *where* the OP came across the problem and why it is of interest.

Answer (score 4):

> **Reopened**

On mathematical grounds, I'd like to voice that a mistake was made to mark this [post #2766434](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766434/sum-of-exponentially-distributed-random-numbers) as a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655302) from 2014.

The linked older question in 2014 is the basic case where all the rates (of underlying Poisson process) are constant and identical. In #2766434 not only the rates are not identical, they are to be modeled with distinct distributions (which I think is the main point of the question).

Comment: "Marked as duplicate" means it *is* closed.

Comment: I previously thought "marked as duplicate" is not the same as "closed as duplicate". Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Even though it's not my post, here's my thanks to all of you who participated in reopening it.

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089990/can-you-formalize-the-proof-that-1-2-cdots-n2-13-23-cdots-n#1089990) is not a duplicate of "proof by induction" because it is explicitly asking for a proof that is *not* by induction, but rather one that explains the method used in the included GIF.  (The question was edited to clarify.)

Answer (score 3):

> The closed question was merged into the non-closed question.

This [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093774/trouble-doing-simple-polynomial-interpolation) got closed as a duplicate of another by the same user, [namely this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093771/trouble-doing-polynomial-interpolation), but it is the former that has an Answer.  (The former was migrated to Math.SE as the new user had cross-posted the same problem.)

I recommend the closed-as-duplicate status be switched to the unanswered version, and have voted to reopen accordingly (so the other/unanswered one can be closed instead).

Comment: Maybe I'll just merge the two questions.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened, closed as duplicate**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095801/why-do-some-accept-zero-as-a-natural-number-but-others-dont) was closed as opinion based (although two votes were to close as a duplicate). It should be reopened and re-closed properly as a duplicate, since this topic has been discussed before. Two immediate duplicates:

1. [Is $0$ a natural number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number)
2. [Should $\mathbb{N}$ contain $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391840/should-mathbbn-contain-0)

There might be more out there.

Comment: No, since the links are in the comments below, whereas a duplicate banner is on the top of the post and the first thing you see. Moreover the question *is* in fact a duplicate. "Closed is closed" is not true, there are *different* kinds of closure for questions, it can be closed since it's off topic, or since it's missing details (which is under off topic, but not really off topic), or it can be opinion based, or it can be a duplicate. Different closures mean different things. This question *is* a duplicate and should be closed as such.

Comment: So... "why is there such a conflict in conventions?" automatically make bad questions for the site? I disagree.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks. It's a shame the dupe-hammer cannot be applied to link to multiple questions at the same time.

Comment: Indeed, that would be a nice feature.

Comment: @Daniel: Although unlikely to be implemented (since if something is a duplicate of several questions it "means" that either it contains multiple questions or those questions are duplicates; of course this is not at all true in reality, but philosophically it seems to be the guiding idea).

Comment: @Asaf: I think on MSE it is sometimes done. Shog9 can even close a closed question or something like that.

Comment: @quid: Yes, but he's using godmode cheats. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

I'd like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124808/discount-in-infinity) question reopened. The confusion in the question is perfectly clear - the OP does not have a clear distinction between the terms 'sequence' and 'number' - but this could be easily remedied by an answer that explicitly points this out, explains the distinction between sequences and numbers, and then goes on to explain that sequences can have limits. The sequence $n \in \mathbb{N} \mapsto (9/10)^n k$ does not literally equal the number $0$, but it has a limit, and that limit does indeed equal $0$. On the other hand, the number $0.9999\ldots$ *literally* equals $1$.

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133483/multiple-answers-sequence) was put on hold as being unclear about what is being asked but as can be seen on comments there had hints on how to improve. Everything who was suggested was adopted to improve the question and no new comments came in about why is it unclear. I therefore request the question to be reopen as I really need answers to it.

Comment: The question just had a major revision.

Comment: @Gerry For consistency, please note all the other answers (except for one....) use a new format for status update.

Comment: @Najib, any system strong enough to be complete will be inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

The author of [Probability of going into an absorbing state](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145592/probability-of-going-into-an-absorbing-state) seems to have an idea of an approach, but there are better approaches to suggest. Good hints will be useful to the author and to future readers. The methods of attack will be useful to general absorption problems. I believe that the question should be reopened so that hints can be provided.

Answer (score 3):

> **Closed, Reopened, Closed as duplicate**

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159273/trouble-understanding-the-mathematical-induction-principle) question should have been closed as a duplicate of

- [Dominoes and induction, or how does induction work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work) (My preference)
- or [the concept of Mathematical Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581127/the-concept-of-mathematical-induction)

I can't re-close right now due to system constraints.

Comment: +1 It is also too broad - explaining "every little detail" would require a book (and there are already many books that discuss induction in great detail, to which the OP should be directed).

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

I wish to appeal for the reopening of one of my questions: [Evaluating $\int e^{\Gamma(x)} dx $ and $\int \pi^{\Gamma(x)} dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162764/two-of-the-most-complex-integrals-ive-encountered)

I have almost nothing more to say; question was even bolded in the original post, and still was marked as unclear. I do not know why; nevertheless I've done what I can in editing it, and see absolutely no grave mistakes/issues with my question. Lot of interesting insights and answers have been lost due to the fact people are not able to answer/give hints. Please help me reopen this.

Comment: Why did you edit @Najib? It was there in every answer, hence I did that...

Comment: Only the change in status is recorded, not the original status. It makes it easier to browse through the list by creating a visual difference between requests for which nothing has changed (and thus still require action), and those for which something has changed (usually the issue has been resolved). Moreover, the format you used was different from the format of all the other requests...

Comment: As for your question... I suggest that you edit the title. "The most complex integral you've encountered" is not very descriptive, it could be pretty much anything depending on who you are... I also think that putting the actual question *before* the background would be a good idea: people read from top to bottom, and having to scan the text for the question might be off-putting. Other than that your question isn't really unclear (though I'm not sure why you expect a nice form for these integrals).

Comment: I did that believing I'd remove some ambiguity about the status that way, but I understand now. Ty for the edit. Will incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Done.

Answer (score 3):

[RE-OPENED]

I would like for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177748/how-to-solve-5x-0-01x/1177834#1177834) question to be reopened. It was only closed in the first place because of a minor typo in the title of the question; the OP has since fixed the typo in question.

There are three answers to the question one of which has been accepted.

The stated reason for putting the question on hold is not valid.

Comment: Your answer appear to be false. As the typo apparently was in the post not the title. Perhaps you could fix this.

Comment: I give up.${}{}$

Comment: @quid, good point. I don't think that my answer loses any utility by not being exactly the one the OP meant to ask. In fact I'll often given an answer to a similar question which is not identical to the OP's in order to discourage cheating. That is the OP should at least have to apply the method himself. I'll just add a note at the beginning of my answer mentioning the discrepancy.

Comment: This seems a reasonbale solution given the situation at hand.

Answer (score 3):

> **Duplicate redirected**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20737/prime-powers-that-divide-a-factorial?lq=1) has been marked a duplicate of [How come the number $N!$ can terminate in exactly $1,2,3,4,$ or $6$ zeroes but never $5$ zeroes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/how-come-the-number-n-can-terminate-in-exactly-1-2-3-4-or-6-zeroes-but-n) which on its turn is marked a duplicate of [Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n). It would be better to link the first question directly to that last one.

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened, Reclosed, Rereopened**

I would like [this feature request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20307/we-desperately-need-a-new-menu-item) to be re-opened.

It was closed as a duplicate, not of a feature request, but of a question from someone who was curious to know why missing details make a question off-topic.  **I am not curious to know why this is done.  I posted a feature request, not a request to be told why that is done.**  I no longer care why it is done because I am satisfied that it is wrong and I don't want to study the reasons why rude people are rude.  I'm sure the study of why people do things that are wrong is fascinating, but it's off topic in my feature request.

Answer (score 3):

[Re-opened]

I think that [Is the axiom of choice really all that important?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253650/is-the-axiom-of-choice-really-all-that-important) should be reopened.

I can cast a unilateral vote to reopen, but I feel that since I wrote answers both to this one and the duplicate, I shouldn't be hasty to use my powers here.

In any case, the two questions (the question, and the voted duplicate) are different in their presentation and therefore the answers are somewhat different in their essence. Sufficient, I feel, for *not* having them as duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

[Reopened]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258577/error-function-etymology-why-the-name) was closed because it is said to be a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/why-is-the-error-function-defined-as-it-is).

This is absurd.  The content of the newly closed question is:

> **Why the word "error" was chosen as the name of the function**
>   $$
> x\mapsto\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac 2{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2}\,dt\text{ ?} \tag 1
> $$

The content of the earlier question, of which that was alleged to be a duplicate, is:

> **Why is it normalized in that way, rather than using the function**
>   $$
> x\mapsto \frac 1 2 + \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac x {\sqrt 2} \right) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2}\,dt,
> $$
>   **which arises naturally in the theory of probability?**

Comment: You have a point there and I voted to reopen, while dupe closure seems not "absurd" either. However, could you *please* try to internalize that one **cannot** notify users that voted to close, so that you writing several near-identical comments is completely pointless and pure noise.

Comment: @quid : Are you saying nothing appears in their notifications?  If so, I'd say that's a bug.  But I also wonder how you would know that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, this is what I am saying. I know because I [read the documentation of the feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) (and I assume the documentation is in-line with the behavior on the site). Here the relevant bit (my emphasis), it is even made explicit there (not just inferable as it is not mentioned as possible): "For questions: The moderator who closed the question. **Users who have closed** or reopened a question without a binding close vote (i.e. without a gold tag badge or a moderator vote) **cannot be notified.**"

Comment: I have no idea what a "gold tag badge" is and I can only surmise what the term "moderator vote" means.  How to tell whether a question has been closed without those things is something I've never given a second's thought to.

Comment: *As a rule* you can assume it was closed without this and *you cannot notify.* You can notify only a closer marked with a diamond (mod) or a yellow circle (gold badge in tag on question, ie, 1000 score in 200 non CW answer). The point is these can close a question *alone* (binding vote, one vote suffices). In this case it makes some sense to allow to notify this one user. However, it is not desirable that numerous users are notified especially not via numerous comments (as you tried), which is a rational behind the design.

Comment: @quid : Why is it undesirable?  To me responsibility appears desirable. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right. I erred in voting to close here.

Comment: Because it adds too much noise. Anyway, this was not really my point. The point is it does not work, and it is by design it does not work. (I will not recommend you file a feature-request if you want it changed as I am pretty sure it was filed already frequently.)

Comment: @quid : What makes you think it was filed frequently?  And is that really a reason not to request it again?  One might think that if the number of people requesting something is large, that in itself might be a cogent reason to think it should be done.

Comment: It is just an educated guess. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-close-voters-when-a-closed-question-gets-edited) and [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238128/notify-close-voters-when-the-op-adds-a-comment-after-the-question-was-closed) and [third](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85771/is-single-comment-to-notify-several-users-a-reasonable-idea) for related but not identical ideas. Yet, do as you please. And, I just said "I will not recommend" not "I will recommend not." (Abstractly, upvoting existing requests is common, not reposting.)

Answer (score 3):

> Re-opened.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311886/hodges-motet-non-vos-relinquam-and-indiscernible-sequences) is about a chapter epigraph in Wilfred Hodges, *A Shorter Model Theory*. Please reopen it. It has been closed for being off topic.

That claim is false, as the text under the musical notation shows. Hodges states that the epigraph is intended as a heuristic illustration("with allowances for artistry") of an important concept, "an indiscernible sequence", theorems about which are central to the chapter.

The question asking about the epigraph is a question about indiscernible sequences, and is on topic.

Further, closing the question is unfair to the asker. It shows genuine research effort, highlighting a non-obvious point in an advanced textbook. I had not previously noticed that this epigraph needs more attention to understand it than other chapter headings of the book. The answer I wrote is certainly not definitive, but the question has motivated me to return to the book and I have a better understanding of the chapter as a result. To that extent the question is helpful to other readers of the book. It is really of much higher quality than most of what is asked on this site!

Comment: Thanks, Martin.

Comment: As is usual with this kind of request, editing this kind of information into the question would make things easier for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

> **Undeleted**

Please vote for undelete the following question: [Projective dimension of all principal ideals is finite. Is R an integral domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801686/projective-dimension-of-all-principal-ideals-is-finite-is-r-an-integral-domain). This is not trivial, has an upvoted answer, and moreover it's linked to this question: [If $R$ is a noetherian local ring, then every 2-generated ideal has finite projective dimension iff $R$ is a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802747/if-r-is-a-noetherian-local-ring-then-every-2-generated-ideal-has-finite-proje)

Answer (score 3):

> **Closed, Reopened, Closed, Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted**

I would like my question to be undeleted and reopened: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353475/nice-combinatorics-puzzle

My question was initially closed for missing context. After I provided the requested context, it was reopened. Then it was closed for the second time, now for being off-topic. Apparently some members of the community are of the opinion that mathematical puzzles have no place at this site. Yet there are countless examples of well-received puzzles at this site that prove otherwise.

========================================================================

Update, september 2018. After three years I return to this website, only to see that my question has not been reopened or undeleted (in contrast to many others). Strange. If I click on the link, I am lead to my old question. In the column on the right I see a whole list of similar puzzle-type of questions which have been approved and awarded points. Bizarre.

Comment: [You might be interested in this.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/should-all-math-puzzles-go-to-puzzling-se-from-now-on)

Comment: I voted to undelete, for two reasons: a) A comment under the question (which received $4$ upvotes and thus played a significant role in the discussion) says: "We're here to *help* people, and you don't need help with this." I disagree; in fact it's quite normal for questions to be posted for reasons other than needing help, and most such questions are not closed or deleted.

Comment: b) The partial answer given by Emisor demonstrates that thinking about prime factorizations is required to solve the puzzle. This is not "elementary, using only every day ideas and notions" (as described in the question Najib linked to above). There are many more trivial questions about divisibility and prime factorizations, and they're generally considered mathematical and not closed or deleted.

Comment: FWIW I cast a vote to undelete this. Memories.

Answer (score 3):

Reopened.

Please reopen [Changing the values of a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ of bounded variation for countably infinitely many points not a dense subset of $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405021/changing-the-values-of-a-function-fa-b-to-mathbb-r-of-bounded-variation-f/)

It was closed as a duplicate of [Changing the values of an integrable function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ countably infinitely many points not a dense subset of $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405023/changing-the-values-of-an-integrable-function-fa-b-to-mathbb-r-countably), but voters apparently missed the distinction that the original question is about *bounded variation* while the alleged duplicate is about *integrability*.

Comment: Agreed on the distinction. Remains the lack of personal input.

Comment: It is reopened now. Should it be closed again, this time for lack of context, @Did? (There is at least some context - the OP says what happens for finitely many points.)

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

[What is the minimum cardinality for a set intersecting each member of a configurations of pairwise intersecting disks of the same radius?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656513/minimum-number-of-points-required-to-cover-all-circles) was closed as unclear. I had moderate success in guiding OP to clarify; I think the question can be understood now [and it certainly can, if you are also willing to dive into the comments]. Last time I looked, it had stalled at 4 votes to reopen. Is there a fifth?

Comment: Is it possible that it stalled at four votes to reopen because you need to read a dozen comments to fully understand the question...?

Comment: I rewrote it now. Hoping to match the intent.

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened and dupe-closed** (with different target)

The question is closed as a duplicate of a question that is not at all a good target.

[Show that the group $G$ is abelian if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894118/show-that-group-is-abelian)

I would like it to be reopened. It then could be closed as a duplicated of the many better targets (see comment there) or also treated as a "proof verification" (but I think just closing it again would make sense).

(The problem is that the target literally asks something very different, commutator instead of center, and only then proceeds to give a proof as if the commutator where the center. What's worse the answer picks up the literal version of the question, so one cannot even edit the target to improve it.)

Answer (score 3):

> <s>**Reopened**, waiting for a reclose</s>
>
> **[Reclosed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2293052/revisions)** as appropriate duplicate

Request to reopen and then reclose this question:

[Rational points on circles centered at the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293052/rational-points-on-circles-centered-at-the-origin)

This closing reason of this question as an extra duplicate of
[Does $a^2+b^2=1$ have infinitely many solutions for $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30818/does-a2b2-1-have-infinitely-many-solutions-for-a-b-in-mathbbq)
is mathematically wrong. Knowing there are infinitely many rational solution
$x^2+y^2 = 1$ doesn't help to determine whether $x^2+y^2 = z$ has rational $x,y$ as solutions for a generic rational number $z$.

Please reopen and then reclose above question as a duplicate of [Which rationals can be written as the sum of two rational squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445058/59379) which contains answers appropriate to above question.

Answer (score 3):

> > Reopened

Please consider reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482083/is-vtav-diagonal-in-general). It was closed as unclear. The confusion (I guess) is probably that the statement is very closed to the statement concerning diagonalization of symmetric matrices.

However, the question as stated is quite clear (and is not the same as the theorem on diagonalization) and should stay on the site, since this is a legitimate confusion that a student would have when they first learn diagonalization and other students would benefit from this question (and of course the answers).

Comment: It is not clear to me that the asker really understood the question they wrote, or intended the quantifiers to be the way they are implied by their phrasing.  The only response they have given to the feedback they received is accepting egreg's answer, which doesn't clearly address this point.  So while I agree that what the asker literally wrote is a question worth having, I'm not sure it's the question they meant to ask...

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes, I agree it's not clear that they understand. But that seems to be orthogonal to whether the question should be closed?

Answer (score 3):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518823/find-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2-n-alpha-n) got closed as off-topic. However in the comments OP showed that they have tried to solve the problem and put some efforts in it. Furthermore, the question has context. They edited the question and I tried to improve a bit the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

It's about this question: [The multiplicative group of all complex $2^n$-th roots of unity, where $n = 0 , 1, 2 , \ldots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327017/the-multiplicative-group-of-all-complex-2n-th-roots-of-unity-where-n-0).

In my opinion, from the very beginning the OP showed enough effort and determination to solve the problem by himself, so I think it was unfair to close it. I've voted for reopening, and maybe others want to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Reopened.

I would like to request that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329721/is-there-any-published-research-on-the-value-of-finding-new-proofs-for-old-theor) be re-opened.  In its original form, it was closed as being primarily opinion-based -- a decision I don't disagree with.  But I have edited it so that it now asks a fact-based question, one to which I am prepared to provide an objective, researched answer.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

Please I would like to request to remove the "put on hold" of: [If a n-manifold exists, then is it the boundary of an existing (n+1)-manifold? [on hold]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382555/if-a-n-manifold-exists-then-is-it-the-boundary-of-an-existing-n1-manifol?noredirect=1#comment2819866_1382555)

I have rewritten the question to clarify it. I have read carefully the comments and simplified it. Indeed it is already answered, and the user that answered understood what I wanted to express, and I already accepted the answer. So if possible I would appreciate very much if could be removed the on-hold with the changes I did. If still the new formatting of the question is unclear please let me know, sometimes it is hard to express things for a non native English speaker :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Reopened.

[Polynomial equations of degree larger than 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405468/polynomial-equations-of-degree-larger-than-4) was put on hold as "unclear". OP has now edited the question so that it is clear (the introductory part is still a little rough, but the boldface part is quite clear, I think). Please consider voting to reopen.

[It's quite possible that the question is a duplicate of some earlier question, although no one has nominated a candidate. In any event, there is the option to reopen, then close as a duplicate, if warranted.]

Answer (score 2):

Hi I want to reopen my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618182/factoring-semi-primes-convert-algorithm-to-function), can you give me a tip on how I can improve it so it will qualify for this site.

Comment: Everything up the "Question" part is fine. It talks about some algorithm about factoring. However, the last few lines in the question section is problematic. It seems you are asking how to implement a function for that. If that is indeed the case, then it is about programming and not math, that will be off-topic for math.SE. If that is not the case, then you haven't told us  the real "math" question.

Comment: @achillehui Tnx, I edited the question to make it more clear. Please take a look in it now.

Comment: This is better now, you get at least one reopen vote from me.

Answer (score 2):

> [**Undeleted**, **re-deleted**, **undeleted**, **reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/201997/revisions)

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201997/finding-a-differentiable-function-satisfying-some-given-conditions) from 2012 (!) was recently closed (and deleted) with the explanation, "Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it." I guess that those who voted to close it didn't notice that the user who posted it had not only included his thoughts on the problem and any attempts he made to solve it – he had actually posted a solution to the problem, based on some hints he was given. This kind of outcome should be celebrated, not closed and deleted over three years after the fact. Please consider voting to undelete.

Comment: The message does say "Please improve **the question**". The **question** is, indeed, not any good right now: bad grammar and spelling, not even a question, and, yes, *no context*. If I went through the question sheet on integrals my students have and asked and answered each and every single one of them with no explanation or motivation, would that be a good thing for the site? I don't think so. But if the *question* included some motivation, explanation about problems encountered and so on, now maybe that would be interesting...

Comment: The **reason** it says "please improve the question" is that we don't want people using the site to get their work done for them without their putting in any of their own effort. OP has manifestly put considerable effort into answering the question, so the reason  – the reason behind the reason, if you will – does not apply.

Comment: Context is also required to make the question useful for future visitors. I hope that we can agree that a question without context is not (at least less) useful for future visitors? What I would like to understand is: if use to future visitors is not a concern... Then what's the point of keeping the question? OP got their answer. And if it is a concern, then the question clearly doesn't meet standards relative to context (which directly impacts its use for future visitors) and keeping it 1/ sends a bad signal ("it's okay to post subpar questions") and 2/ dilutes the good content of the site.

Comment: (Due to a glitch my earlier comment didn't get posted apparently, but I also wanted to make the point that the age of the question is completely irrelevant. This ties into my previous point: OP got their answer 3 years ago. Now the only possible reason to keep this Q&A is for future visitors, and the age of the question has no impact whatsoever on that.)

Comment: I voted to undelete it. I think Gerry has a point here.  I will refrain from voting again, if the disagreement continues, because I don't think that's right. Nevertheless, the question does not look like your average HW question. It probably was a HW question, and we can all surely see that there should be solutions.But explicit examples are apparently not easy to come up with. None of the close-voters made suggestions to the OP what to try.

Comment: I have [edited the post](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/201997/revisions), so that the information that OP's attempt is posted as an answer is more visible. (I suppose this can be a factor if somebody sees the question and deliberates whether the question should be deleted or should stay.) I was tempted to user first person (and simply copy the beginning of the answer), but since we already had some disagreement about this in the past, I chose to use more neutral language. If there are some other improvements which can be made, go ahead and edit the question further.

Comment: You (everyone) know, my question wasn't rhetorical. I'm genuinely interested: why do you (everyone) want to keep this question? For what purpose? (FWIW, I don't think the added sentence makes the question better... @Jyrki says explicit examples are not easy to come by: why not include that information instead? Maybe showing that naive guesses don't work. This would show to everyone that the question is actually interesting, and not another iteration on "solve this system for me".)

Comment: Four days later, and nobody has been able to answer my question. So I'm voting to delete again. Since a moderator undeleted the question when there was only one undelete vote, I think it's fair that only two users (plus me who had already voted) are enough to re-delete the question :)

Comment: I vehemently disagree with your first comment. The reason it says "please improve the question" is so that we then have better (written) questions on the site, not to make an OP jump through hoops to earn the privilege to get an answer.

Comment: I removed the "meta" content from the post, and cast the last vote  to reopen.

Comment: I think the reason we need to require context before questions are answered is because, *after* someone gets an answer, there is much less incentive to edit the question.  In this case, the OP has been inactive since 2013, so asking for them to edit the question seems futile.  We can and should look for more quality in questions than "here is a seemingly arbitrary list of requirements, can you cook up a function that meets them".

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

I think [If $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ then prove that $f(x)=ax$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656500) should be reopened. It was closed as duplicate of a question about Cauchy's functional equation, but it is subtly different, and in my opinion both interesting and a little surprising. (No assumption on regularity, but instead demanding $f$ mapping positive reals to positive reals.)

Comment: It took 40 minutes to reopen this question... Maybe next time wait a few hours for the review queue to do its thing before posting here? :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It wouldn't have hit the review queue. (The edit was made before the final vote to close.)

Comment: Your reopen vote put it in the review queue: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/577459 and three of the votes to reopen came from there... Anyway, what's done is done.

Comment: Additionally, incorrect close votes were also discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27587013#27587013). So users of that chatroom might have noticed it as well. (In fact, I planned to post reopen request there if the question is not reopened from the review.)

Comment: But I should also say that I am glad that the question was reopened. (Just in case the comments sounded too negative.)

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

I think [How do I prove something without premises in a Fitch system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797016/how-do-i-prove-something-without-premises-in-a-fitch-system) should be reopened.

The OP has been edited to provide the necessary information. Proofs without premises are hard to figure out in the Fitch system, and the answer to this quesiton would likely help later users.

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted**

I'd like to see [Volume enclosed by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803165/volume-enclosed-by-x2y2z22-x) undeleted.

The question was deleted very soon after a comment by myself and a reasonable answer by Christian Blatter - though, that answer did offer a solution using an alternative approach. It certainly appears to be a frustrating case where an experienced user creates a temporary account to ask a question only to delete it as soon as they feel they understand it. The comments lead me to think that they don't actually understand it and I'd like to add an answer illustrating the correct approach.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Reopened**

Please reopen

[Prove that there are not two matrices 2x2 such that: $AB-BA=I_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837381/prove-that-there-are-not-two-matrixes-2x2-such-that-ab-ba-i-2)

The question was closed as a duplicate of the more general question:

[$AB-BA=I$ having no solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284901/ab-ba-i-having-no-solutions)

The point is that for the $2\times 2$ one can simply write two general matrices $A$ and $B$ with entries and show that there are no solution to this. This method wouldn't work (at least not very well) for the general case. As such there is value in having the $2\times 2$ case as a separate question.

Comment: I believe the etiquette is to hold back on posting here until the post went through the queue. But other than that I can see the point in this case more than in some other recent examples. It's at least not impossible somebody would be asked the former without knowing about the trace.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

A high school sophomore asked, in initially a sophomoric way, about proving the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (FTA):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848874/the-proof-that-the-number-of-zeroes-of-a-polynomial-the-degree-of-the-polynomial

After receiving the usual feedback (downvotes, closure), the OP edited the Question into fair shape. After an exchange of Comments I further tweaked the wording to focus on aspects of stating and proving the FTA accessible at a high school level.  I think this is a topic which would add valuable content to Math.SE, since the FTA is often introduced without proof to high school students.  This must seem puzzling to those who pause to think why.

Since the Question has now completed its turn in the Reopen Review Queue, I'm appealing to Meta Readers for a couple of additional reopen votes.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862725/working-with-lagrange-multipliers-reducing-gradients-is-okay-right) on Lagrange multipliers was closed for being "unclear."

The actual question seems clear to me: When solving the system of equations for $\lambda$ in the typical Lagrange multiplier calculation, is it OK to reduce the equations to make solving easier? I admit it would be nice if the OP would say something about why they would think that might not be OK, but I still don't really see what's unclear.

There are currently 3 votes to reopen (one of them mine), and it seems to have [gone through](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/657841) the review queue fully.

My apologies if I misunderstand "the natural course" of reopening, but I assume that's more or less done, having completed the review queue, albeit somewhat recently.

Edit: Thanks to quid, I do see the logic of the original closure; no qualms there.

Comment: You understood it right (the meta process I mean). On the question, well, yes I agree it is a borderline but seems about alright now (I cast a vote). But in fairness it was http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1862725/1 that was closed, which is both less clear and less polished than the current one. Indeed, it seems the closure induced an edit by OP that did improve the question. The process works as intended.

Comment: @quid That's a good point -- I looked over the revision history, thinking "Oh, one line, it was basically a formality on their part." But I didn't consider the original version in isolation, it was less clear than I'd thought. I do understand the closure now.

Answer (score 2):

> **[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/44387/revisions)**

Please vote for undelete [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44387/121097). It's a full answer written by a well-known user and it's very useful. The request of the OP for a hint has expired, in my opinion. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that this conversation reached an end of sorts. If you need to revisit it [do it in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44550/discussion-on-answer-by-user26857-requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc).

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted**

Please vote to undelete [How to solve this equations in modular arithmetic? $6247x \equiv 1139 \pmod{9461}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970728/how-to-solve-this-equations-in-modular-arithmetic-6247x-equiv-1139-pmod9461)

The question might have come from http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~andrejb/engg2440/hw/16H03.pdf which specifically says that any use of online material must be properly cited and credited. Deleting the question after receiving an answer seems in bad taste.

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted**

The question [How find the function if such $f(P(x)+Q(f(y))+Q(y)P(f(x)))=Q(y)+P(f(x))+P(x)Q(f(y))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940548) got recently deleted, despite having a score of 3 upvotes and no downvotes, and an answer with the same score. That answer was written by me, and this deletion made me lose 55 points in a single blow. While I understand the necessity of cleaning the site up, I strongly question this specific deletion decision; I cannot find any fault with the question. Could the community take a look at it and voice its opinion, please? Thank you.

(Given that we are talking about a deleted post, only users with at least 10000 reputation points will be able to see it, the others will be directed towards the standard "not found" page.)

Answer (score 2):

> **[Autodeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2039710/revisions)**

I would like to ask whether you would consider reopening [Show that the set $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)|x_1x_2x_3x_4=0\}$ a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039710/show-that-the-set-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4x-1x-2x-3x-4-0-a-linear-subspace-of)

At the moment it is closed with the close reason *missing context*. The OP reacted in comments to some hints. After that I have edited his attempts into the post. (It would have been better if the OP edited the post, but perhaps they will do so next time.) After the edits, I do not think that missing context is still a valid reason. (I would have no problem with closing the question as a duplicate. The closest I was able to find was [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480938/determine-whether-the-subset-x-1-x-2-x-3-in-mathbbf3x-1x-2x-3-0).)

I do not claim that it is great question. But reopening would help reinforce the message to the OP (and other new users): "Editing your posts to include what you were able to do after some hints in comments might lead to reopening."

The question already went through [reopen review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/724073). And I have also suggested reopening this question [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33864946#33864946) before asking here, but without success.

Answer (score 2):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2116042/revisions)**

I propose reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116042/the-mathematics-of-tug-of-war). It's basically a request for references, so I don't think the "show your work" objection applies.

Answer (score 2):

> **Reopened**

[What is the intuitive explanation for the CDF of any random variable to follow uniform distribution (0,1)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401766/what-is-the-intuitive-explanation-for-the-cdf-of-any-random-variable-to-follow-u)

It seems probable that the reason this was put on hold is that initially the question was phrased in such a confused way that many couldn't tell what was meant. That has been remedied and so far three people have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted, deleted, undeleted,**

I would like to request [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485493/complex-eigenvalues) be undeleted.

Shortly after I wrote an answer, the asker commented on the answer, and then deleted the question without explanation. I voted to undelete and also flagged the question, and then a moderator (Jyrki Lahtonen) undeleted the question and explained to the asker why it is rude to delete an answered question. But then the asker deleted the question again without explanation, and then asked a [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486116/roots-of-unity-of-eigenvalues) separately.

If there is a duplicate question somewhere, then I am fine with closing the question as a duplicate (rather than deleting it), but I was unable to find a duplicate.

Also, if I have handled this situation poorly (e.g. answering a question instead of giving hints, or insisting on undeleting a question), please let me know and I will try to correct my behavior.

Comment: Very odd situation here. OP tried very hard to bury the question on m.se, deleting it twice, then when that didn't work vandalizing it twice, and was sternly rebuked by a moderator. And then a moderator went ahead and deleted it. What's going on?

Comment: @GerryMyerson the question was not deleted by a moderator. It was *auto* deleted by the community user. This happened because negatively scored posts of deleted users are deleted. Arguably, it is not a good idea to delete negatively scored questions that have an positively received answer in this way. If you want this changed you may consider to [upvote this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote). // I undeleted again; but I am not sure if autodel will delete yet again, let's see.

Comment: @quid, thanks for enlightening me, and thanks for undeleting. I have now upvoted the feature request, but I note that that post goes back four years, with no activity on it for nearly two years now. Does that mean no one higher up has ever looked at it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am quite sure that somebody looked at it but they decided not to do it (at this point). That is, it is not inertia or neglect but an active decision. The reason I am quite sure is that there was some change related to this more recently. The [behavior was changed for metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231430/when-an-account-is-deleted-dont-auto-delete-its-negatively-scored-posts-on-the) (per site and the main one) and they added a mod-tool to track such posts more easily. Then it ought to have been trivial, and likely even more simple, to change it also on mains.

Comment: Thanks again, @quid. I'd rather that when people make active decisions they also make them in public, with their justification.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree that sometimes the  communication related to feature request could be more active. The following thread that was started some time ago helps a bit https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/

Answer (score 2):

**Reopened**

---

[Show that $\operatorname E\left(\frac{\hat{E}^T \hat{E}}{n-q}\right) = \Sigma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511545/)

The objections to this question have been addressed by recent edits.

Comment: It seems preferable to link to the question, not your answer. If you follow a link to your answer, such as from your profile, the URL in the address bar of your browser will be for your answer not the question. Clicking on the title of the question in the thread would be one way to resolve it. (I change it.)

Comment: @quid : I hadn't realized that my answer is what I'd linked to.

Comment: No problem. I did not assume you did it on purpose. It happens somewhat frequently, which is why I try to raise awareness. With limited success...the most recent answerer here did the same thing. At least I can copy over my comment! :-)

Answer (score 2):

> **Undeleted**

This question *[convergence in operator norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766689/convergence-in-operator-norm)* received an answer (from an experienced user) in an hour after creation.  However, OP self-deleted his question three hours after that.  According to one of our site mods, this is an "[abusive behaviour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759560/extending-the-triangle-inequality#comment5694741_2759560)".  Therefore, I propose to undelete this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Reopened

I am requesting my posting [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106832/infinity-and-the-maximum-of-natural-number) to be reopened, since I have revised the question to the point of being a multiple choice question, so that the issue of "... it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking..." should no longer be an issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened, Reclosed, Deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1297175/revisions)**

I have edited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297175/why-should-statistics-be-considered-mathematics), deleting the poster's opening statement about his hatred of statistics, which is off topic.  It was closed as "primarily opinion-based".  But the proper remedy was just to delete the initial opinion, and I have done that.  The question remains intact after deletion of the off-topic opinion.

The content of the question is substantial and serious.  Now that the off-topic personal remark at the beginning is gone, I propose that this be re-opened.

[Why should statistics be considered mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1297175)

Answer (score 1):

[Undeleted]

I suggest we undelete [Most natural intro to Complex Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364439/most-natural-intro-to-complex-numbers), a question that has a net of 7 upvotes, 3 favorites, and several answers with 5 or more net upvotes (including, I add in the interests of full disclosure, one of mine).

Comment: This is tangential but I feel like mentioning it: *favorites* in my mind is not an indicator of quality. More often than not I favorite a question as something is wrong with it  and I want to keep monitoring the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1443429/revisions)**

The question [Need Examples to Understand Choice Function and Choice Structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443429/need-examples-to-understand-choice-function-and-choice-structure) is in no way a duplicate for the following question:
[(P(X),CR) may be a choice structure even if R is not a rational relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443029/px-c-r-may-be-a-choice-structure-even-if-r-is-not-a-rational-relation)
In the former I have asked people to provide me some examples to understand the definition of Choice function and Choice structure. In the other question, I have asked for an example to show that a relation underlying a choice structure should not necessarily be a rational relation. The only relation between these two questions is the definition included in the latter question to clarify the question. I though including the definitions will help people to understand my question! Would you please reopen my question or at least tell me how I can clarify the distinction between my question and request StackExchange to remove the hold on my account?

Comment: Wouldn't an example of a choice structure in which $R$ is not a rational relation also be an example of a choice structure?

Comment: @Carl Mummert, No, because in the former question, my problem was understanding the fundamental concepts. If you take a look at the content of the question, I have completely explained that. Providing the example for a choice structure based on a non-rational relation would not help me understand those concepts. The latter question is actually a proof, while the former one only need explanation and examples.

Comment: I would recommend doing one thing at a time. If you want to understand the fundamental concepts, ask about them. If you want a non-rational structure, ask about that. But don't ask both at once.  Also, it would have helped if you had explained the microeconomics context of these questions - they are not really about set theory, but few here are experts in economics, so people may not realize that is what you are asking about.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that these questions were also discussed in a separate meta thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21473/why-were-these-questions-closed-as-duplicates

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened, reclosed as a duplicate of another question**

I think that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474054/implication-in-mathematics-how-can-a-imply-b-when-a-is-false/1474077) should be reopened, and the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137890/why-is-it-sensical-for-a-proposition-with-a-false-antecedent-to-validate-to-true) be closed as a duplicate.

Based on the quantity of answers and votes, it would be more useful for the other question to be closed as a duplicate, despite the timestamps.

Comment: I think reversals of duplicates are better asked to moderators directly, via a flag or maybe in the "Reopen?..." chat. *

Comment: Moderators have the option of merging a question and a duplicate, so answers don't get lost – isn't that right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is true that question can be merged, it can be tricky though, say, if notations differ or the question (that then will be lost) is referenced in a direct form. Yet then, also if a question is closed as a duplicate the answers are not usually lost (except somebody deletes the thread explicitly).

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate while going through the review queue. I did notice that the target was not nearly as highly voted. I did spot an even earlier (and higher voted) third question about this same theme. I did not want to go against the popular opinion at that time, so I just added a link. Now I redirected the duplication to that question instead.  FWIW the oldest version stands currently at +47 votes as opposed to +11 here.

Comment: I voted to close the "other question" of  a duplicate of the one @JyrkiLahtonen mentions now, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/555426/121097) posted by a deleted user is correct and it answers the question in an elementary way. The OP also wants to accept it (and asked me to undelete the answer, but unfortunately I can't).

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

[Is $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ an $\mathbb{N}$-graded ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661602/is-mathbbzx-y-z-an-mathbbn-graded-ring)

This very straightforward question was closed as lacking context.  I don't really know what more context you could want from the question; I already added to the question information from the comments clarifying OP's motivation in asking the question.

Comment: I would want to know in which way OP tried to apply Nakayama's lemma. In a way it is not strictly necessary for the question as asked but that one is completely trivial and the more interesting thing could be to figure out what was actually going on. Moreover, it would also not hurt if a defintion of Z and N graded were included. One may speculate that had OP taken the time to write them down their question would have resolved itself. (At least the part that is now answered; the actual one is unanswered and unknown in any case)

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

[Why aren't all matrices diagonalisable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694916/why-arent-all-matrices-diagonalisable)

This question was closed as "unclear", perhaps because the original title and first sentence are rather vague despite the remainder of the post posing a clear question.  The question was clear enough for two people to give good answers to it (one accepted), and I changed the title to better match the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened, closed as duplicate**

[prove that $A^2 = I $ implies that $A=I $ or $ A= -I $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689056/prove-that-a2-i-implies-that-a-i-or-a-i)

It is clear what is being asked here.  The fact that the proposition to be proved is not true doesn't make it unclear.

Comment: After reopening, it should probably be closed as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106070/if-a2-i-identity-matrix-then-a-pm-i or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44341/finding-number-of-matrices-whose-square-is-the-identity-matrix (or some other copy of this question)

Answer (score 1):

**Re-opened**

[For invertible matrices $A$ and $C$, prove or disprove that $(C^{-1}BAB^T + I)$ is invertible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712352/for-invertible-matrices-a-and-c-prove-or-disprove-that-c-1babt-i#comment3494642_1712352)

User had a conjecture about some matrices and asked for help proving or disproving it. Ultimately, it turned out to be false based on a simple counterexample, which was posted as an answer. As of this writing, the question had 2 upvotes and zero downvotes, and the answer had 4 upvotes and 0 downvotes.

In other words, the site was working exactly as intended. Then, days later, the question was randomly put on hold.

Now, this is not a groundbreaking or amazing question by any means, but it is also not a bad question either, and therefore it should be left open.

Comment: Something feels really weird about the *asker* being the one to close the question because they didn't include enough information - seems mostly to be an attempt by the asker to get rid of the question now.

Comment: What is the value of *conserving* this question on the site?

Comment: @Did It doesn't add much value, but it does add a little bit, and that is enough. This is one of the main philosophical tenants of the stackoverflow/stackexchange model.

Comment: @NickAlger Any source for the "philosophical tenant" thing? (Please be specific.)

Comment: @NickAlger:  Should "tenant" be "tenet"?

Answer (score 1):

> **Deleted by OP, but reopened while deleted, undeleted**

[NB: I have now cast a vote to undelete.]

Please <strike>reopen</strike> *undelete* [How to find all systems of distinct representatives using i.e. Hopcroft–Karp algorithm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723135/how-to-find-all-systems-of-distinct-representatives-using-i-e-hopcroft-karp-alg)

Recently a Question about finding all maximal matchings of a bipartite graph was closed (placed "on-hold") as off-topic in part because it was a cross-post of a StackOverflow post and in part because it concerned how an existing program that finds *one* maximal matching could be modified to find *all* of them.

So far so good, as I also voted to close.

Then the same user posted this new Question, [How to find all systems of distinct representatives using i.e. Hopcroft–Karp algorithm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723135/how-to-find-all-systems-of-distinct-representatives-using-i-e-hopcroft-karp-alg)  While substantively the topic is nearly identical, it asks about modifying that algorithm, not about modifying some code.  The problem of finding all maximal matchings in bipartite graphs is studied in the literature, esp. by Takeaki Uno ([see this 1997 paper](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac97web.pdf) and some later papers).

With this perhaps subtle change I think the new Question is on-topic for Math.SE, and I've voted to reopen.  In general I think we should avoid "closing as duplicate" when the target has no (good) answers and the underlying problem is truly on-topic here.

Comment: There are currently four votes to reopen this deleted question. I'm tempted to cast the 5th reopen vote, just to satisfy my curiosity as to what happens when a deleted question is reopened.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Now we know what happens (when a deleted question is reopened).

Comment: And now there are two votes to undelete.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Please vote for the reopening of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770223/annihilator-of-a-flat-ideal?noredirect=1#comment3614144_1770223). The OP understood that he has to add some context to his question, and did it. Thanks.

Comment: I voted to reopen. But to be honest, the rant-like paragraph in the [last revision by the OP](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1770223/3) is somewhat putting me off. (Judging by your edit and [your comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770223/annihilator-of-a-flat-ideal#comment3613792_1770223), you did not like it either.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak We are definitely right, but I think we have to give the OP a chance to understood that this is the right way to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened, reclosed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1854049/revisions)**, **deleted**, **undeleted**, **reopened**

I have edited the question it shouldn't cause any trouble now.
Need one more reopen votes.

[A space more fundamental than Euclidean space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854049/a-space-more-fundamental-than-euclidean-space)

**Update:** The question has been revised again.

**Second update (from the editor of the post):** I feel I must respond to the criticism (from Nick Alger and others) that I have changed the OP's intent.  The title of the post was (and is) "A space more fundamental than Euclidean space" and, to my mind, the OP's intent was to ask what this space is, and how it is more fundamental.  This is borne out by the text of the original post

> I have heard that the space of the 0-vector is more fundamental then euclidean space, that euclidean space is more complicated. Could someone explain what is the space of the 0-vector? Google couldnt find anything. And how is it more fundamental?

The phrase "Weierstrass minimial surface" was added in revision 4, an hour later, presumably in the hopes that someone might recognize it and that that would help to answer the original question.  Unfortunately, it probably made things worse, since there apparently is no such thing as a Weierstrass minimal surface.

Based on all this, my reading question is: I heard a physicist talk about a geometry more fundamental than Euclidean geometry.  What is this geometry, and how is it more fundamental?  I feel that my revision is in the spirit of the original question, and is more likely to get an answer, as it clarifies what the speaker meant.

The factors that made the original post difficult to answer, which are no fault of the OP, are that

1. the question is based a conversation in a video, and the speaker is difficult to understand, resulting in some key phrases being mistranscribed.  (My belief is that the speaker didn't actually say "Weierstrass minimimal surface".)
2. the speaker misspoke at several points, saying "zero vector" when he meant "null vector".  (One can verify this by looking at the speaker's publications on this topic.)
3. the speaker may have have conflated the issue of a fundamental, underlying geometry with the issue of minimal surfaces, as one is wont to do when summarizing a large research area in brief extemporaneous remarks.  (This is not my area, so I am uncertain on this point, but many of the speaker's papers talk about a fundamental geometry without mentioning minimal surfaces.)

The result of these confusions was that mathematicians reading the question saw the nonsense phrase "zero-vector space generated by Weierstrass minimal surfaces" (which is not in the video) and said to themselves "must be some of that gibberish that physicists are always spouting.  Go ask one of them."  (Disclosure: I am trained as a physicist.)  In fact, after all the misunderstanding is stripped away, there is a mathematical question here, and I wanted to make that clear.

I'm sorry that the question now comes across as an impenetrable wall of text.  One mistake I may have made was including the term "pure spinor", which comes up often in the publications, and relates to null vectors in, I think, a somewhat involved way.   I'd be happy if someone can pare it down to something more reasonable.

Comment: *Changes* of state are recorded, yet not the initial one.

Comment: Question seems fine now. After stumbling upon the current (edited) version of the question, I myself am interested in knowing the answer.

Comment: @Will Thanks for the reply on the post; at the moment I cannot reply there, since the post is deleted. At this point, I do not consider this as good and voted to undelete. However; this disruption was imminent at the time or your edited, which is one reason why I had considered it as wiser to make a new post.

Comment: @quid: Isn't that better to give a new start to the question (That's why I voted to delete the question)?

Comment: @ArcticChar in principle yes, as I said in comments there. However to try to push this through in this way is ill-advised, in my opinion.

Comment: I think that the idea of trying to salvage the question is well intentioned, but entirely rewriting it in place of the OP ( http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1854049/revisions ) seems less in line with community norms than just starting a new question with the improved content. It really should be up to the OP to make significant improvements on their question, IMO.

Comment: Yeah I don't agree with the newest massive edits; while well-intentioned, they really override the original author's intent. Would the original author even understand his/her own question now? Previously it was a simple and direct question about the definition of a phrase and the intuition behind it. Now it is a rambling wall of text asking general questions about spinors. The key phrase "Weierstrauss minimal surface" doesn't even appear anymore (though it does appear partially), and the key object "zero-vectors" don't appear until one has already read through a page of text.

Comment: @NickAlger: I have responded in the post.

Comment: @WillOrrick one can ask this question at various levels of detail. The original question, in my mind, mainly asked for a rough categorization of the remark in the talk. You provided it, and IIRC OP even said that your remarks are an answer to the question. You think otherwise. But I believe that you in fact did answer the question *to the extent that some cared about it* (possibly including OP but I do not want to interpret them). The question now asked is a lot more specific.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1828691/revisions)

[Counter-examples related to Slutsky's Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828691/why-does-slutskys-theorem-fail-to-generalize)

Nothing is unclear about this question.  The fact that the well known Slutsky's theorem is mentioned makes it clear that the question requests counterexamples showing that one of the hypotheses cannot be weakened in a certain way.  A comment says "are you dealing with probability spaces, general measure spaces, what are $X_n,Y_n,\ldots$".  But the term "Slutsky's theorem" certainly leaves no doubts about that.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

The following question was closed as a duplicate of a question that looks very similar, but really it is not.

[For a subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$: $H_1/N \cong H_2/N \Rightarrow H_1 \cong H_2$. Is it true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900472/for-a-subgroups-h-1-and-h-2-of-g-and-a-normal-subgroup-n-of-g-h-1-n)

This one assumes isomorphy, the dupe target actual equality. 
(Some answer there does answer this question, but is sketchy and not very assertive. The two other answers, including the accepted one, answer that question as asked that is  something else entirely.)

ps. The even is recent but the question is through review one vote missing.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

---

Please vote to undelete this question (only one vote needed): [Polynomials in one variable simple module here or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945145/polynomials-in-one-variable-simple-module-here-or-not). The answer is remarkable. (I think the users doing such things should be warned.)

Comment: Reopen? Did you mean, Undelete? Anyway, it has been undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted**

[Homogeneous equation solve $y''+9y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985642/homogeneous-equation-solve)

Is yet another question that was deleted just 12 minutes after receiving an answer.

Comment: "deleted just 12 minutes after receiving an answer" Is it a problem *per se*? (Regarding the question itself, I see some context in it hence, indeed, closure does not seem adequate, but this is another argument.)

Comment: Did, it often indicates that some foul play is afoot. In this specific case, the OP had changed the parameters of the question (or rather their professor has), and deleted this copy to post a new one. It turned out okay, and there was nothing fishy going on. But this was posted before everything was clarified.

Comment: Oh, I get it, **the asker** deleted their question... Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Reopened.

[Could someone help me with the maths behind this calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029438/could-someone-help-me-with-the-maths-behind-this-calulator)

This is a good problem which the OP didn't know how to formulate mathematically. I've edited to make clear it is about how best to hedge a particular bet and to frame it as a mathematical problem.

Comment: While you may indeed have created a fairly self-contained math problem, unrecognizable from the OP's formulation, it is still a request for advice about how to gamble.  Such requests strike me as have pecuniary motivations rather than educational ones.

Comment: I disagree about unrecognisable - one look at the page the op linked shows what they're trying to do, and all I did was spell that out, not create anything new.

Comment: You are referring to the out-of-site page the OP linked to while @hardmath is mentioning the actual text of the question (on this site). That you have to refer to some other content than the question itself to motivate it goes towards closure (remember that questions should be self contained).

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

[**The relation between quasi-permutation matrix and permutation matrix?**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696812/the-relation-between-quasi-permutation-matrix-and-permutation-matrix)

Please review this Question with an eye to reopening.  The post seems to me a self-contained request for terminology explanation, and the OP was certainly engaged with clarification and attempts to understand that explication.

Disclosure: I answered this Question with reference to the original literature, but likely one or more improved answers could be given by domain experts.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215087/mathbbz-sqrt11-is-norm-euclidean) was closed as duplicate although the question is not answered in the linked thread. Please vote for reopen.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Can this question be re-opened? I'd be interested in seeing it answered.

[Factor $ab^3-ac^3+bc^3-ba^3+ca^3-cb^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241289/factor-ab3-ac3bc3-ba3ca3-cb3)

It was closed as a duplicate of another question, even though it specifically asked for a solution using a certain hint, and none of the answers to the other question or its duplicates, as far as I can tell, use the result in the hint.

Comment: Interesting that at least seven people have posted questions asking for a factorization of this expression. That none of the many answers posted to the seven questions have hit upon the hint leads me to wonder whether there isn't some mistake here, that is, whether there is no way to make any use of the hint.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's possible, but I think it's more likely that nobody has hit upon the idea that the problem setters had in mind. (The phrasing makes it sound very much like the kind of question that would have appeared on British university entrance scholarship exams in decades past.) And on previous questions, they wouldn't have been looking to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2251021/revisions)**

Please consider reopening:

[Permutations with restrictions on item positions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251021/permutations-with-restrictions-on-item-positions)

The OP got what was needed from a Comment I left, and proceeded to ask [this related Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252923/determining-orders-from-binary-matrix-denoting-allowed-positions).  Once clarified the original Question was about efficiently *counting* certain restricted permutations, and the follow-up concerned efficiently *generating* them.

I find the original Q interesting in that the [theorem of Valiant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-completeness_of_01-permanent) (1979) gives a "negative" answer and deserves to be [more widely visible](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=valiant+permanent) on Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2276799/revisions)**

Request for reopening: [Open Problems in Semigroup Theory.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276799/open-problems-in-semigroup-theory?noredirect=1#comment4708786_2276799)

This question received 5 upvotes, a high score for the tag "semigroups", indicating some interest of the community, but it was quickly put on hold as too broad. Only one open problem was mentioned in a comment.

The question is certainly too broad if group theory is not excluded, but otherwise
I am not so sure it is that broad. Anyway, since the OP is referring to Howie's book, one may restrict the question to *semigroups in algebra*, in a wide sense${}^*$. I know of a few existing lists of open problems on semigroups, but it would be useful to gather them in a big-list. All in all, I see this question as a frequently asked question and I think it is worth to reopen it, perhaps in a slightly different form.

$^{* \text{ For instance many questions on finite semigroups are closely related to profinite semigroups, which are topological semigroups.}}$

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

A lot of context has been added to [Binomial expansion going wrong!](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2339559).  I think it is a good question displaying a common pitfall when using power series expansions (and not only because I wrote an answer). I think it should be reopened, but I can't vote to open without unilaterally reopening the question.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2372058/242) started out with a few close votes before the author showed their work, and ended up being closed. Now that work has been shown it probably deserves to be reopenend (esp since it is an instructive example  of use of the mod Distributive Law - which deserves to be much better known).

Comment: The question was not yet through the [reopen review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/847282), which would likely have led to the reopening by itself.

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted**

Please consider undeleting this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386906/torsion-free-abelian-groups-which-admits-infinitely-many-linear-group-orders). Both the question and the answer seems quite interesting and is of high qualities.

Comment: The Question was self-deleted on Aug. 14, a few days after it had been answered (and clarified in Comments on the Answer).  I've upvoted the Answer so that self-deletion is no longer an easy option.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

This question: [What does it mean system of contractions $\textbf{with overlaps}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426884/what-does-it-mean-system-of-contractions-textbfwith-overlaps) was closed as unclear. While I do think the original version was lacking context, it was only unclear if you don't know what an IFS with overlaps is. I've since edited the question to add context and recommend it here for reopening. It does have 3 reopen votes but has been stuck there for a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Based on Andrej Bauer's comments, it seems that the class of spaces discussed in "[Base having open compact members](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2191926)" is actually interesting and useful in some contexts.

I agree that the formulation of the question is not great (I did at least some minimalistic attempt to [add some context](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2191926/revisions), although probably I'd have to know more about this type of space to improve the question more). Still, I would suggest to *reopen* this question, so that the stuff which is currently only posted in comments can be better formatted and posted as an answer. (And who knows, maybe after the reopening we will here also from other users who can add something interesting.)

As you can see [on the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2191926/timeline), the question already has been through [reopen review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/878558). I have also asked [in the c.r.u.d.e chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40296789#40296789), but without getting any feedback so far.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2429821/revisions)**

I would like to request the following question be re-opened:

[Poisson process with dead time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429821/poisson-process-with-dead-time)

Earlier versions of the question were unclear and confusing. I edited the question heavily, removed extraneous text about Monte Carlo simulations, and also added a diagram for clarity. As it stands now, I think the question is quite clear. It also has an answer.

I would therefore request this question be reopened, or the close voters give more specific feedback about what needs improvement so I can improve it.

Comment: For some context, the answer accepted after reopening reads, in full: "I would have thought $T_n−T_{n−1}$ would be i.i.d. between the the two methods and over time. My simulation in R seems to confirm this." Sorry but where are the mathematics?

Comment: I filled in the mathematics in my answer. Henry's "comment answer" got me on the right track.

Comment: You are saying there is an answer to the question you asked but that it is not the answer you accepted? So sophisticated...

Comment: As I said, the "comment answer" did answer the question for me, so I accepted it, and I filled in the details. Perhaps I should accept my own answer instead? Or edit the comment answer to include my details?

Comment: Well, at this level of departure from logic, I would not dare to give any advice... :-)

Comment: Since you have >1000x more reputation than me here I do really value your advice. It sounds like you are still bitter about name-calling, so I'd like to apologize again.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about... but please let us leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

> > **Undeleted**

I would like to request undeletion of [Proof that $d^2 \phi = 2\pi \delta^{(2)}(r)dx\wedge dy$ in polar coordinates around a puncture?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2525439/16490). I saw [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27309/what-can-i-do-if-the-problem-is-deleted-when-i-tried-to-edit-my-answer) recently in meta suggesting it is frowned upon to delete a recently answered question. In my case, I was in the middle of a lengthy edit in response to a request for clarification, and feel to have the rug pulled out from under me. Thanks.

I still have the tab open in my browser, although my response is hidden under an overlay. Is there any way to recover my work in progress?

Comment: The question is probably deleted because there is a duplicate. The question should be closed anyway.

Comment: @John, it was deleted by the person who posted it, with no reason given.

Comment: @JohnMa So do you think it is not worth the effort to recover an answer to a question that is worthy of being closed?

Comment: @gerry with Ted's comment that probably the reason.

Comment: @ziggurism it depends. Your answer is of high quality but there's already an almost identical one here.

Answer (score 1):

> **Deleted** (by OP), **Undeleted**

[Matlab and the 3 Step Adams-Bashforth Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492480/matlab-and-the-3-step-adams-bashforth-method)

I just noticed, that this question got deleted by the querist. 
It took me some time to answer this question properly, as it also contains some implementation in Matlab.
IMO this question is not the best example for a question that should be asked on MSE. Still, this contribution might be helpful for other users struggling with similar issues.

If the community sees that differently, then the deletion is fine. But the OP should have never deleted that question in the first place, as he got help solving his problem, but did  return nothing..

I suggest to change the title to "Why does the Adams-Bashforth Method converge for this ODE?"
Better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

Please undo the following duplicate link by reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524886/on-mathbb-c-has-2-connected-components). The OP misread the duplicate and voted to close their question.

This question asks if the **complex** orthogonal group 
$$\{A  \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C) : A^tA = I\}$$
has two connected component. The [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085259/why-on-has-exactly-two-connected-components), however, is about real orthogonal groups. Worst still, the duplicate is also closed as a duplicate of [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100978/how-many-connected-components-does-mathrmgl-n-mathbb-r-have), which shows that $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ has two components. Of course all the method employed there will not be useful in solving the original question, since $GL(n, \mathbb C)$ is connected.

Comment: I will just add the the question already has gone through the [reopen review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/907707) as you can see [from the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2524886/timeline). BTW is it on purpose that you gave a link *[to a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524886/on-mathbb-c-has-2-connected-components#comment5213809_2524886)* instead of *[to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524886/on-mathbb-c-has-2-connected-components)*?

Comment: @MartinSleziak, No, just fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please undelete [Exterior product with coefficients from finite fields.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539626/exterior-product-with-coefficients-from-finite-fields) as I had an answer near complete when it was deleted.

Comment: OP self-deleted the question after having been told it is unclear. It is not impossible, they'll come back with a clarified question. Until then I do not see the merit of undeleting as unclear as that one, especially when even OP somehow acknowledge it is unclear.

Comment: @quid So shall I delete my nearly completed answer? Start anew if the user decides to repost the question with clearer phrasing?

Comment: I assume you could store the text somewhere (locally); if nothing else as a draft for an email or something like that. If no question is forthcoming in the near future you could use the work to create a self-answered Q&A pair.

Comment: @quid how could we tell if/when the user reposts the question?

Comment: You can follow the activity of any user on their user page; in the present case here https://math.stackexchange.com/users/493344/ You could also search for "exterior product" on the site; which is sufficiently distinctive to be helpful. I would not wait overly long, maybe a day or two.

Comment: Are you still requesting undeletion, zig?

Comment: @GerryMyerson to be honest, my unfinished answer is not quite in a state to be submitted. I hope to polish it up soon

Answer (score 1):

> **Undeleted**

Another day, another post deleted while I was halfway through a lengthy answer. This time it is [Doubt on Do Carmo proof of Gauss Formula (Isometric immersion)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544369/doubt-on-do-carmo-proof-of-gauss-formula). It's probably a self-deletion by the original poster, but I spent some time on it, so if it's reasonable please undelete.

Answer (score 1):

[Undeleted]

Please consider undeleting [Aleph and omega - were these deliberately chosen to represent infinities because of the connection between God (the alpha and the omega) and infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/644200/462)

As I [mentioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12530/462) in the [old thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6424/462), this is a reasonable reference request on whether Georg Cantor's (well documented) views on religion influenced his choice of notation. I think there are common misconceptions here, and this question may be a good place to at least start addressing them.

If undeleted, I think if nothing else we could collect the relevant comments under the question as an answer, although of course something more detailed would be even better.

(It would perhaps have made sense to edit the request in the old thread rather than posting this one here, but this is not possible since that thread was since closed as a duplicate of this one.)

Comment: Now undeleted, but notice that while it was deleted it said, "deleted by Community♦ Mar 8 '14 at 13:28 (RemoveDeadQuestions) This question was automatically deleted." So I assume it's in danger of being automatically deleted again, unless, what, it gets an upvoted answer? I can never remember exactly what it takes to make a question safe from autodelete.

Comment: Yes, thank you Gerry. I'll try to post an answer later today if no one else does first.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634510/mathematical-properties-of-natural-parameterization-of-the-exponential-family) has been inexplicably classified as "unclear what you're asking".

Convexity of the natural parameter space of an exponential family of probability distributions is a standard result introduced in standard theory-of-statistics courses.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Undeleted - Redeleted - Undeleted - Deleted - Undeleted - Reopened - Closed as duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2665553/revisions)**

[How to find? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665553/how-to-find-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n1nn1) was deleted. It is true that it has no context, other than the poster used Mathematica to get the result is $2$, but the question is a good example of changing the order of summation and telescoping series.

I think that this question, unless it is a duplicate, should be undeleted. The question is mathematically good, even though the context is a bit thin.

Comment: Your giving a hint instead of a full answer is good in my opinion, but you are a moderator, and should not be encouraging poor question generators. I'm sure you can see all the poor questions generated by this one user even till recently. If you like this question very much, you could easily post a new Q&A pair of your own with high quality, instead of leaving junk posted by others around. After all, the SE system does explicitly encourage (on the Ask-A-Question page) you to share your knowledge in the Q&A format if you are inclined to. No? =)

Comment: @user21820 Alternatively, your opinion of what merits deletion is not widely shared amongst reputable users. Hardly surprising, given the scope of the site.

Comment: @MarkMcClure  If you have something to say about the question in question (excuse pun), please state it, instead of posting off topic comments attempting to discredit another. Please stay on topic.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: We've been over this before. The proportion of users that actually **care** about the site quality is close to zero. And I am not interested in the opinions of users that do not care. Reputation or reputability is of little importance here. I have already provided a clear and viable approach for preserving good content, which nullifies any concern that deletion is harmful to good content. Incidentally, I don't think that the answer in question here is so awe-inspiring anyway... You'd have a better argument for lousy questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539174).

Comment: In fact, I voted to close but not delete that linked question, because it is so exceptional that I am happy to close my eyes. In my personal opinion, it should be protected for historical reasons, but that's another discussion.

Comment: @MarkMcClure What are the arguments to reopen, vs. reposting a much improved version of (perhaps a generalization of) the problem? Let me start with an argument against reopening: 1. **Bad example**. Up to you now...

Comment: This is a textbook example of a PSQ, which does not seem to require "exceptional handling" as this meta thread is aimed to provide.  The most interesting aspect of the question is that the OP implied they have access to Mathematica 2. The OP had no lack of time to improve the post.

Comment: @user21820 suggested reposting a better version. I have additional suggestion: We could use the existing question (visible for 10k+ users) as a place where some kind of *draft* of this better question can be made. (And the changes can be then reverted if/when the new question is posted.) I have added at least links to somewhat related questions. If there are further suggestion what else can be added so that the question no longer lacks context, they are more than welcome. (Ideally something which explains why the question should be considered interesting/useful.)

Comment: @CarlMummert: I could be wrong, but I think the poster might be saying that Mathematica returns the answer $2$, not that they are using version 2.

Comment: @robjohn: that's completely possible - but I posted a comment about it on Feb 25 and nothing was edited before the question was deleted today, suggesting that the OP was not actively participating in the question.  That also speaks in favor of deletion, IMO, when the OP does not respond to comments about the question, which looked like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2665553/1

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: In my opinion, I don't think that the links to other questions make this one better. I am interested in knowing where the OP found this series, why it is of interest, etc. - real, meaningful context, not filler context just to avoid being a PSQ.   There are numerous minor variations of every series, and they can't all be interesting just because they are a variation of some other series.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd links added by @MartinSleziak actually makes it unclear why the OP fails to solve the problem, since the current questions is easier (sorry I can't think of how to make sense of that for now).

Comment: After some searching I was able to find some book which contains this problem. I have included this in to the question - which is part of @Carl Mummert's suggestion how the question can be improved. (=Where does the question come from?)

Comment: I am not really sure whether to keep also the generalization in the question or not. And I have no problem with removing some of the links. (At least comparison to $\sum\frac1{n(n+1)}$ seemed natural to me, so I would be for including this one.) @JohnMa (and others) do you think that leaving [the first two bullet points](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2665553/8) in the current revision, perhaps with a more detailed explanation why the series converges, would count as sufficient context?

Comment: @MartinSleziak For the generalization (the one with the $k$), can it be solved using similar telescoping argument? Since no answer addressed this, I think that generalization could be an isolated (interesting) question.

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, I agree that the generalization could be a separate question. For the situation here - since we are discussing how the question linked by robjohn can be improved - the main point is whether mentioning the generalization improves the question (adds context) or, in fact, distracts from the question and is contraproductive. If I understand your comment correctly, you would be in favor of removing the generalization from *this* question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak My suggestion is that either it is removed from the current question, or (if it not removed) ask another separate question for the generalized one at the same time and link those two Qs with each other. Actually I think the latter is better, since the generalization seems to be more interesting, and linking them give more contexts to both questions.

Comment: The post has now been undeleted ([revisions](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2665553/revisions)/[timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2665553/timeline)) - perhaps a bit hastily, while the discussion what to do with the post was still going on. I have at least removed the two links which seem less relevant to the post. I'll leave further edits to others (and perhaps to the OP, but we cannot expect any action from them until the suspension ends).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: it has once again been deleted.

Comment: @robjohn If I may suggest (and you can see both from the comments above and the discussion in chat that several users find this a reasonable solution), maybe posting a new question would be way to go. And since you are the user who started this thread, you seems to be natural candidate for the poster of the question. (It goes without saying that you're free to use any material comes from my edits - I have explicitly stated a few comments above that my edits are done with the intention to created a draft for the new question.)

Comment: You're welcome to ask a new question which you so desperately want to answer, too, @robjohn.  The question was asked by a user currently suspended precisely because of their prolonged history of asking low-quality PSQs over the years (yes, years).  I would support a newly asked question, that better models a good question, which you can copy and paste your earlier answer into.  Please take the initiative to do so: custom make a model question that your answer answers.  Sometimes the quality of answers, which in this case, isn't outstanding, doesn't justify keeping a poorly asked question.

Comment: @amWhy: I am in no "desperation" to answer a question. There have been a large number of questions I have answered, but then decided not to post my answer because of the quality of the question, or because another answer was too close. This question seemed to be from someone trying the sum in Mathematica and wondering how it got the answer $2$. I provided a *hint* since the "context" was thin. I just did not see a reason to delete the question.

Comment: Well, it's good to hear that your are in no deperation, @robjohn. Cheers!

Comment: And, @robjohn, there have been an even larger number of question you have answered, and kept despite the poor quality of the question.  In any case, this site could use your time and effort for better purposes than protecting  poor quality questions.  And no, the question is not mathematically good, unless you care to provide reasons you think it is "mathematically good", other than your opinion, it can be read as a statement from someone (who answered the question) with a biased perspective.

Comment: @amWhy: I commented why I thought it was a good question: it involves a good combination of ideas like telescoping series and change of order of summation. The way the question was posed was not up to the standards imposed by the community, but that does not make the question a bad question. By the way, I am amazed that you can count "an even larger number". How did you count how many questions I answered but did not post?

Comment: @amWhy: I don't want to stoop to [ad hominem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) attacks. Please stay on topic for this comment thread and leave me to volunteer my time as I see fit.

Comment: This is ridiculously abusive. The post content is fine, it's mathematically interesting, and generated three good answers. Moreover, it's clear from amWhy's comment(s) there that the deletion is at least partially motivated by personal animosity against the poster. The question wouldn't be deleted now if it wasn't for the repetitive deletion votes of a (very!) small group of users repeatedly targeting the thread.

Comment: @robjohn  I said, quote "there have been an even larger number of question [sic] you have answered, **and kept** despite the poor quality of the question[s]. unquote.  I made no claims about questions you answered that you did not post.  So, please stop misrepresenting my words.

Comment: More users voted to delete the question than did to undelete it, @user296602, so get your facts straight?

Comment: @amWhy: "an even larger number of questions" than what? This seems to refer my statement that "There have been a large number of questions I have answered, but then decided not to post my answer because of the quality of the question, or because another answer was too close" since that is the only "large number of questions" I mentioned. I was not attempting to misrepresent your words, just questioning them.

Comment: Probably it is worth mentioning at least here that [I posted a new version of the question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=43333261#43333261). (I did link to meta post neither in the question nor in the comments under the question - I thought it is not necessary to attract additional attention to this discussion.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks (+1)

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak (+1)!

Comment: @Martin, why do you link to chat, and not directly to the new version of the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because the link I've given contains further information - by scrolling up/down in the transcript one can see the discussion in chat related to this question. (And if somebody is not in interested in the additional information, all this changes is one click more.) Since your comment suggests that you find also link [directly to the new version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685921/how-to-show-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n1nn1-2) to be useful, here it is.

Comment: I will add a link to the [post about the same question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30181#30181) in the newer reopen request thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

---

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2730780/245577) has just been deleted, and I was one of those who recommended its deletion through the review queue (as can be seen in the [review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/992230)) because it was identical to the question, and thus seemed completely useless; but I realized afterwards that the question had been edited to match the answer *after* it was posted. I have rolled back to avoid other reviewers to be confused (see also the [revision history of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2730773/revisions)), but I suspect that the other reviewers voted for the same reason, as almost all the deletion votes have been given after the question was edited.

I think it's unfair to the answerer that the answer was deleted due to a subsequent change of the question. I thus suggest that this answer get undeleted.

Comment: I undeleted. Even though the answer is not so great, but I see the point you want to make.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2691441/revisions)**

The question *[Is the function from the coefficients of a monic cubic polynomial to its least root continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691441/is-the-function-from-the-coefficients-of-a-monic-cubic-polynomial-to-its-least-r)* received an answer (from an experienced user) in half an hour after creation.  However, OP self-deleted his question shortly after that.  According to one of our site mods, this is an "[abusive behaviour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759560/extending-the-triangle-inequality#comment5694741_2759560)".  Therefore, I propose to undelete this question.

Comment: It seems that we edited [nearly at the same time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/28358/revisions) and our edits clashed. I have rolled back my edit.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for your time for editing this.  Pasting the URL of the post used to show the title link.  It seems that it no long works.  I didn't know why there's no preview while I was writing this.

Comment: I have observed on occasion an inconsistent behavior of link expansion between the preview and the post. I am not really sure when it works and when it does not. Here is a [test in the sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/18903/4) and [link to the source](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/0d18fd90-8201-4d63-b9a1-587bf2218dd2/view-source).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for your answer.  I've corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935144/how-to-use-newtons-method-to-find-the-roots-of-an-oscillating-polynomial) was initially primarily about implementing Newton's method in Matlab, and was closed as off-topic. But the specific polynomial exhibits some properties that makes it interesting from a mathematical point of view. The question has been reworded to be primarily about math, and the existing answer addresses the math question. I'd like for it to be reopened.

By the way, the question has been on the starboard for four days at [Reopen? Undelete? Close? Delete?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete). I think most people interested in this meta thread would also be interested in that chat room.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160252/equation-with-sum-of-factorial-and-subfactorial) was closed as "unclear what you're asking." I edited it into standard mathematical notation so that the question is unambiguous. The question does not appear otherwise off-topic (I'll certainly accept having found the trivial solutions as context). The question interests me and I would like it reopened.

(I am unsure of why the [review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/359658) responded so negatively to the question)

Comment: I said leave closed because it just said I found this and this without showing any work and then requested how to do it. To me, that is like saying what is some integral I found it to be x. We know they can probably use Mathematica to get the value so what have they really done?

Comment: @dustin Thanks for your reply; it is good to get a response from someone who reviewed it. (I also realized, looking at the review dates, you would almost certainly have reviewed [this revision](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1160252/2), which has severe formatting issues too)

Comment: I can't remember which version I saw. I just knew why I wouldn't choose reopen. If it said I did this with work and obtained this, I would have said okay.

Answer (score 0):

> **Deleted**

Recently a reference/book request question was put on hold as too broad. However, we have allowed and currently still allow these questions since older and newer questions aren't being put on hold. For this reason, I request [books on math bio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180283/books-about-mathematical-biology/) be reopened unless we are now closing all other book/ reference post as well.

Comment: The question is unreasonably broad. OP does not even say anything at all about their general background in math.

Comment: @Quid that is exactly how almost all the reference request are.

Comment: Then we should  close them too. However, let me also add that the math background thing is less of an issue when somebody asks about, say, an intro to abstract algebra. But for this question it is really key to know of OP knows statsitics, (P)DE, dynamical systems, etc. or not.

Comment: For example that one, while really not great, is a lot more specific http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180720/which-book-should-i-read-to-prepare-the-vector-analysis in that it mentions a beginning physics background. This one is better too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180124/complex-analysis-textbook-advise

Comment: @quid when i am not on my phone i will link well received overly broad requests.

Comment: Great. I will keep the close-votes handy.

Comment: @quid the complex one you linked should probably closed as dupe since there are a bunch on it.

Comment: I don't know. Very possible. My point was only it gives a lot more details and background.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened, Reclosed**

So, OP edited "context" into [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192043/check-whether-a-function-is-one-to-one-and-onto) and two hours later it got put on hold anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

[Topology of sets - prove or disprove the following statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193766/topology-of-sets-prove-or-disprove-the-following-statements) was originally posted without any context or signs of effort. After others complained in the comments,  OP actually *fixed the question*,  explaining their thoughts on the problems,  all of which were well-considered. This is a good outcome, all too rare, which we should encourage!

But then the question was closed anyway, belying the commenters who asked for clarification.

Let's reopen.

Comment: I think only the last vote came after the edit, which appears to be an anomaly.  (By the way, it is possible the review queue would have taken care of this.  You could wait a while after voting to reopen to see if there's a reason to still post here.)

Comment: Just so that everyone knows, there are online OCR tools that convert images to text. You still need to correct the formulas, but it significantly reduces the time needed to do it. In this case, it took me about a minute (plus a few seconds to add linebreaks in the last paragraph). Compare the two scenarios: a question formatted like this one was arrives in the reopen RQ, vs. a question formatted like this one is now arrives in the RQ...

Comment: @Najib I would very much appreciate pointers to some of those tools; I spend a lot of time inlining scans and screenshots.

Comment: I used http://www.onlineocr.net/ in this case, I only had to correct the formulas. I don't know how well it works for larger bodies of text.

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted,** **Redeleted**

What was the point of deleting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106624/finding-an-f-automorphism-having-specified-the-images-of-two-elements ? Is the website really better without the mathematical content in the answer to that question, than with it?

Comment: The question is unclear and missing context. It would be preferable, IMO, to start from scratch and post a new question with explicit hypotheses, since OP isn't around to clarify anymore.

Comment: The thread is quite confusing. I am not sure how I would vote myself. But,  arguably, somebody interested in the subject is better served finding/reading something other than those posts.

Comment: Curious. It was autodeleted shortly after my vote undeleted it.

Comment: Yes, that's very strange. I didn't think the Community user acted that fast, @Matt.

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted**

Could [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765090/unitary-farey-sequence-matrices) be undeleted, since it related to several other questions I had (see "Linked Questions" section)...

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

[Relation between number of unique values in Gramian Matrix (G) and the matrices that created it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319877/relation-between-number-of-unique-values-in-gramian-matrix-g-and-the-matrices#comment2690506_1319877) got closed in spite of the clarifications made in the comments.  The clarifications have now been incorporated in the post, and further improvements made.  It should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

Did marked [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347332/if-x-y-and-z-are-independent-are-x-and-yz-independent) a duplicate. Why is it a duplicate?

I think e is answering a question using a fact asked about in another question. How does that make my question a duplicate?

Before the marking, I got an answer and accepted it. That there was this really long answer that was unrelated to what was suggested by Did seems to suggest my question was not a duplicate.

Comment: Posts in this thread [should not be deleted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio/21084#comment75491_19918) if they lead to any kind of action, to keep the record visible.

Comment: For [some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21950/).

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted**, **Reopened**, **Reclosed**, **Reopened**

Please undelete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342616/what-is-an-interesting-integer-and-are-there-uninteresting-integers) because:

- Qiaochu Yuan's answer is of (very) high quality. It is relevant in many senses and canonical for this kind of problems (which are not so rare on the site).
- The two answers + OP totalise 33 upvotes and 3 downvotes. So apparently the question is appreciated by the community.

Comment: Slightly ironically you link to *your* answer not the question, while not mentioning at all that one of the two answers is yours. (It is not possible to use at-notify in the way you seem to want to use it. Even if you are aware of this it is not a good idea to use the syntax as it can confuse others into believing it in fact does work.)

Comment: @quid you are right, it is because I copy-pasted the url and accessed it from my profile. I have no problem to mention that one answer is mine but I don't think that the question should be reopened because of that. Nevertheless I still think it should be reopened for Quiaochu's answer.

Comment: @quid regarding the notification: ok I'll avoid that next time.

Comment: A problem I see with that Q&A is that while Qiaochu's answer should be a good answer to the question "Is every natural number interesting?" or something like this, it appears it is quite explicitly *not* what is asked for. Rather the question is about one specific number. (I have not voted on this myself either way. Certainly, there are worse things on this site.) // Thanks for following up on my other remarks.

Comment: @quid If the question doesn't get reopened, maybe it could be a not too bad idea to create question fitting the answer and copy-past the answer in this question (everything in CW obviously).

Comment: Yes this seems like a good idea (assuming something like this does not exists already, which I do not know).

Comment: I'm sorry but is the question no longer opinion-based? Did you do anything at all to improve the *question*? Note that the popularity of a question has nothing to do with its appropriateness for the website, and it's dishonest to simply add up the scores of the Q and each A, as someone can simply upvote all three -- does this mean that it's three times as popular? And if indeed this sort of problem is "not so rare", then I'm sure you can find a good example of question where Qiaochu Yuan's answer can be transferred.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's a good point, I'll try to improve the question this weekend.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi So I tried to edit the question and hope it can be considered on-topic now.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

Please reopen [Finding Nash equilibrium in game with random event at event tree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394523). After the first vote to close as duplicate was cast, the OP pointed out that this question is about a different game. This is immediately confirmed by a look at the image linked to in the post (which the OP can't include in the post due to lack of reputation). The question was nevertheless closed as a duplicate.

This is particularly unfortunate since it was good style on the part of the OP to ask a new question about this new game instead of continuing to ask me new questions in the comment thread under my answer to the old question. Closing this new question disincentivizes this constructive behaviour.

Comment: I saw that question in the review queue, but it lacks any context for why the (new) game in question is of interest, so it would still qualify for closing under that reason, even if it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened, Reclosed as a duplicate**

[A matrix is positive if and only if it is Hermitian and its eigenvalues are positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400002/a-matrix-is-positive-if-and-only-if-it-is-hermitian-and-eigenvalues-are-positive)

For real matrices the statement in the question is incorrect. However, the question is actually quite interesting for the case of complex matrices. According to a recent edit, the author of the question is interested in this complex case.

This question is highly relevant to anyone out there on the internet who is contemplating:

1. the various definitions of positive definiteness and how they relate to each other, and
2. how a matrix could be positive definite over the reals, but the same matrix is not positive definite over the complex numbers.

This is the sort of question that math.stackexchange needs to have a canonical answer to, for the benefit of the internet community.

---

*Edit:* This question is **not** a duplicate of the [linked one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561461/how-to-show-that-a-hermitian-matrix-is-positive-definite-if-all-eigenvalues-ar) given by Najib Idrissi in the comments. I think many people who originally voted to close misread it as such. The other question seeks to prove the following two assertions:

1. $\text{Hermitian} + \text{positive eigenvalues} \implies \text{positive definite}$, and
2. $\text{Hermitian} + \text{positive definite} \implies \text{positive eigenvalues}.$

This is a trivial application of the Spectral theorem, and a question commonly asked on homeworks in undergraduate linear algebra classes.

On the other hand, the actual question seeks to prove a very different assertion:

3. $\text{positive definite} + \text{field is complex} \implies \text{Hermitian}$.

This is more interesting question, and requires a clever trick to prove (as explained in my comment on the question). Indeed, if the field of vectors used to test the positive definiteness is only real, then the assertion is false, as the following real-positive-definite matrix demonstrates:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\bar{a} & \bar{b}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = (a+b)^2 \ge 0, \quad a,b \in \mathbb{R},$$

whereas we can see that it is not complex-positive-definite by choosing $a=i, b=1$,

$$\begin{bmatrix}-i & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}i \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = 2 - 2i \notin \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: "For real matrices the statement in the question is incorrect." Is the adjective "Hermitian" commonly used (or indeed used at all) for real matrices? Anyway that question is unsurprisingly a duplicate, see eg http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561461/how-to-show-that-a-hermitian-matrix-is-positive-definite-if-all-eigenvalues-ar

Comment: The question itself is a PSQ. If the goal of the OP was to have a canonical answer, the first step should be to write a canonical question, that includes adequate background and motivation.

Comment: @CarlMummert To me it looks like a precisely written question, not a PSQ. I really doubt it's from homework since it's is too hard for an undergrad linear algebra class, and a "left to the interested reader" type question that wouldn't be asked as homework in a graduate functional analysis class. Also, if you read the comments to the deleted answer, the author says his motivation is trying to understand the connection between two different definitions of positive definiteness.

Comment: Everyone who followed the same curriculum as I did could have definitely solved this question in undergrad (by the end of the second year after high school). It only takes the spectral theorem for Hermitian matrices... "PSQ" means "Problem statement question", i.e. a question which consists of nothing more than a problem statement -- this has nothing to do with precision. And again, the question is a duplicate anyway and will be closed as such as soon as it's reopened: what's the point?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It is not a duplicate of the question you link, it is more interesting. See the edit to the meta post above for details.

Comment: Well then, I edited the question to include that important piece of *context*. It's easy to miss on a first reading (I did, anyway), and I think it really adds to the value of the question, in addition to population the "Linked Questions" sidebar.

Comment: To the two people who cast a reopen vote: did you go to the *new* duplicate target? It's not the same as before.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Nope, must have been someone else who voted. It is indeed a duplicate of the new target.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I think two people just voted to reopen as a knee-jerk reaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound awfully strange, but I would like for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561033/evaluate-int-01-int-p1-frac-x3-sqrt1-y6-dydx/561042#561042) to be undeleted.  Not in spite of it being a bad answer, but because it is an exemplary bad answer. I have linked to this answer twice (I think) in meta as an example of why mindless CAS sales-pitch solutions are not only annoying, but dangerously misleading.

Comment: I really don't think that being an "exemplary bad answer" is a good reason to keep an answer on the site. Quite the opposite, actually.

Comment: You can reproduce it here, or in the drafts sandbox, then you will have a permanent link.

Comment: OK, thanks. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened, then marked as duplicate**

Please consider reopening this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437564/proving-ab2015-e-implies-ba2015-e):

- The Latex has been fixed,
- the OP has given a good try, and
- it has a decent answer.

Comment: The question is also a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238212/is-it-true-that-the-order-of-ab-is-always-equal-to-the-order-of-ba .

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

[Conditions for the convergence of two sorted vectors of samples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465705/conditions-for-the-convergence-of-two-sorted-vectors-of-samples)

I think it was clear enough what was being said even though at least two things (one of which I mentioned above) were not as well expressed as they could have been. In its current state, the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

Please consider reopening [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510569/reflexivity-vs-finite) question. For now it is closed as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554408/finite-dimensional-c-algebras) question.

The closed question is a special case of the linked duplicate. Unfortunately, both the question and the answer in the linked duplicate use languages from $C^*$-algebra which is not needed at all to answer the closed question. Consider that the closed question are much more elementary and can be answered using knowledge covered in a first graduate course in real analysis, it should be reopened (or at least, not closed as a duplicate of that linked question. I have the feeling that this question has been asked before).

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted**

I added an answer to [this (4 day old) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513982/looking-for-a-quick-randomish-way-to-map-1-n-to-1-n-and-back) and right after this OP deleted the question.

I think it's a decent answer and hopefully this is not an acceptable practice.

Comment: Not really acceptable practice.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1529600/57159) was originally trivial (I was one of the close-voters), but the OP
subsequently clarified that they wanted geodesic distance on the sphere rather
than Euclidean distance, and I edited that clarification into the question.

Comment: I don't understand what "representing these points in 4 dimensions" means, and I don't understand what $d_{new}$ is supposed to be. I think the question still needs clarification.

Comment: Is [version 6](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1529600/6) sufficiently clear? ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

[Is the recurrent sequence $a_{n+1}=\arcsin (a_n)$ converging?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571416) was closed for missing context. However, the question was [answered by the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1571580), which shows their attempt and where they are having a problem.  Although this information might better be added to the question, I think that this provides more than sufficient context and that this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

[Is $\#^k \Bbb{RP}^2 \times I$, $\Bbb{RP}^2$-irreducible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1602901/98602)

This was closed as unclear, but there is nothing unclear about it. Maybe it used language unclear to the non-specialist. I edited the title and body a little bit to clear up any confusion that seemed possible.

Answer (score 0):

> **Deleted**

Request for reopening: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595644/how-do-i-integrate-square-root-of-a-rational-function

The question was closed as too broad, and has since been clarified to ask only for when there is an elementary antiderivative.  I don't know much about how to answer the question, but it seems like this is a focused enough question to be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Reopened, Closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1660490/revisions)**

The question [Quadrilateral with maximum area inside a semicircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660490/quadrilateral-with-maximum-area-inside-a-semicircle) is in my opinion an interesting question. If the main reason for closing with missing context reason was the lack of work shown by the OP, then it is worth pointing out that the OP posted their own attempt as an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660490/quadrilateral-with-maximum-area-inside-a-semicircle/1660572#1660572). So I think that this question might be reopened.

(I am aware that today's post by the same OP had some comments which were a bit unpleasant. But maybe we can judge the posts by their own merit and not based on the OP. Moreover, the reaction of the OP might have been caused by the reason that as an inexperienced user they are not that familiar with how the site works - especially putting on hold and reopening. So they might have felt that putting the question on hold was in some sense unfair.)

Comment: This is a post that is written in a very low-quality manner by an OP who is still active. Rather than re-opening the question before it is fixed, we should wait for the OP to improve it. I don't know anything about the comments by the OP, but if they wish to post a question and immediately answer it, the question itself needs to be composed as a high-quality post, including good motivation of the problem

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened, reclosed**

I think [Two i.i.d random variables inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690434/two-i-i-d-random-variables-inequality) should be reopened. The OP has given their approach to the first part of the question, and would like help with the second.

This question has received a decent amount of interest in comments since its closing. I think its answers would be of interest.

Comment: It has only been closed for 9 hours. Why not give the OP some time to improve the question?  I see that, unfortunately, nobody has used the (undeleted) comments to encourage the OP to do that.

Comment: The fact that this was an interview question had been given in the title, but it was removed after closure. The OP tells what they used to solve the first part; however, it seems that they have no idea how to approach the second part. If that is so, then I guess they can't add much and they are out of luck here. I have added some comments on how to proceed. We'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Matrix equation with transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1696584/3060)

This is a question about a linear system where the unknown is a matrix. As someone who has some experience with systems like this, the question as written was perfectly clear and interesting to me.

I assume that people who voted to close tried to understand the question in the normal linear algebra context where the unknown is a vector, got confused, and therefore assumed the question was unclear.

Comment: It seems that Gerry has made an edit to that question to clarify the notation. However it might not be good enough. I am happy to reopened it if someone (the OP would be in the best position to do that) make an authoriative definition of what $X-2$ is.

Comment: Err, although well-intentioned, I think the edit made the question worse. First, the exact size of the matrix is irrelevant and over-specific. Second, whether '2' represents two times identity or the matrix full of twos (or any other matrix, actually) is also irrelevant since it doesn't change the structure of the problem or the solution method; that matrix only enters the problem as right hand side data.

Comment: I see you have edited the question, Nick, which is a good thing. I take it that it's not important whether the matrices are invertible?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think the most general requirement is that $I \otimes A^T - C^T \otimes B$ has full column rank. If the input matrices are square and invertible that would be sufficient, of course, but much less interesting. In optimal control problems you sometimes get matrix equations similar to this where the matrices are not square.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

Please vote for the reopening of this question: [Give an example of a commutative von Neumann regular ring which is not a product of fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805338/give-an-example-of-a-commutative-regular-ring-which-is-not-a-product-of-fields).

The OP has provided some context, and want to see what's going on whether a part of the hypothesis is dropped, which I find a legitimate question. Moreover, as it is now the question has a wrong answer, the answerer making a confusion between regular and [Von Neumann Regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) rings. But under the question there is a comment providing a good answer, and I think we have to give the commenter the opportunity to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Re-opened, on hold again, re-re-opened, on hold, locked, unlocked, re-re-re-opened, on hold yet again, deleted.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840890/probability-of-getting-2016-20162016-to-infinity-after-dividing

The expressed objections to this question are silly.  The poster is asking for an explanation of what apparently struck the poster as a very surprising phenomenon.  The poster is very obviously not familiar with the technical definitions of "probability" and related terms as used by mathematicians.  To construe that word exactly the way mathematicians do when reading things written by other mathematicians is silly.  To ask the user to specify the probability distribution is far beyond silly; it is the height of absurdity.

People post without knowing mathematicians' jargon.  Participants should get used to that.

This is a good question and it's perfectly clear if one bears in mind the things I said above.

Comment: The etiquette, as far as I can see that it has been established in the recent years, is to refrain from posting here* until the question has gone through the usual reopening process (e.g. entering the queue and giving people time to vote). Indeed, the post was edited and reopened less than 50 minutes after you posted here, and was reopened 65 minutes after it was closed. This post is now noise that could have been avoided by waiting an hour. $$$$ *Unless the point of the answer is to complain about the closure - but this thread is designed to not be used for debate.

Comment: It is in fact not inconceivable that by posting it here, you drew more attention to it and it got reclosed as a consequence, as just happened.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : Do you have some idea WHY it was closed the second time?  It remains a good question. $\qquad$

Comment: @T.Bongers : I was not aware of any rule of etiquette saying one shouldn't post here until some other (more "usual" as you call it) reopening process is complete.  Where would I have learned of such a rule?  As far as I knew, I was using this thread for its intended purpose. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't say it's a hard and fast rule - it's just the mores that  have been established in the multiple years that these threads have run. It's been mentioned, e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio/23539?noredirect=1#comment94212_23521) most recently. Not every reopening merits the time or effort of a meta post - especially not when it has only been closed for 15 minutes (and was reopened an hour later...). I also think Najib is likely right in their assessment of how it was reclosed.

Comment: It remains the same question (up to a trivial edit whose purpose was to put the question in the review queue, guess) that five users had already voted to close. It's not really productive to pretend everyone has the same standards as you do and act confused when it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I went through the same experience; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21409) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21411).

Comment: All: Sorry about disturbing the process. I locked the question for a while in response to a flag indicating a close/reopen war. That was a knee-jerk response to halt the skirmish forcefully. You are now welcome to continue your brawl, if you judge that to be the prudent thing to do.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Needs some more undelete votes.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened.**

The question [Is $X\simeq [0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862612/is-x-simeq-0-1) should be reopen. To anybody who knows anything about Bing-style geometric topology, it's clear that the question is not a homework problem but an attempt to come up with a new characterization of the closed unit interval (up to a homeomorphism). The proposed characterization is similar to the standard one, which is discussed in Henno Brandsma's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322411/topological-characterization-of-the-closed-interval-0-1/322519#322519) but does not appear to follow from it.

Comment: I did not vote on the question and would not, but the critique made is exactly that the question does not give enough context. Your post here gives context. It would be more efficient to include the context on main, and to signal it here in a neutral way, rather than to make a somewhat dismissive post here.

Comment: The OP has not improved the post in the 2 days since it was asked, so it seems that they have little interest in having it re-opened.

Comment: @quid If people understood that, 90% of this thread wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Re-opened**

Request to reopen the question [If $p + q = 1$ prove that for any natural $n, m$ following is true: $(1 - p^n)^m + (1 - q^m)^n \ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049852/if-p-q-1-prove-that-for-any-natural-n-m-following-is-true-1-pnm/) since:

- User described his effort
- The question is interesting by itself
- It has a decent answer already

Answer (score 0):

**Re-opened**

[Proving without Zorn's Lemma additive group of the reals is isomorphic to the additive group of the complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114241/proving-without-zorns-lemma-additive-group-of-the-reals-is-isomorphic-to-the-ad)

This Question is closed as *duplicate* of [Is it true that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic as abelian groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145163/is-it-true-that-mathbbr-and-mathbbr2-are-isomorphic-as-abelian-groups)  Although intrinsically related, the newer Question asks if (for the sake of simplicity) one might avoid using Zorn's lemma (to exhibit bases over the rationals of equal cardinality) as the earlier Question discusses.

Since the point of the Question was from the beginning a *follow up* to the proof offered in the duplicate, I'd like to see this reopened.  It already has a cogent (and accepted) answer, but possibly there is more to be said.

Comment: Should that question perhaps also be tagged ([tag:axiom-of-choice])? ("Without Zorn's Lemma" can be also interpreted as "without AC". Although it is not clear whether this is what the OP intended.)

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened, deleted by Community ♦, then undeleted**

I would like to re-open [*Real Analysis: Uniform Continuity [on hold]*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2129885/290189) (question deleted) since the author *has shown his work* after my comment.  There's no reason to block this question now.

Comment: Did you have an inclination to answer this reopened Question?

Comment: Yes, I *had*, but we should judge solely on the question body itself---OP has a doubt but he had ask*ed* in a wrong way.  After he corrected this (by adding more context), he should no longer be stopped.

Comment: My point is the Question is reopened, as you asked,  so now an Answer can be posted.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that.  Sorry that I misunderstand your point.  I'll try it later if I've time.

Comment: One month after the question was reopened...

Comment: Please do not erase the link to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> [Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1078755/revisions)

There is a great deal of useful information in an answer to [Collections of undergraduate research projects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078755/collections-of-undergraduate-research-projects)

I would like to see the question undeleted, to save that information.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2145597/revisions)**

This [deleted Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145597/maximize-p-a2b2c2abacbc) was deleted after being closed as it had shown no effort.

However, after discussing it with the user @WordShallow [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54562/discussion-between-s-c-b-and-word-shallow), I added the solution he had attempted into the question.

I request that this question be undeleted.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reclosed** as dupe

Request for reopening: [Let $A=3^{105} + 4^{105}$. Show that $7\mid A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261723/a-problem-dealing-with-number-theory)

It has been closed as duplicate of [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by a+b when n is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd), which is currently closed as well.

If OP had recognized that his question, in short "Show that if $A=3^{105} + 4^{105}$, then $7\mid A$", was a particular case of the question "[Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by a+b when n is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd)", then indeed it would be appropriated to consider it a duplicate. But what if he or other future user had not?

Since I tend to consider the latter question as an *abstract* duplicate question, rather than a truly duplicate one, I am in favor of reopening the question [Let $A=3^{105} + 4^{105}$. Show that $7\mid A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261723/a-problem-dealing-with-number-theory)

ADDED. All the four existing answers to the question [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by a+b when n is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd) solve the problem using algebra-precalculus concepts, while the OP of [A problem dealing with number theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261723/a-problem-dealing-with-number-theory) tryied to solve it using congruences.

Comment: The general opinion is that specific cases can be closed when an abstract duplicate exists; see [Coping with abstract duplicate questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756) and [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868).

Comment: @epimorphic There is also [this opinion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3760/752): "One of the reasons we get the same question over and over is people who are learning new concepts cannot tell if two problems are essentially the same.", which I agree with.

Comment: That's an attempt to explain why such questions pop up over and over again. I don't see futurebird advocating that lone specific cases (which is what's in contention here) should be kept open.

Comment: @epimorphic Let's see if OP has any reaction. One of the things that occurs here is that both questions, the specific one and the more general one are closed and the latter is not listed in the [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions).

Comment: Another fact that weighs in favor of reopening (it has gotten a couple more close votes since being reopened!) is that the OP made an unsuccessful attempt to solve/prove by factoring.  I'm sympathetic with attempts to show that the gist of such attempts can be made successful with rework.

Comment: @Bill I am confused by your edit. It appears you just "marked as duplicate" the question.  Is this an oversight or did I miss some subtlety.

Comment: @quid The subtlety is the real-world - I was pulled away from the computer before I had a chance to return to meta and update this question. Now done.

Comment: Generally I prefer *not* to close specific cases when they are amenable to special techniques that prove pedagogically useful. But that is not the case here.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the reply and the edit. I did not realize at first that your first edit predates your closure by small but still non-negligible time (as opposed to the two being essentially done at the same time).

Comment: @quid Yes, I edited the meta question to fix the syntax, then decided to have a closer look at the question. Eventually I agreed with Lab's decision that it is a dupe, so reclosed it about 18 minutes later (I wasted some time looking for better dupes and was sidetracked by other tasks in the interim).

Answer (score 0):

[Deleted, 14 May 2017.]

I have voted to reopen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275568/let-%CE%BE-1-and-%CE%BE-2-be-two-independent-random-variables-with-gaussian-distributi?noredirect=1#comment4681187_2275568) because comments under the question show that the poster has exerted some effort and does understand the question. Moreover, answers can be calibrated to the level of effort or the particular aspect that the poster wonders about.

Comment: Deleting the comments. Nothing to see here. Move on.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened.**

I would like this question to be reopened 
[Prove or disprove that a graph made by $n$ straight lines is Hamiltonian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297246/prove-or-disprove-that-a-graph-made-by-n-straight-lines-is-hamiltonian)
I have made corrections to the question and have mentioned my efforts which was the reason for closing this. Some other users were also questioning for this to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

This Question was initially put on-hold for missing context:

[Calculating determinant $a_{ij}=x_{i}y_{j}$ if $i=j$ and $1+x_{i}y_{j}$ if $i\neq j$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351625/calculating-determinant-a-ij-x-iy-j-if-i-j-and-1x-iy-j-if-i)

Soon after the OP explained their approach/progress in a Comment, which I have added into the body of the Question.

Please consider reopening.  Although closely related to other Questions involving rank one updates of diagonal matrices (see *abstract duplicate* linked there), this Question has some novelty because it amounts to rank two update of a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Re-opened.

[Value/Cost of numbers from average intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378149/value-cost-of-numbers-from-average-intervals)

The reason for closing this was "This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center."; there was nothing about missing context or details.

I posted [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378149/value-cost-of-numbers-from-average-intervals#comment4903267_2378149) under the question: "I think this should be construed as 'How many points is it worth paying to get a particular number as one of the five?'."

For example, if you give up one point to fix one of the five numbers at $0.3,$ is the expected number of points you you will score more than $1$? If so, then the value of $0.3$ is more than $1.$

Clearly this is a mathematical question.

Answer (score 0):

[Reopened] [and ready for more appropriate reclosure]

Please consider reopening [$2^n + 1$ is prime $ \implies n$ is a power of $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393990/2n-1-is-prime-implies-n-is-a-power-of-2), possibly so that it can be linked (one way or the other) to a more appropriate duplicate.  Given the "proof verification" nature of the Question, I could also see it being considered not a duplicate.

It is obviously about Fermat primes, but it was closed as a duplicate of [this older Question about Mersenne primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319963/if-2n-1-is-prime-from-some-integer-n-prove-that-n-must-also-be-prime).

The OP was actually having difficulty relating the proposition to "contradiction of the contrapositive," and Robert Israel gave a good Answer to clear that up.

A valid older duplicate might be:

[Fermat primes relation to $2^n+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491830/fermat-primes-relation-to-2n1)

> If $2^n+1$ is prime how to show that  $n$ must be a power of $2$

Answer (score 0):

> Deleted by Roomba

Asking for more opinions about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2437734/11619).

The question nominally looks like a question about Matlab and its handling of infinity/NaN. It may turn out that the problems are, indeed, there. But in my somewhat expert opinion there are other possible explanations to the observed quirks in the behavior of the Belief Propagation algorithm.

Because [coding-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory) is on-topic at our site, in my opinion this question could also be on-topic at Math.SE in spite of appearances to the contrary.

Comment: I am dropping the matter - closed+deleted it is :-). Thank you for your votes/opinions. Undeleting this request in case it helps users with <10k to gauge the success rate of similar future requests :-)

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened, [Re-closed], Deleted (https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2538958/revisions)**

I  propose that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2538958/465208) be reopened. I understand that there are already four votes to reopen. But since the question is about the free product of groups, I expect that many users will skip it, even some group theorists. Thus the number of users who are likely to see and evaluate it will probably be small reducing the likelihood of getting a fifth vote to reopen.

The question asks how to apply a Theorem, which the OP states explicitly, to prove a corollary, which is also stated explicitly. The proof of the corollary involves a simple substitution. It is the kind of thing that one may see quickly or completely miss. Thus there is little additional "context" which the OP could provide.

On the other hand, one can assume that since the OP is working in free products, he or she, will be able to understand the easy solution. So, additional context is not needed for that purpose.

Comment: The context could easily include the context where the OP encountered the problem (i.e. its source), the background and interest of the theorem, or why the OP is interested in proving the corollary in the first place.

Comment: @CarlMummert I agree, but how would it help in this case? And it would only serve to make a short question longer.

Comment: !Stephen Meskin: This has been discussed at length, but newer users may not know just how much length the discussion has taken. For example, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201/630 and links from there.

Comment: @CarlMummert That is an interesting string. I could only read a small fraction of it at this time. From what I read,, it seems like there are alternative views. The comment that got to me was by Alexander Gruber of Apr 26 '13. Not withstanding the pros and cons of the issue, I cannot tell whether a conclusion was reached and, if so where to find a list of such conclusions. Moreover, I think the statement describing the reason for closure can be misinterpreted. I have mentioned these issues in another post. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27449/465208     But we are getting off topic.

Comment: !Stephen Meskin: the nature of this site is that a clear conclusion is rarely reached - the number of enforceable policies is extremely small.  There are some people who are OK with PSQ posts, but many people are not.  Whether a particular PSQ post is closed often depends on who looks at it. But in general the way for someone to avoid the closure like this one is just to write a more self-contained post, with some background, motivation, and sourcing.  In this case the OP  *had the theorem and corollary already stated* but did not say where they were from.

Comment: @CarlMummert I'm beginning to discern the *nature* of this site. It will take a while. I have edited the post in question with a reference to a prior post on a closely related question which except for a few unrelated personal statements is of the same format and level, but doesn't seem to have received even one downvote. or flag. Should we not have a bit of consistency?

Comment: @Carl, what is the function of the exclamation mark you are putting in front of Stephen's name?

Comment: @CarlMummert My edit didn't seem to take. The reference was https://math.stackexchange.com/q/346802/465208 I think this reference also gave some context to the question since the referenced question gave the source of the the Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

> Undeleted

[Vector fields pointing from one fiber to another - Notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547484/vector-fields-pointing-from-one-fiber-to-another-notation/2547493?noredirect=1) was deleted while I was substantially editing an answer to address followup questions by the original poster. Please undelete.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

I was among those who voted to close [Integrating to find mass and centre of mass](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544709/integrating-to-find-mass-and-centre-of-mass), but the OP has now supplied by Edit a good account of their attempt and some specifics of the confusion that needs to be cleared up by a good Answer.

Please consider voting to Reopen, as I have.

Answer (score 0):

> Undeleted

[Prove cf(α)≤|α| if α is a limit ordinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564426/prove-cf%ce%b1%e2%89%a4%ce%b1-if-%ce%b1-is-a-limit-ordinal)

Was deleted shortly after receiving an answer, and halfway through me typing mine. The question itself is certainly valid. So it might be the OP trying to hide asking online.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened**

I propose that this question be reopened: [Why is the fact that a quotient group is a group relevant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565113/why-is-the-fact-that-a-quotient-group-is-a-group-relevant) This question was closed as being a duplicate of the question [Why the term and the concept of quotient group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69050/why-the-term-and-the-concept-of-quotient-group) However, the questions are completely different, as can be seen by the huge differences in the types of answers. One question asks "why is the idea of a quotient group like division?", while the other asks "why do I care that a quotient group is a group?"...

Answer (score 0):

> Reopened

I would like to ask you to consider reopening this question: [How to prove this interesting inequality: $\frac{5x+3y+z}{5z+3y+x}+\frac{5y+3z+x}{5x+3z+y}+\frac{5z+3x+y}{5y+3x+z}\ge 3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2617527)

Originally, it was in rather bad shape, it contained basically just the problem statement and a link to a picture - which is why it was closed and deleted. With the help of other users the OP improved the question (MathJax, source of the problem). So I think it looks much better now than it did originally. And the question was already undeleted.

I will add that the question already [went through reopen review queue once](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/942669) - it was before the edits. Since the edits were made [while the question was deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2617527/revisions), I assume those edits will not push it into reopen review queue.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened** and then **merged** with an older question ([revisions](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1118030/revisions)/[timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1118030/timeline))

I think this question should be reopened: [Polynomial equation $f(x)f(2x^2)=f(2x^3+x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118030)

For starters, the question was open for 2 years and has only just been closed. Secondly, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600903) question, which is *not* lacking context or other details, was closed as a duplicate of the above. So noone can answer the good question because it has been closed as a duplicate of a (now-closed!) bad question.

This is a silly state of affairs and I think it should be fixed.

Comment: It seems okay to undelete the second one and then merge the two.

Comment: @John I have no idea how to do that! (I am guessing its a 20k+ privilege though!)

Comment: Actually only mods can do that.

Comment: To add to John Ma's comment - 20k+ users can vote to undelete, moderators can merge.

Comment: @JohnMa I am not sure whether the merging is still needed, since the linked question [has been reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1118030/revisions). In any case, I have edited the deleted one - so that the notation is the same and they can be merged: [Solve $f(x)f(2x^2) = f(2x^3+x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2600903) (Of course, the edit can be reverted if they are not going to be merged.)

Comment: And there is a third copy posted today - which is (quite deservedly) getting close votes and downvotes: [Solve $P(x)*P(2x^2) = P(2x^3+1)$ I know this is a duplicate question but I cannot find the original](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2619120).

Comment: My feeling is that merging give the question a little bit more protection from closure deletion, since the deleted one provides more contexts. @martinsleziak

Comment: I would suggests to [continue this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2018/1/24). Mainly to avoid leaving too many comments under this post.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

I am requesting that this question be reopened: [Why is group theory axiomatized with operations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2654537)

I believe that the reason for closure is tied up in the first comment, which basically says "I have never seen this definition of a group before, therefore I do not know what you are talking about!". But...this definition *is* used (as I point out in the comments).

(I have also edited the question, as discussed in the comments below.)

Comment: That's a misrepresentation. More to the point, there is also a comment 'You said "bla bla bla", but what are the axioms that you're not understanding?' Indeed, OP should include (an example of) the definition they ask about. Further, you should link to the question not to your answer.

Comment: @quid Sorry about the link - I had just copied-and-pasted the URL I was at.

Comment: @quid w.r.t. the "blah blah blah" comment, I see your point. I ignored this comment as the "blah blah blah" axioms are associativity, identity and inverses - that is, the 3 axioms common to both definitions. However, I still think the question should be reopened.

Comment: The question is needlessly unclear. Why cannot OP (or anybody for that matter, say, you) include the axioms,  or at least that closure axiom in the question? It's a poorly phrased question with a ???? in it, and the cdot is not formatted correctly. First fix the question, then ask for reopening. There is no justification to insinuate it was closed because it was not understood. There is enough reason to close it while it is understood *because* it is poorly explained and thus needlessly hard to understand.

Comment: I had just logged on to delete my second comment, above, before you saw it, and with the intention of editing the question in the morning :-) I will edit the question in the morning...

Comment: That's great. I am looking forward to the edit.

Comment: @quid I've edited it now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was not online. I cast the last vote.

Answer (score 0):

**undeleted, autodeleted**

I nominate [this definite integral problem](//math.stackexchange.com/q/2640088/290189) for undeletion and reopening because OP has shown effort (by making $u$-substitution) in solving the problem and it contains a self-answer with a *positive* score.

The moment when some other user(s) upvoted an answer, it carries their recognition, so [*it's not entirely the property of the owner*](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/74469/259305).

Comment: Actually it seems pointless to undelete an unclear question, that the question-er [are not coming back](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640088/integration-problem-help#comment5454807_2640102) to fix it.

Comment: @JohnMa The question statement is clear (find the definite integral). The question asker's attempt in the question body is unclear, but that's the point of asking.  Btw, the upvote on OP's self-answer is casted by somebody else.

Comment: The OP for that Question self-deleted their Answer, despite the upvote.  I'm not urging re-deleting the Question, but certainly that mitigates the argument for reopening (based on an upvoted but self-deleted Answer).

Comment: @GNUSupporter : The problem is it is not clear how the question-er fails to evaluate the integral. And because of that, it is not clear how your answer help solve their problem. Honestly I do not see why this post is worth keeping (of course you are welcome to improve the question to make that a better post).

Answer (score 0):

> **Undeleted**

The question *[How to integrate this polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2787481/290189)* received an answer (from an experienced user) in nine minutes after creation.  However, OP self-deleted his question one minute after that.  According to one of our site mods, this is an "[abusive behaviour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759560/extending-the-triangle-inequality#comment5694741_2759560)".  Other users *don't* have enough time to vote on this answer.  Therefore, I propose to undelete this question.

Comment: It seems the OP undeleted the question 16 minutes after deleting it.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thanks for your update.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

I want my question re-opened. It was put on hold with the following message

> "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the
>   question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your
>   thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it.
>   This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and
>   helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." –
>   amWhy, Cesareo, José Carlos Santos, Shailesh, Alex Francisco

The question is
[How to calculate the distance travelled by a car in an elliptical track after a certain time given its angular speed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827075/how-to-calculate-the-distance-travelled-by-a-car-in-an-elliptical-track-after-a)

I've edited the question adding more context & more details regarding what I want & what i tried by myself.

Since I am a new user, I may not know how much information to give without making it verbose. So please leave a comment if any other action is required from my side & reopen the question

Comment: My understanding is that by editing your question you automatically placed it in the "review queue", meaning there was no need to post a request to this discussion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh I was not aware of that. For future reference, in what circumstance should I post here for reopening.

Comment: Quoting from the introduction to this thread: "Notice that the first edit after the question was put on-hold pushes the question into reopen review queue, if the edit was done withing 5 days of closure. So does a reopen vote. It is reasonable to wait until the review is finished before posting here. (If the review has already been finished, it is shown on the timeline of the question.)"

Answer (score 0):

> **Deleted**

I want to reopen [this inequality question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795656/show-this-inequality-sum-limits-textcyc-sqrtx2x-le-prod-limits-textc). Although OP did not show any effort to solve the question, majority of the MSE users considers the question to be interesting and some of them will be able to give a good answer to it.

Comment: You seem to have marked the requesting post **Reopened** at the same time you wrote this.  In fact the linked Question is closed since May 25 (this year), and the author of that has been missing in action since.  I'm going to edit your request, since the post is *not* Reopened.  Saying "majority of the MSE users considers the question to be interesting" sounds like an exaggeration.

Comment: So now can I repost it? BTW, it has 12 upvotes and 2 downvotes so 86% of MSE users finds it interesting. "Majority" is not exaggeration.

Comment: Sure, you can repost such a problem in a better context with a new Question (assuming it isn't a duplicate, I did not search).  Getting more upvotes than downvotes means a majority of users *who voted* approved of the Question, but this is clearly not the same as a majority of MSE users.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to request to undelete [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2843216/572778) answer. Since the deletion I improved it by attaching simple script demonstrating basic idea behind the said algorithm and I hope it is of some value now, it even received one upvote.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not of any value in my opinion. The question is about how to achieve some performance bound. Your post does not address that at all.

Comment: @user21820 From the question itseld: "However I can't find anything more than a brief overview of the algorithm itself, let alone a worked example. Could anyone provide a detailed explanation or example, or reference to where I can find one?"

Comment: Look the question is obviously concerned with a certain algorithm that has a certain time complexity. Yours is nowhere near that, so it is not an answer to that question. In particular, yours is **not** the **Pollard-Strassen** algorithm.

Comment: Furthermore, it already had an answer 6 years ago that does actually address the question. So why insist on keeping your answer that doesn't?

Comment: @user21820 Because not everyone has the book and it shows the idea behind the algorithm. I don't understand what harm does it cause to keep the answer visible.

Comment: After my three comments, you still apparently do not understand the meaning of "algorithm". Question asks about X. Your post talks about Y. And X ≠ Y.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reopened, deleted by community user**

The question is put on hold because the question looks too complicated and long - but now it has been reduced and improved.

This is related and needs to be re-opened: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846746/79069, please vote up/reopen!

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> **Undeleted**

What was the point in deleting [For which $k$ are there most partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117954/greatest-value-for-k-in-partition-of-a-fixed-number-n-into-k-parts) ? Is the website really better without the mathematical content in the answer to that question, than with it?

Comment: What a weird Q&A. $P(n,k)$ isn't defined explicitly *anywhere* (you can guess from the title, or you can follow the OEIS link, but it's not defined in the question...) The first edit to the question was literally copied from your answer plus something that should have been a comment. Then the OP self-answered the question with something that should have been an edit, which was converted into an edit by a mod but comments were lost and the discussion doesn't make sense anymore. It's simply a mess, and I don't really see any mathematical content besides the OEIS links, TBH.

Comment: (In particular, your answer is a prime example of VLQ: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.” The mathematical content in question is not even on the website.)

Comment: I'd say you can *tell* (not "guess") from the title. Bad way to write a question, but still it's a reasonable question to ask, and as you acknowledge that there is mathematical content, I have to ask, again; is this site better off without mathematical content, than with it? Because I thought we were here to provide mathematical content.

Comment: I might or might not have deleted this myself, I will however say that I find the thread quite confusing.  To answer your comment by analogy: Somebody selling apples might well search for those  that are somewhat foul and put them in the garbage. Somebody else might consider them still as edible and maybe leave them around, or perhaps try to sell them at a discount.  It depends on ones priorities and what image one wants to convey.

Comment: @quid, are you suggesting that my answer to that question was foul?

Comment: No. I compared the *thread* to an apple that is "somewhat foul." I am now not sure if "somewhat foul" is an idiomatically correct way to refer to an apple that started to degrade/go bad but might still be considered as edible (in part) by somebody. Maybe partly rotten would be better. Anyway I assume you can imagine the type of apple I have in mind: one side degraded, one side alright. So, the analogy  described the *thread* as having some good parts but being overall of questionable quality.

Comment: However, the main point of the analogy was in fact not to evaluate the thread in an unfavorable way (as I said I might not even have deleted it myself) but rather to point out that the mere fact that  the website is here to provide mathematical content does not imply that everything that is mathematical content needs to be preserved, just like somebody in the business of selling apples might also decide to put some apple to the garbage rather then try to sell it (while some other vendor of apples might have a different judgement on some specific apple).

Comment: On the question in more detail I would argue it is not clear. I will give you that what $P(k,n)$ is can be determined but what is "what's the greatest value you can find for a number $k$ for $P(n,k)$, where $n$ is fixed?" supposed to mean precisely? One might ask for  the max of $P(n,k)$ over all $k$ or the values of  $k$ that maximize $P(n,k)$ (so the arg max if one wants). However, the question does neither. At least not in a clear way.  Maybe one should read it as "what's the greatest value you can find (for a number $k$) for $P(n,k)$, where $n$ is fixed?" but this is quite odd.

Comment: @quid, I thought it was quite clear that the question is, given $n$, find $k$ that maximizes $P(n,k)$.

Comment: Given later edits this seems indeed the intent. However, your answer starts (my emphasis).  "**The** numbers are tabulated at  " giving a link to $\max_k P(k,n)$ *not* the $k$s. You give this too. But the first link giving **the** numbers does in fact not give the numbers you now consider as asked about. I continue to think there is need for clarification.

Comment: @quid, I wish someone had asked for clarification (or provided it) before voting to delete the question.

Comment: This could be a good way to proceed. Yet, if I am not mistaken, one can edit deleted posts. Hence in a similar spirit one might hope for clarification before (requests for) undeletion.

Comment: I cleaned-up the question and cast the final vote to undelete. And then also one to reopen. I added the info what 'the numbers' are in your answer. If you do not like it just roll back, obviously.

Comment: If closing a question as unclear isn't a request for clarification, I don't know what is.

Comment: @Najib, I take it that comment was addressed to me. Closing a question as unclear requests clarification from the person posting the question, and from anyone else happening to stumble across the question after it is closed, and I suppose from anyone who checks the list of recently closed questions several times a day, but that leaves out a lot of people.  Like, almost everyone.

Comment: Well yes, it is a comment on your answer and I didn't @ping anyone. I am a bit confused, what method do you suggest that doesn't leave out almost everyone? And who better than the OP to provide clarification?

Comment: @Najib, let's review the bidding. The question was posed 8 March 2012. OP was last seen here 9 March 2012. The question was closed as unclear on 20 March **2015**, three years after OP left the building. So, tell me again that it was a request for OP to provide clarification.

Comment: I am a bit confused, what method do you suggest that doesn't leave out almost everyone? (It seems you missed that part so I'm including it again) Then maybe we can realize asking a new, not completely garbled question is the best course of action. Maybe the answers to that new question will even be more than just a link to an outside website...

Comment: @Najib, the answers are already much more than just links to an outside website. Have a look!

Comment: Well that's obviously much better now. I wish all these posts had such a happy ending.

Answer (score -1):

> **Self-deleted**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434805. It was closed with reason "unclear what you're asking", but as far as I can tell it's crystal clear what's being asked. It seems to me that the question was viewed negatively because it takes the rather unorthodox approach of finding derivatives either numerically or by "factoring out / canceling" (which only works for linear functions), instead of learning to differentiate analytically; but that doesn't make the question unclear and it's not a reason to close the question.

Comment: You know that there's a reopen review queue? There is nothing about this post that requires "exceptional handling" (the stated purpose of this request thread), at least wait a few hours before posting here...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: No, I'd read about a "reopen review queue" before but don't know exactly what it is, and I didn't know that there's a convention to wait a for hours for that queue to operate before posting here. I don't find the stated purpose of this thread quite as clear as you do. It says "... exceptional handling. This includes requests for reopen and undeletion votes." If the intended meaning is that such requests should only be made after waiting for votes to be generated by the review queue, then that should be explicitly stated.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I strongly object to the tone of your message. I see no obligation to make myself familiar with every mechanism on this site. It's everyone's personal choice in what form they want to contribute their time to the site.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I've looked at the review queue now. The question doesn't appear to be in it. If I understand the page that you linked to correctly, this means that enough "leave closed" votes were cast since I cast my reopen vote to kick the question out of the queue? If so, am I right in thinking that if I want to argue in favour of reopening the question, there is no mechanism for this within the review queue, and it's preferable to do it here than to do it in comments under the question? If so, would you agree that, even if my post was initially inappropriate, it's now become appropriate?

Comment: I can confirm that the question is in the review queue (I just voted to reopen). Indeed, I don't see any harm that a request is put here.... (The link: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/480860)

Comment: @JohnMa: Thanks. I guess I'm not getting it in my review queue because I already voted to reopen it. When I follow your link, I do get the review page, but it says "This item is not reviewable.".

Comment: I [posted on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21411) on the question of whether it's inappropriate to post here without waiting for the reopen review queue to operate.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There is not necessarily any correlation between rep and knowledge of site functionality, esp, for users (like the OP) who have  just returned after being away for a couple years (welcome back!). In such cases we should strive to be more welcoming, because surely it is no easy task to get up to speed on the many ways the site has changed.

Comment: "I strongly object to the tone of your message. I see no obligation to make myself familiar with every mechanism on this site. It's everyone's personal choice in what form they want to contribute their time to the site." I like the way you phrased this. Well put!

Answer (score -1):

> **Reopened**

I think [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491442/is-some-one-dimensional-subalgebra-an-ideal-of-the-2-dimensional-abelian-lie-alg) should be reopened.  It was originally both unclear and lacking context, but it has been greatly expanded and the statement of the question is now clear and well-motivated (despite the fact that some of the motivating discussion is still a bit muddled).

Answer (score -1):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515109/can-any-3d-rotation-be-done-with-only-2-angles/) was closed as "unclear what you're asking". I have fixed the terminology in the question so that it shouldn't be unclear anymore.

(It stalled in the [reopen queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/530419) just one vote short. I'm reasonably surprised that so many voted to leave closed)

Answer (score -1):

> **Reopened**

Request for reopening a  reference-request question:

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685938/which-is-the-best-book-for-mathematical-logic-for-non-mathematicans) is on hold as opinion based. reference-request questions *somehow* can be seen as "based on opinions". I clarified what kind of book I want. It has good answers and can have more. (It has 2 reopen vote).
Thank you

Comment: Reference requests are not necessarily based on opinions. Also you needlessly make it more opinion based than it has to be  by asking for "best." Moreover, if the 'best' book were out of print since decades and hard to get access to and written in a language you do not understand maybe you would be more interested in a very slightly worse book that is in English and readily available.

Comment: yes thank you. I've edited the question and forgot to edit title; now I edit

Comment: The question now has four votes to reopen, if someone would like to be the fifth.

Comment: @T. Bongers. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

**Reopened**

[Can $P(\omega)$ be superatomic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771572/can-p-omega-be-superatomic)

Are there any standards by which this is not a good question?  There don't appear to be standard techniques in the course of whose application one can say specifically where one got stuck on this question.

Comment: "Are there any standards by which this is not a good question?" Please explain how the question complies with the [last point in the default reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), titled "Give definitions," for the closing reason in question.

Comment: Note my Comment on the Question at issue asking the OP about how the notation used is defined.  The body text there does little more than repeat the title.

Comment: As your Answer on the Question was accepted, I would say the OP endorsed your interpretation of the problem sufficiently to edit the Question and supply the clarification/definition of notation.  Likely the OP got what they wanted and have less motivation than you for any reopening efforts.

Comment: @quid : The question originally had "set-theory" as a tag, so the definitions would be just those that are conventional in set theory. If "calculus" is a tag, one doesn't give a definition of $\displaystyle\int f(x)\,dx$ every time one mentions an integral. Failure to adhere to the points on the page on how to ask a good question can often result in a bad question, but that doesn't mean it always does.  In cases where it doesn't, it doesn't, and in such cases one shouldn't treat such a failure to adhere as an offense.  But I suspect some people $\text{feel }\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$that they must zealously campaign against all such failures regardless of whether it is a case in which the result is a bad question, and that that is what is going on in this case. Indeed, someone down-voted my answer.  I wonder why? That would be a bad-faith down-vote if it resulted from any expression of mine on this page or anywhere besides in the answer. $\qquad$

Comment: The understandability of the main post should not depend on the tag. Besides, with or without that tag the question is, for me, unnecessarily hard to understand due to the lack of definitions. As pointed out, there was a comment asking for clarification. That you completely ignore that comment, could be seen as not in overly good faith too.

Comment: The question was edited to include context, by its poster initially and then some more by Martin. I cast the final vote to reopen.

Comment: @quid Probably a majority of questions include notation that is not defined in the question. If the notation is not familiar to the reader then they should ask for clarification, not use that as an excuse to close the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque as could be evident from the comment thread above, there was a comment asking for clarification. Alas, initially it had no effect. Later more severe measures of community moderation had the desired effect. If anything this is one more instance  showing the importance of using votes to close and down-votes to reinforce the message.

Answer (score -1):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/280530/revisions)**

[Can you provide me historical examples of pure mathematics becoming "useful"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280530/can-you-provide-me-historical-examples-of-pure-mathematics-becoming-useful) has been put on hold, as "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." But in fact there are several excellent answers, including one with 94 net upvotes, and as for "too many possible answers", well, it is a big-list question, it's expected to have a lot of answers. Please have a look, and consider voting to reopen.

Comment: It's a poor fit for the format like most big-list questions. I voted to close again. Also the quality of several answers (though not all) is not so great, to say the least.

Comment: @quid, so, just vote down the bad answers.

Comment: You seem to miss the point. The presence of numerous bad answers further illustrates that the question is a bad fit for the format.

Comment: @quid, so, what does the presence of numerous good answers illustrate?

Comment: That it is conceivable that more focused questions along the same lines could be productively treated on this site. Unfortunately, the continued active presence of overly broad threads, such as this one, indirectly stifles the emergence of such more focused questions.

Answer (score -1):

> **Self-deleted.**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401782/a-bounded-function-that-converges-to-0-does-it-have-a-finite-energy-norm

BEGIN QUOTE

A function $f(t)$ belongs to $L_\infty$ and its limit (as $t \to \infty$) is $0$. How do I show that such a function is in $L_2?$

END QUOTE

Superficially, this may look like a copied-and-pasted homework problem, but only very superficially. A homework problem would usually not ask students to prove something that is **not true,** so that seems to indicate that this question is the student's own work rather than something copied and pasted from an assignment.

Comment: It very well could still be homework. The problem could simply be mistaken. The student could have misinterpreted it. It could have been an "is this true?" and the student decided to try and tackle the "yes" answer. There could be more assumptions in the problem that the student didn't think relevant. There could be implicit assumptions in the problem that the student didn't conceive of. And all of these things could be present even if it isn't a homework problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl : Indeed it could be homework and the problem could be mistaken. Note that I said "usually". And I said "copied and pasted". There's no policy against asking about homework here, and I didn't say this isn't homework; I said it does not appear to be a copied and pasted homework assignment.

Comment: And I did not say you said it wasn't homework. You did, however, bring up the idea, argue for it, and suggest its truth.

Comment: @Hurkyl : No --- I said it does not appear to be COPIED AND PASTED homework. In other words it contains the poster's own thoughts.

Comment: Okay... but if that's the point you are trying to emphasize, I overlooked it because you make a distinction in a way that does not appear to have any relevance. Is a verbatim replication of a problem really significantly different than a flawed attempt to replicate it?

Comment: I note that the question has been deleted by the poster.

Comment: @Hurkyl : The point would be that in this case the flaws would have been introduced by the poster, therefore showing that the poster must have thought about it.

Answer (score -1):

**Mod deleted.**

---

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708226/given-five-points-on-a-face-determine-if-the-face-shape-is-closest-to-a-circl

I propose that this be re-opened so it can be re-closed with a proposal to migrate it to stats.stackexchange.com .

---

Moderator comment for the deletion : This is too similar to another question by the same user: [How can I define closeness of these geometric shapes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731477/how-can-i-define-closeness-of-these-geometric-shapes) It is not very clear why this was not noticed/mentioned before posting this request.

Comment: FYR: A similar question was re-asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731477/how-can-i-define-closeness-of-these-geometric-shapes?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Please learn how to check your flag history. It is more than a bit astonishing that you do not know this.

Comment: @JohnMa : How would I have known of that other question?

Comment: For me, I just check the [linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708226/given-five-points-on-a-face-determine-if-the-face-shape-is-closest-to-a-circl) post on the right of the OP. In this situation there is only one. I clicked and I found that it was re-asked.

Comment: @MichaelHardy maybe by checking the questions that user had asked in the interim from their user profile? There was a great total of two such questions. What is difficult about this?

Comment: @quid : So each time you look at a question, you check to see whether the poster has asked a similar question before? When no one has said anything about that? And I find that that poster has asked 11 questions, not just two. You use the words "in the interim". What "interim" are you referring to?

Comment: I had said it in a reply to your flag. Here again: " OP has asked a similar question on our site by now. It is not clear it's a good idea to disperse the discussion. " Note the "by now". The interim refers to the time between posting the question you are talking about and right now or right then in any case after this question.

Answer (score -2):

> **Reopened and reclosed and reopened again**

I recommend that [Assigning tables for Speed Networking session](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112651/assigning-tables-for-speed-networking-session) be reopened at this point.  It seems to have been closed initially because the title included "need answer ASAP!!", about which Asaf commented such posts should be "on hold for at least 48 hours".

The Question otherwise seems on-topic and motivated by a practical concern for resolvable block designs.

Comment: The issue is that the practical concerns will not be taken into account, also as they are not mentioned, really. This was the first objection raised. It would be kind you also mentioned it.  The one that is proposed highly voted, I doubt this is good in practice.

Comment: @quid: I don't follow your complaint.  We often use "off-topic" to exclude questions which lack context or motivation.  Here a clear context is described, and a mathematically justified solution was given that meets all stated restrictions.

Comment: My first complaint here is that you did not mention that the complaint was raised. But made it look it was only closed for some "ASAP."

Comment: The complaint on the questions on main is that the context is in fact not described in a clear way. This a pseudo-application as it is.

Comment: @quid: You are in a better position than I to present this complaint.  Other Readers will have to judge the stated context as clear or "pseudo-application" for themselves.  I have at times helped non-mathematically inclined folks tasked with schedules of dinner parties or sports tournaments of a similar nature, and did not suspect the honesty of their requests.

Comment: [This is what context means](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), if that helps to clear things up. The fact that a valid solution was posted is irrelevant in deciding whether to reopen a question or not. So is "honesty" of the question.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: The fact that a valid solution was posted is relevant to the issue of whether "the practical concerns will not be taken into account", as quid put it.  That was my reason for calling attention to it.  Your dictum "This is what context means" does not connect me with your insight.  Perhaps you and/or quid would be kind enough to explain it to me in chat?

Comment: Yes, but you ought to mention at least its existence when you post this here, especially since you discussed concerns that were raised. Not doing this is at best impolite and at worst dishonest. (I did not question the honesty of the question; I wanted to get more details on the situation, or the information that it is an abstract question. I do not care if the person does organize anything or not. But if they do one might better propose something adapt to the situation.)

Comment: While it seems you persistently ignore what I say, on "The fact that a valid solution was posted". I said here, first comment: "The one that is proposed highly voted, I doubt this is good in practice." The fact that somebody came up with some solution that works to the specification does not mean that the practical concern were taken into account. OP did not mention any, so they are to blame. But, still, they should be present. The outcome of that procedure seems way to "structured" to be good for the purpose; moreover it is quite static so participant will even notice this subjectively.

Comment: @hardmath As you can see, sending me an email on my work address on a Saturday night may not get you the speediest response. In fact I'd appreciate if you could not send me emails related to MSE, you can simply contact me here. Why did I post this link to "what is context"? quid and you seem to have differing notions of what context is (you say the question has clear context, quid voted to close as "no context"). So I posted the official definition as a reference.

Answer (score -2):

> **Undeleted, reopened, closed as a duplicate**

Request to undelete and reopen [Suppose $a_n$ converges and $b_n$ divergent. What can you tell about $a_n+b_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583487/suppose-a-n-converges-and-b-n-divergent-what-can-you-tell-about-a-nb-n) on account of:

- it being a perfectly clear question from a time (2013) where the question standards weren't as obvious as they are now;
- the OP showing effort in the comments;
- and [Why close old questions with accepted answers using the "no context" reason?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/why-close-old-questions-with-accepted-answers-using-the-no-context-reason)

---

**Edit:** It has been pointed out in the comments that the question is a duplicate of an older question. The previous closure reason was off-topicness with which I didn't agree. I am now voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: To include the full story, we should mention that you answered the question, and the OP has been absent since the end of 2013. Also, the question was closed the day it was asked, so it seems inaccurate to refer to changing standards - it seems like a question that had sat closed for more than a year, and finally people got around to cleaning it up.

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't see how that's relevant. **Edit:** And people can see I answered the question when they open the link. Yes, it was closed on the same day it was asked. But at the time that was the decision of a few users and not the stance of (most) the community as it is today.

Comment: It's almost certainly a duplicate, and the question doesn't meet the quality standards of the site. It doesn't matter if it's been posted yesterday or twenty years ago. I find somewhat disingenuous the fact that you posted a link to a lengthy debate with no clear conclusion as if it supported your decision. Also (in case you don't know) deleted questions are still editable, so if you're willing to put in the effort of improving it, you can do it now, and then there won't be any question of whether it should be reopened or not.

Comment: To Najib Idrissi: the question was already edited by Famous Blue Raincoat. But it is not normal practice on this site to significantly change a question - that is up to the OP. Which is why it is relevant (@Git Gud) that the OP has long departed this site.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi If it is a duplicate, close it as a duplicate. I'll even close it myself. The question I linked in my third point has 24 up votes vs 6 down votes. Interpret that as unclear conclusion if you wish. Regarding editing the question, let me ask you how to make it acceptable, because I honestly don't know. Adding the very weak (in the sense that it doesn't do much towards getting an answer) efforts the OP has given in the comments would be useless chaff.

Comment: @Git Gud: if we don't know how the question can be made acceptable, short of deleting the text and rewriting it from scratch, I don't see a strong argument to undelete the question?

Comment: [It took me thirty seconds to find this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499937/convergence-or-divergence-of-the-series-sum-n-1-inftya-nb-n-given-the) I'm sure there are better duplicates out there.

Comment: @CarlMummert Suppose a perfect question gets deleted. Since it's perfect, you can't improve it. Does that mean it should remain deleted? Just to make it clear, I'm not claiming the question is perfect. My point is that I don't know how to improve it and in my opinion as it presently is, it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Git Gud: questions like that have been unacceptable for some time - that is why the "no context" closure reason (used on that question) was added in the first place!

Comment: The third bullet point appears irrelevant.  The first is at least of unclear relevance.  I would omit them.  I think the edit incorporating OP's comment was sufficient improvement.

Comment: @CarlMummert Why is it relevant that the OP hasn't been active? Questions and answers are supposed to be accessed unbiasedly and without context. It follows from this that whether the users are active or not is irrelevant. **Edit:** OK, I see now you've answered this already-

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I fail to see the relevance of you having taken thirty seconds to find a duplicate.

Comment: @Git Gud: I don't think the reputation is the issue - it's just a few points. I do think that, as a general principle, a request to re-open a deleted question by someone who answered the question comes across as less objective than a request by someone who has not previously interacted with a question.

Comment: @CarlMummert Point taken. I'm going to remark something though. I'm not in the habit of coming to this thread to check on things. When I do ask for something like this, it is exactly because I interacted with the thread, otherwise I'd be ignorant about it.

Comment: "The question I linked in my third point has 24 up votes vs 6 down votes. Interpret that as unclear conclusion if you wish.": Yes, the *question* has these votes. Votes cannot indicate "agree/disagree" on that... Votes up would be in agreement with what, exactly? It seems to me that the question tries to be fairly neutral. It even includes "one good reason to vote-to-close these questions". Have you looked at the comments and answers to that question, in particular the +17/-6 answer if you're so intent on having numeric values attributed to positions? It looks nuanced to me.

Comment: I had deleted my comment as I noticed then but too late that @JonasMeyer said the same thing already. Thank you for the clarification this explains it a little. Still I feel you did not really address the points raised. I also fail completely to see the relevance of "Yes, it was closed on the same day it was asked. But at the time that was the decision of a few users and not the stance of (most) the community as it is today." Why didn't you do anything about it *then*? By the way, reputation does not even change when old questions are deleted; I do not understand the quibble about that.

Comment: @quid I too deleted my comment after I noticed you deleted yours. I agree that 3. is a bad reason on account of the thread itself not supporting "Don't mess with old questions" and in view of this, I also don't support 1. anymore. Why didn't I do anything then? I don't know, maybe i didn't see it. Maybe I didn't care then. And I did lose reputation, that's how I noticed the question had been deleted. My issue was with Carl's remark "To include the full story, we should mention that you answered the question" as if I wanted to undelete because I lost reputation.

Comment: Yes, again I noticed it too late. Thanks for the reply. For the points, I did not pay close enough attention, sorry. In addition to the 60 days on site, there is a score at least 3 criterion to prevent points being subtracted upon deletion, and while this is now fulfilled it is possible it presumably was not when it was deleted. And I did not account for that.

Comment: @quid Good to know about it, though. I had no idea. I don't pay much attention to my whether my answers get deleted or not because I thought I could just check by looking at the reputation. This is worrisome because I often go back to my answers for many reasons and this way I may end up losing valuable time because an answer may have gotten deleted and I had no idea about it.

Comment: @GitGud: You can check "deleted recent answers" from your answers tab once in a while.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks, had never noticed the button.

Comment: @JonasMeyer The deletions of old posts that do not affect reputation also do not appear on that page. It includes deleted posts that were *created* in the last 60 days, not *deleted* in the last 60 days.

Comment: Thanks @FamousBlueRaincoat; so Git Gud, my suggestion was off.  For answered questions to be deleted by nonmoderators, they have to be closed first.  You can check your answers to closed questions [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/266734/my-answers-to-closed-questions). Bookmark them if you want.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks. Please don't delete your comment, I'll come to it when I need it.

Comment: Wow, someone posted a link to my DESE query even though I don't recall advertising it. I'm feeling warm and fuzzy inside :)

Answer (score -2):

> **Deleted by author**

I suggest reopening this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318701/are-all-numbers-interesting

The problem isn't worded the best way, but I think an answer can be given.

Comment: The question is lacking a definition of "nontrivial property". This essentially makes it meaningless.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: The basic question about what makes a number (or anything) *interesting* I think can be addressed.

Answer (score -2):

> **Undeleted, Redeleted**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591147/help-with-context-sensitive-grammar) from 2013 was recently (11h ago) deleted and I don't know why. It was closed as missing context in 2013, but there are no missing details and I gave an answer, I would like it to be undeleted.

Comment: Surely this is me but where are there any elements of context? The full text of the question reads: "I am not able to understand writing a context sensitive grammar for this language. Can anyone please help me out?
$L = \{ a^p | p \text{ is a non-prime integer}\}$"

Answer (score -2):

> **Reopened, Reclosed**

Please consider reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1453959/462):

> Can everything in maths be proved from first principles?

I disagree that the question "does not belong to this site", as claimed in a comment, and that it is too broad (the given reason for putting it on hold).

Moreover, I think this is a matter that people interested in logic may wish to consider, as it is significantly subtler than saying yes (by definition: mathematics is what we can prove from given axioms) or than saying no, as the posted answer suggests (because of the incompleteness theorem).

Comment: For example, the question is not clear about whether it means "proved from first principles using ordinary natural language proofs" or "proved from first principles using formalized proofs" or "proved from first principles using formalized proofs that can actually be generated by an automated theorem verifier/proof assistant such as Isabelle or Coq".

Answer (score -2):

**Reopened**

[Show that $\left(\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{f(x)^2+g(x)^2}\ dx\right)^2 \geq \left(\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\ dx\right)^2 + \left(\int_{0}^{1} g(x)\ dx\right)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1600668) has been closed for lack of context. The OP added what context they had, which is not much, however, this inequality is very useful and can be answered using an extension of Jensen's Inequality to $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be useful in other situations.

Answer (score -2):

I have a CW answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696443/42339) that was recently deleted by a moderator. I think this was a lapse of judgement, and I'd like the answer either undeleted, or converted to a sequence of comments under the original question.

If you look at the OP's profile [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/167108/feralin), you'll see that he/she is only 18 years old and primarily a programmer. Ergo he/she is likely to find help regarding how to express oneself helpful, and this is what most of my answer addresses. Therefore, I think it kind of undermines the pedagogical goals of this site to be disallowing long comments such as this; in other words, I think it blocks our ability to help the OP in a major way.

The aforementioned answer also takes the liberty of mentioning a similar problem that some readers are likely to be interested in, and linking to one of the many solutions to this problem on the stack.exchange network. I think this usefully increases the interconnectedness of this site, and hence that these kinds of links should not be so readily deleted.

Comment: It was flagged by several people as "not an answer", and I agree, it fundamentally doesn't address the question. To discuss the wording of the questions, comments are the appropriate means.

Comment: @DanielFischer, this is just avoiding the argument, namely that deleting these kinds of answers blocks our ability to help the OP in a major way.

Answer (score -2):

> **Reopened**

[would changing the lower limit of a power series affect radius of convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807881/would-changing-the-lower-limit-of-a-power-series-affect-radius-of-convergence)

This question has been edited since it first appeared.  (This despite the fact that no edit history seems to appear; can someone explain how that happens?)  It is a good question.

Comment: I think this was already a good question before the further edits.  I suspect lots of people insist on adhering strictly to the letter of some feebly thought-out guidelines and that's why they voted to close it. $\qquad$

Comment: "[C]an someone explain how that happens?" There is short period (five minutes at most) where no revisions are kept. (It  can be shorter if another editor buds in or there are comments.)  Other than that, as happened already sometime IIRC, you link to the answer not the question. (Presumably as you follow the link from you profile to your answer or something.)

Comment: Is "lower limit" a common term?

Comment: @JohnMa : Yes. $\qquad$

Comment: @quid : Thank you.  I hadn't noticed that particular detail. $\qquad$

Answer (score -2):

> **[Reopened and then closed as a duplicate.](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1803146/revisions)**

I want [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803146/find-the-missing-digits-in-the-expansion-of-34) question to reopen it has $6$ upvotes and $1$ downvote

Comment: Isn't that question duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312138/determine-4-specific-digits-in-34)? (As suggested in comments. That question is also listed among related questions.)

Answer (score -2):

**Request to undelete [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1888919/68107) to my question**

The answer was self-deleted, but it is useful and an excellent answer to the question. I don't know why the user deleted it, but I'd like it undeleted so I can upvote / comment.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why it took you a week to interact with the answer to you question?

Comment: Did you contact the answerer before posting this request? You know, rather than (possibly) twisting their arm... (The user's page mentions: "Last seen 14 mins ago", hence they are still visiting the site.)

Comment: Other than that I agree with @Did I can see reasons why they actually might want to keep it deleted. Though it is also not unlikely they were just annoyed over your non-reaction.

Comment: @quid I just didn't read through the answers in detail until now. I don't think it violates any protocol not to interact with answers for a week but I can see how it would be considered rude, so I'll avoid it in the future. I hadn't thought about it too much but I agree it's not the best practice.

Comment: @Did contacted, thanks. I wasn't sure whether pinging on a different answer a message about an unrelated answer would be considered OK.

Comment: Deleting answers which are good contributions to the site *is* discouraged, explicitly -- and though in this case it isn't an *upvoted* answer I'm still not sure why everyone disagrees with my request so much. Sometimes attitudes on mathSE completely baffle me.

Comment: Obviously there is no rule that you must interact with answers on your question within a given timeframe. However, if a user is regularly active on the site, like you were, and still does not get around to vote on the answers they got to a recently asked question than I find this odd. As said the main point why I would not vote to undelete this though is that it's not clear why it was deleted. Maybe they want it deleted for other reasons. It seems plausible to me.

Answer (score -2):

> **Reopened**

[Why doesn't $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383695/why-doesnt-sin2x-1-cos2x#comment4915466_2383695)

This question was "put on hold as unclear what you're asking by". The question is clear. $$ \begin{align} & \text{One source says } \sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos(2x)} 2, \\ \\ & \text{and another says } \sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x. \end{align} $$ The poster found these two results discrepant and wondered why. It only needed to be explained that both can be correct, and a few simple implications of that explained.

Answer (score -2):

[DELETED](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2407133/revisions).

This question has a superficial resemblance to a homework problem that may have been copied and pasted without the poster's understanding the question. However, the resemblance can be seen to be only superficial when one considers the following:

- Apparently the poster simply didn't know the binomial theorem. Or perhaps failed to recognize this as an instance of it.
- The two posted answers simply explain the binomial theorem. That's *not* a case of doing the poster's homework for them.
- (And here is what may be a more adventurous reason.) A question can be justified by the fact that a good answer can be written.

[How can I get $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(pe^t)^kq^{n-k}=(pe^t+q)^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2407133)

Answer (score -2):

> **[Reopened, closed, deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2415731/revisions)**

[Compute $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1 \max\{x_1,\ldots ,x_n\}\,dx_1\cdots dx_n. $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415731/compute-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-01-cdots-int-01-max-x-1-ldots-x-n)

Initially this was phrased like a homework problem with no thoughts by the poster. It has been edited since then.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, but the post here is completely unnecessary given how recent the post and closure are.

Comment: @user296602 I'll point out that this post was made *after* the [reopen review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/864266) was already completed, at least if I am reading the timestamps correctly.

Comment: I find the added material incomprehensible.

Comment: I have voted to undelete this question. It is an interesting question with effort.

Answer (score -2):

> **Undeleted**, **Reopened**, **Redeleted**

I'd like to appeal the deletion of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424765/are-there-integer-valued-polynomials-with-at-least-one-irrational-coefficient which came up while I was doing close vote reviewing (https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/888212).

Sure, it's not the most profound question on the site, but it's a reasonable thing for a beginning student to wonder about, it's clearly not a homework question, and the answer is not super obvious (orangeskid sketched a nice argument in the comments).

The question was originally closed as "unclear what you're asking" but this concern no longer applies since the question as been edited.

Comment: And after the edit, what we have is a clear question, with zero personal input from the OP, right?

Comment: @Did Sure, but it seems clear to me that the question is motivated by simple curiosity, and I'm not sure what additional context (other than "I was thinking about polynomials and was wondering: ") you'd hope to see.

Answer (score -2):

> [**Closed, Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted,Re-re-undeleted, mod-deleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2662412/revisions)

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662412/three-sided-coin-model) was closed and then deleted.  In the comments and the subsequent [meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27962/why-has-my-question-been-deleted), some users said it would help if the question were more self-contained. The OP doesn't have sufficient rep to add images, so I included the relevant excerpts from their linked PDF.

---

Reason for the mod delete: Even the best version of the post is not good, containing an **image** of a formula instead of the formula. If anyone (OP or anybody else) wants to pursue this further, please, do so in a new thread, informed by what was discussed. To recall, formulas should be typeset using MathJax. Images could also be described verbally if there are issues with inclusion.

Comment: For the record, the necessary rep to post images is 10 points. :-)

Comment: @Did And the OP currently has 9...so close!

Comment: My point is that it requires a very limited investment in the site to reach this rep hence one can avoid feeling too sorry for users claiming they deliberately disregarded well established rules of the site because they did not have the necessary rep (which, irrespectively of the amount of rep necessary, is a strange reasoning in itself, if you think two minutes about it).

Comment: The argument you put forward is more than  week as the second image you include could perfectly well be typeset. In that sense your edit is a poor one.

Comment: And what about the first image, where the variables are actually defined? My edit added requested context, and it requires some impressive mental gymnastics to conclude that it was a "poor one." Also, "more than week?" I'm afraid I don't see how to compare an argument to a period of time.

Comment: @Quasicoherent what about it? How does this justify you not typesetting the formula? If you have to resort to harping on a silly language-error, it just proves that your point is weAk. And OP could have typeset it from the very start on, only resorting to the pdf for the figure. But they did not.

Comment: @quid Yours is the weak argument. As noted above, the OP did not have sufficient rep to add the figure. I added the figure, and while I was at it I added the equation since it took little additional time.  Is there a reason you so dogmatically want the formula to be typeset?

Comment: @Quasicoherent The missing figure was/is not the only problem with the post. The argument that the only reason OP did not ask a good question was their inability to include a graphic does not hold any water.  Reasons why formulas should be typeset were discussed over and over again around here. Further, do you think it was an informative title? If not, why not improve it? And the list could go on. I am rather hostile towards tinkering around with subpar posts. Either really improve them or leave them alone. (This is a a general statement, I do not want to target you specifically.)

Comment: @quid Where exactly did I make such an argument? I said "...some users said it would help if the question were more self-contained," which is undeniably true. I stated the edits I made to the post and why I made them, nothing more. I agree that a typeset formula is preferable to a picture, but adding the formula, typeset of not, was an improvement to the post. To call such an edit "poor" makes no sense to me. It seems that you're saying if I can't make an optimal edit, there is no point in making an incremental improvement.

Comment: @quid Also, what are these other problems with the post? In both the OP and the meta thread, nearly all the comments refer to the linked PDF or a lack of context as far as I can see.

Comment: Alright so what then is your argument? You did not give an explicit argument for reopening / undeleting so I assumed the implicit one. You also may want to notice other objections that were raised early on such as  "there is no reason why you [referring to OP] cannot type and use mathjax to format model 2" In fact the cannot include image narrative originates more from those defending the question not those that were against it. Re the title, sorry I had not noticed that you had changed the title. Thus, I take back this point.

Comment: This objection was acknowledge by OP but ignored; it was also ignored by you. It is a strange thing to do, as it could have been taken into account easily. You may not have realized this but using images for material that can be typeset without major problem is frowned upon. This may be accepted at times but if it comes from somebody that pretends to fix a post then this is strange.

Comment: The argument is explicit and is exactly what I stated in my answer. The post was closed for lack of context and the need to be more self-contained. I added in additional context and made it more self-contained, as well as improving the formatting. Thus users who previously voted to close and/or delete might change their evaluation after this edit. This was the case for at least one user, as the edit history shows. There was no need for you to assume any "implicit" argument that I never made, and we are awfully far from a field to be seeing [strawmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).

Comment: There was never any objection to my inclusion of the image of the formula for Model 2 in the OP or the meta thread, except by you. The first objection to it was made by you here, which you then repeated in the comments to the OP. You are mischaracterizing the users’ comments by conflating “you can typeset that formula” (which some other users said) and “the formula *must* be typeset” (which no one but you has said).

Comment: So to recap, your objections to the post before my edit are: uninformative title, not self-contained, and missing the formula for Model 2. I improved the title (as you now acknowledge), I made the post self-contained by including the figure, and included the formula for Model 2. Your only reproach seems to be that this formula is in an image, not typeset.  And yet this is somehow a “poor edit.” Is this correct? Your definition of “poor” must be very different from mine.

Comment: Nowhere in the site rules do I see that formulas must be typeset. In particular, neither the [How To Ask page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) nor the [How can I format mathematics here? page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) makes any mention of typeset formulas being mandatory. (If I’m mistaken, please provide a link to such a rule.) I agree that typeset formulas are preferable since they are (I think) search-able using Approach0, but if this is just a preference and not a site policy, then deleting the post because of this seems like a flimsy pretext.

Comment: (I also find it hard to believe that a future user would have found this post by searching for a typeset formula rather than simply searching “three-sided coin.”) Moreover, I see no precedent for such an action.  There are many posts that contain images of formulas that *could* be typeset (here’s [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336888/morphism-between-curves-constant-of-surjective)), but most people realize that it is easier to just include the image rather than re-typing it.

Comment: So I repeat my question: why are you so dogmatic that the formula must be typeset?

Comment: But seriously, “pretends to fix a post”? I hope that this is another language issue (for instance, prétendre = “to claim,” in French), but if not I am utterly disappointed in you. I have been a user on this site for a LONG time, and have contributed to it positively in many ways. If you can’t assume the bare minimum of good faith on my part, there is no point in continuing this conversation.

Comment: I had not noticed your comments earlier as you did not comment notify me. On the image-formula thing see for example https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11696/ And, this come up very frequently. Not typesetting math but posting an image of the sheet/book is usually quite poorly received in questions. Re the pretends. Intends or claims might have been clearer. I did not mean to suggest that you intentionally only tried to give the impression to fix the post. Nevertheless, in your attempt you ignored an explicit objection and did something that is widely perceived as poor editing.

Comment: I did not delete the thread because of this. I deleted it because it was in various back-and-forth activities. Faced with this I have mostly two option: I can  delete or lock it. Since  even the best version should be further improved (see the meta thread above) locking is not a good option. The improving could just  as well be done in a new thread, without all the baggage the thread already had accumulated. It is better to start a new thread if your goal is to have the question on the site without drama. In a way my deletion facilitates this.

Comment: That is, if this is your main goal. If your main goal is to make a point then be up-front about it. You linking that older meta question in the other thread makes this plausible, too. As said recently, I am tired of somewhat incremental improvement been done to poor threads just to keep them around. On my side there is some accumulated anger about this. In that sense, I realize that you might find  my reaction here unjust, and in a way it is as you received the accumulated anger.

Comment: Further reference on the image thing: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions

Comment: @quid My impression has been that, historically, the main issue has been image-*only* questions; the image here is helpful, but the question is very close to understandable without the image - and the images are hosted through SE anyways, so going dead isn't a big concern! In fact, about the only improvement I would see as important is to write out the second image, which would take a user less than a minute to do. So it seems to me that the deletion actions by *several* users are more about pent-up anger than about actual quality control, which is unfortunate and disappointing.

Comment: @quid I meant the second image (with the text and formula) - I lost that word while editing. I interpreted your comment about "accumulated anger" differently than you meant it - sorry. I do agree that the deletion with leave to restart the thread is a decent middle ground, but I am very disappointed by how this has been handled by several users - the communication was poor, the editing was ridiculous (especially the vandalism), and the comment chains got downright toxic. I'm also disappointed by the same users engaging in repeated deletion votes; I had thought that was frowned upon.

Comment: @user296602 Sorry I deleted my comment as I then realized what you meant. (I was rather rushed, I should have understood it right away.) To be sure, I do not think that anybody has a particular issue with the first image being part of the question. The point about it being possible to describe the image was (as far as I am concerned) in reference to (false, imo) claims or implications that *unfortunately* OP could not have done better.

Comment: For the second, well yes, but apparently no one cared to do so, especially not OP. I do not agree with the word 'vandalism'; one may have different opinions about the merits of undoing the edit, but it is not vandalism.  Regarding the comments becoming toxic, yes this is unfortunate but I hope you realize that you had a non-negligible active role in this. Regarding the repeated voting, in a way it is not good form, but in general I am not that worried about it (I am more worried about some thinking that this voting is somehow a democratic process, which it is not).

Comment: @quid The only revision that I would refer to as vandalism was the inclusion of an 11 page pdf as an embedded image. I acknowledge my role in the comment chain propagating, but I still think it's important to point out when high-rep users are being unnecessarily rude and callous (especially when it's part of a pattern); if they take it badly, so be it.

Comment: Moreover, in the specific case the dynamic was a bit strange with the early mod involvement. (I have no issue with the early undel, maybe on another day I would have cast that vote.) It also should be noticed that OP voted to undelete twice. Some might even be surprised that they can vote at all. Finally for the images see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23564/ and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25830 (maybe more for Q.c., too) I think I can at least claim that I say consistently that images ought to be typeset to the extent possible (with reasonable effort) .

Comment: Oh that version. I think I agree @user296602 this wasn't a good idea, but there was no insistence on it so that's done. On the latest cmnt. Yes. But in pointing out such things one can do it in different ways. Your first comment in all this also could have been more sensitive. To me the real problem is that by now there are a couple of users among whom there is a lot of tensions. Then many things become complicate. Maybe we should all try to be more charitable. I realize I am not always good at this myself. And if not this, then just keep a distance from those with whom  one has issues.

Comment: @quid I am frustrated that you seem to be changing your arguments again and again. We began this chain with you attacking an argument I never made. We then spent many comments debating the matter of including Model 2 as an image vs. typesetting it. And now you finally say that you deleted the post mainly to stem the bleeding, and I agree that this is a sensible reason! …So why didn’t you just say this in the first place? Until now, nowhere in this thread, the meta thread, nor the OP did you give any indication that this was your motive for deletion.

Comment: Indeed, in [your comment on the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662412/three-sided-coin-model#comment5517829_2662412), it seems that your only objection is to the Model 2 image.

Comment: I appreciate you linking the meta posts on images. I certainly agree that typeset equations are preferable. I don’t think we’re going to agree on how big a problem including Model 2 as an image vs. typesetting is, but I will point out that while the accepted answers support your view, I think [this highly upvoted answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1856/22912) supports mine.

Comment: Regarding me ignoring an objection: this is false, as I already pointed out in [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio/27968?noredirect=1#comment114092_27968). (This thread has gotten long, so I can understand if you missed it.) You don’t have to take my word for it: you can consult the OP and meta thread, and the timestamps will show which comments were there when I made the edit.

Comment: Regarding the vandalism: call it what you like. I don’t think there can be differing opinions on this point: after my edit the question was objectively better than in the previous version. Twice the same experienced user reverted to the previous version and undid the improvements I had made. Based on their comments, it seems that this was done in an effort to teach OP (and maybe me) a lesson.

Comment: They admitted themselves in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662412/three-sided-coin-model#comment5517634_2662412) that their edits would make it harder for people to answer the question. I find it hard to call these edits anything but a willful effort to deface the question.

Comment: Regarding my “making a point:” you really haven’t gotten it, have you? My investment in this question was actually quite low. I came across a post on meta and thought that the linked post was interesting, despite not following the site rules. I spent 5-10 minutes editing it in an effort to make it conform to the rules. I agreed with other users that the deletion was hasty and linked a recent meta post on this topic. Users had suggested that the appropriate place to discuss reopening this question was this thread, so I posted here. All this probably took about 15 minutes.

Comment: What has eaten up hours of my time is responding to rude, baseless comments by users who seem intent on attributing to me all sorts of motives that I have never had, nor professed to have had. In the end, I don’t really care if this question is ever answered. I thought the question was interesting and I would have enjoyed reading an answer, so I spent a little of my time to try to improve it. (I will note that when I linked the meta post on deletions, I had only read the answers there and hadn’t noticed the controversy in the comments.)

Comment: Yes, I find your comments here inappropriate. I would find them inappropriate if you were just a user, and doubly so now that you’re a moderator. Moderators are supposed to act as dispassionate arbiters and work to keep conversations productive. I have found several of your comments here to be provocative. I’m not sure what the point of your comments regarding your accumulated anger is. It has the makings of an apology without actually being one.

Comment: Various users, including you here, are wasting my time trying too hard to save random question. This is misguided. Reask the question if you care about it, if not move on. (I did not read all your comments.)

Comment: Having now read all your comments some clarifications or a summary if you like: some mod-action on the thread in question was needed, it was even solicited explicitly by users via flags. In such a situation one has mostly two options: delete or lock on some version. If I lock on some version this suggest this version has my approval. However, I did not find any version good. Would I have found some version good, I might instead have locked the post on that version.

Comment: Your edit did improve the post. But in my opinion *given the context* it was not good enough. In retrospect I should have avoided the first comment on meta. I was however annoyed about the fact that a second meta-post was created about the same issue and also about how you broached the subject. Likely, you assumed it is the correct action to post here, but it is not when there is a full meta-thread about the question. In this case it is redundant and in a way "fanning the flames."

Comment: Now, you complain that something takes hours of your time. But it is your choice to invest this time. So, you made that edit, and it did not have the desired effect. You could have just moved on. But you did not. This is your right and your choice. But it is *your choice*. Finally, as you may have missed that, in the mean time OP of the original question grossly misbehaved, which now does not make me more sympathetic to this entire thing here.

Comment: All that said, I do realize that the way I communicated and defended my actions here was not as clear and measured as it should have been, and I am sorry for this. That said, I still believe that the decision itself was the right one.

Comment: @quid I appreciate your clarifications and apology.  I am also sorry I was not more patient and charitable in my responses to you here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and your kind words. I am very glad we were able to reconcile. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Please review this [eighteen month old Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650874/are-transcendental-numbers-dense-in-the-reals-whats-an-algebraic-number) for possible Undeletion.

It covers a basic definition, property, and example in algebraic number theory.  I made a few minor tweaks to the wording of the title and the body.

It was closed earlier this month as "off-topic" and then Deleted a few hours ago, despite having four upvotes and six answers with a dozen upvotes among them.  [Disclosure: Its removal came to my attention because mine had two upvotes.]

Comment: It's a multipart question, which is bad already. The first and third part are duplicate of other questions, e.g. [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205294/algebraic-numbers-dense-in-r?rq=1) and [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257811/how-to-prove-that-cos-2-pi-n-is-algebraic). The second part shows no research effort whatsoever, and is mind-boggling: OP wants to know why transcendental numbers are dense, but doesn't even know what an algebraic number is?! And finally the question has no context. It's a horrendous question.

Comment: No, a question about algebraic numbers being dense in the reals is not a duplicate of asking if transcendental numbers are dense.  The request for definition of algebraic number does provide context for answering about density of transcendental numbers.  It is closely related, yet your opening criticism is "It's a multipart question, which is bad already."

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1024575 Did you seriously believe that the question wasn't a duplicate...? I made a mistake when choosing which one to link, I don't think it invalidates my point in the slightest. Asking what an algebraic number is in a question about density of transcendental number isn't context, it's laziness.

Comment: Someone who professes not to know the definition of "algebraic number" is not necessarily lazy, just ignorant, and this is something they have undertaken to correct by asking here.  Whether the Question is a duplicate is strictly speaking irrelevant to the policy on Deletion, and  you chose poor examples to illustrate duplication.  Referring a user (who asked in Jan. '14), to the Answer about using Baire category (asked/answered in Nov. '14, and which is only a "hint") was not an option back then, and scarcely makes more sense today.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot vote to reopen a question asking "What is an algebraic number?" (I just gg'ed `algebraic number` to check that the first link is what it ought to be. It is.)

Comment: @Did: Please note that a vote to Undelete is what I requested.

Comment: OK. What is the final result you have in mind?

Comment: You're being disingenuous, @hardmath. OP doesn't just want to know what an algebraic number is, they also want to know why transcendental numbers are dense, and if $\cos(\pi/17)$ is algebraic. To me, this screams "I was given this assignment, but I can't even be bothered to read the definitions of the words it uses. Please do all the work for me." The fact that the target duplicate didn't exist at the time is irrelevant now. And it doesn't change the fact that the post is multiple questions in one. And I have to join Did in asking what you want for this post if not for its reopening.

Comment: @Did: I am suggesting the Community review for Undeletion.  Since, as I disclosed in my original post, my ox is in small measure being gored here, I have refrained from casting an Undelete vote.  However I was frankly alarmed that the Question was deleted, and it would please me if this thread's established mechanism for Community review were able to revoke a decision taken by three non-moderators, only one of which has barely crossed the 20K rep threshold.

Comment: Sorry but I am not following everything you say (maybe some language problem on my side), and some parts that I am following, I almost certainly disagree with (non-moderators, so what? less or more than 20K, so what?). All in all, I understand that you do want the question reopened. To me, this question is very bad. Unless you have *clear* and *convincing* arguments otherwise, to me, this closes (!) the case..

Answer (score -3):

> **Undeleted,** **Re-deleted**, **Re-Undeleted** so that it could be **Mod-Deleted**

Undeletion of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/what-are-the-implications-of-the-discovery-of-the-kalle-numbers

The question produced many valuable, useful and highly upvoted answers, directly answering the question, the question itself was not bad, and other users have been wondering about the same, just that some seems to react on the way it was posed, but that doesnt break any rules so that shouldnt be ground for deletion. We cannot abuse our privilegies by deleting questions just becuase we have a personal grudge agaisnt the poser of the question.

Answer (score -3):

> **Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531441/questions-about-zfcu-zfc-with-atoms-in-second-order-logic): OP has edited it and I think can be reopened now. OP is not able to ask anymore questions, and looks a bit hurt/confused.

Comment: The grammar in that question could be tremendously improved (unfortunately I don't know enough about the subject to even make sense of the first question -- is he asking if something called "ZFC2U", assuming that's even the properly formatted name, is "categorical"?). IMO if you're going to post in this thread it would be nice to make the necessary improvements first -- in general it's even sufficient for the question to be reopened without posting here.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, neither do I, but I feel apart from that the question has what it needs to be reopened! Maybe someone in that field will notice and fix it!

Comment: The introduction of urelements into the axioms suggests some sophistication on the part of the asker, but the second part of their Question, how to express(?) "the cardinality of a set" seems either naive or to presume some subtlety that requires elaboration.  It might be expecting too much for an expert in the field to rescue the sense of this Question.

Comment: @JessePFrancis The editing that was done on this Question amounted to adding the second part of it, without any clarification to the first part.  I'm sure your intentions are good, but the frustration of the OP on having a closed question (after receiving a good answer on the first part) does not justify suggesting that flagging it for moderator attention may lead to a lifting of their question ban.

Comment: @hardmath flagging was suggested since he said he is barred from posting anymore questions and cannot access meta/chat.

Answer (score -3):

> **Reopened**

I had my question here:

[Is $22/7$ an often used approximation for $\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697176/is-22-7-an-often-used-approximation-for-pi)

put on hold. The reasons is "This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center."

I don't understand how this isn't about mathematics. I am asking about the use of the approximation $22/7$ for $\pi$. I am not asking about if this is a good approximation or how it came about. I am asking specifically about how widespread the use of the approximation is/was. How widespread was the use of this approximation in history? I could imagine that some might have done research on this very question or the more general question about the use of the approximation. That is all I am asking about.

I can see several ways to answer the question. One answer could simply be

Answer (score -3):

> **Reopened**

Could we please get one more reopen vote for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999121/fractals-and-cantor-set-dimension)?

First, the question is a common basic problem in fractal geometry and a good fit for this site. The original version of the question (when it was closed) was not well written simply because (I think) the OP is not a native English speaker. I've edited the question to hopefully improve it. It also has a solid answer.

Also, there's [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999016/fractals-similarity-dimension-and-cantor-set) on the site pointing to this one as a duplicate, which seems silly.

Finally, I think it's possible that some of the downvotes were for "missing context" due to apparent lack of effort. This is not a totally simple pre-calculus question, though, and it's not clear to me that such a vote is appropriate.

Comment: Context was never meant to be required for "totally simple pre-calculus questions" only, was it? Hence I fail to get the argument in the last paragraph, I am afraid.

Comment: The "duplicate" motivation in your previous-to-last paragraph is also rather odd, if one looks at the history of these two posts (basically, an OP abusing the system).

Comment: @Did As I said "it's not clear to me that such a vote is appropriate" indicating that I honestly don't know the extent of the intention of the rather specious "Missing context" rationale for closure. Perhaps that deserves yet another meta question. As far as the duplicate issue goes, I don't think the OP was abusing the system as much as not knowing the system. If your point is that both questions were asked by the same OP, well, then yes. It still seems odd to me to have one question closed as a duplicate of another that is ... closed.

Comment: If posting two identical copies of a question 90 minutes apart is not abusing the system, I do not know what is. And no, no "knowledge of the system" is needed to be aware that this behaviour is abusive, only common sense.

Comment: Why is that odd with the dupe? Would you prefer if both were closed separately? Then both reopened separately? If it is an identical duplicate of the same OP *clearly* it should be pointed out as such, via a duplicate vote. To reiterate the fact that was unclear to you for future reference, it is appropriate to enforce context also for advanced question, arguably even more so than for beginner's question. A specific suggestion for context was even made in a comment.

Answer (score -3):

> > [**Reopened** and **closed again**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2389916/revisions)

Please consider reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389916/minimal-closed-surface-in-3-dimensional-sphere-with-positive-curvature). I think it's completely fine for a graduate student to don't know where to start, if they never learnt about Hopf differential (which is not so much taught in nowadays course on minimal surfaces).

Review in the reopen vote queue [didn't go well](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/855093), as expected.

Edited: The question was edited again. Probably still not good if one has to judge it by the HW standard.

Comment: As it stands, this seems like a standard closure for a question with no source or motivation. Given that the only expansion of the question since closure was essentially "here is my question", this doesn't seem like a strong candidate for reopening yet. I've left a note for the OP, and I hope they will edit the question into something more reasonable.

Answer (score -3):

> **Deleted**

[Integration : $\int\frac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x+\cos^3x)^2}{\rm d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1176609)

This question does not seem off-topic, and has an interesting answer that adds content to the site. Consider re-opening

Comment: "This question does not seem off-topic" What are your reasons to think this? "and has an interesting answer that adds content to the site" What are your reasons to think this? I mean, except for the fact that you are the author of said "interesting answer"?

Comment: tbh it was not a self motivated post, i was going across my content and i just observed someone else (rather a reputed user) commented these statements. I seem to agree with it, and I do think answer involves a nice interesting technique which is rather not apparent at first sight. As far as question goes, it is an integration question, and context from OP might be lacking but doesn't make it off-topic in my opinion

Comment: @Did I mean I meant interesting from an average pov, you see not everyone is mathematically as sound as you. sometimes you gotta see it from a different pov. (mod edited)

Comment: It seems preferable to link to the question, not your answer. If you follow a link to your answer, such as from your profile, the URL in the address bar of your browser will be for your answer not the question. Clicking on the title of the question in the thread would be one way to resolve it. (I change it.)

Comment: @Did it seems OP was prompted to the action by  an (old) comment of robjohn. The post here paraphrases this comment. (I for one do not see the point of this type of content. Just to highlight that the self-praise is  not fully self-praise but a quoted praise.)

Comment: @quid Indeed. 1. The comment you are referring to had not escaped my attention since, as you can surmise, I had visited the relevant page. 2. I fail to understand said comment. 3. The reactions to my comment here by the OP go from the evasive (not self motivated but, context lacking but not off-topic) to the insulting kind (the disgusting "pedestal" stuff). If ever I needed to be convinced...

Comment: @Did: I did not mean to imply that you did not know it, sorry if it came across this way. I just thought there was some value in making it explicit here. Not everybody reading the conversation might follow through and study the full thread linked to. // I removed the pedestal stuff.

Comment: As a "puzzle question" (and with no context), this is very much off topic for this site. The purpose of this site is not for users to post questions for which they already know the answer.

Comment: I don't want to encourage people to post puzzles, especially if they don't also post a solution, and I don't want to encourage people to answer puzzle questions. And yet I feel that insofar as m.se is supposed to function as a repository of knowledge it's a shame to have this clever solution to an integration problem deleted. I wonder whether there would be support for an m.se question where we could gather the nice integration questions/solutions that are currently scattered all over the site.

Answer (score -3):

[Conditional expectation $E(Y^3/X^2\mid X/Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725446/conditional-expectation-ey3-x2-mid-x-y)

This was closed as "missing context or details". But this is not the kind of question that can be done in a routine fashion by plodding through techniques mechanically; rather it is challenging, for what it is. And the poster actually has the right idea but doesn't know how to supply the details. So this is not at all like copying a homework problem without understanding it.

Comment: This might be one of the most ridiculous requests I have seen for a long time... For the record, the question has no context and is mathematically wrong. The OP has been told so and, until now, is staying silent. 'Nough said?

Comment: "rather it is challenging": what is challenging? Finding a related correct question? Finding the context? Michael, if you want to know the truth I did not only vote to close but I also downvoted for the two reasons mentioned by Did.

Comment: @Did : "Mathematically wrong" is not a reason to close a question.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : The answer to the question in your comment would appear in my posted answer to the question. That a question has presuppositions that are mistaken is not a reason to close it; rather it affects the content of any posted answer.

Comment: See my comment on main, which I will not repeat here. Time to pass to something else, MH...

Comment: @MichaelHardy Even if this is not reason, "has no context" is a reason. This is implies that  "mathematically wrong and has no context" is still a reason. Except if you want to argue that being wrong makes up for having no context. Do you want to make this argument?

Answer (score -3):

> **Undeleted**

I feel that the following question should be undeleted and reopened:

[Can a countably infinite torsion group exist in which the density of squares is double the density of non-squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808895/can-a-countably-infinite-torsion-group-exist-in-which-the-density-of-squares-is)

It was closed because the question is, in a very precise, mathematical way, meaningless. However, naively the question makes sense. So I feel that my answer which explains *why* the question is meaningless and also explains how to get something more meaningful is worthwhile. At least, more meaningful than simply closing and deleting the question.

Comment: And the most important factor in your reasoning to reopen the question is that you answered it and want the rep you earned answering a meaningless question back.  (I wish folks would self-disclose their interest in begging to undelete and reopen a poof post.)

Comment: My understanding of the current consensus is that a good answer is not enough to salvage a poor question.  I agree with you that there might be an interesting question buried in the linked question, but the question itself is utterly unclear.  If you really want to preserve your answer, may I suggest that you instead create a new question that is well-answered by everything in your answer starting at the line "Now, how should we make it formal that 'half' of the integers are even?"

Comment: @amWhy I do refer to my answer in my post here (and I do find it rather petty to discuss rep - if anything, I spent a while working on the answer and would be disappointed if it was time wasted).

Comment: @Xander perhaps my underlying question is "why is this a bad question"? It doesn't tick the usual "rubbish question" boxes (they try to interpret their question, etc.). If a question is subtly meaningless, it doesn't make it a bad question (and if a student asked me this question I would spend a pleasurable hour discussing this question with them....)

Comment: @user1729 The question is not clear.  It begins by asking about the density of squares in a group, but ends up being about the right definition of "density."  Your answer begins with a discussion of *why* the question is unclear (so it seems that you agree that the question is unclear), before answering the question of defining density.  To my reading, you *never* address squares in a group, hence you haven't even answered the big, bold, boxed question that was asked.  The fact that you have to bend over backwards to clarify the question before answering is indicative of a problem.

Comment: Again, if you feel strongly that your answer should be preserved, *ask a better question*.

Comment: @user1729 So writing what you believe settles/explains the OP's confusion, and goes on to substitute some other interpretation, and all the help you feel you delivered, is a waste of time, unless it translates into points?  You are the one who is inferring that, without the upvotes and accept you got for the poor question, writing your answer amounts to having been a waste of time?  That's what I consider petty.  Maybe we have different definitions.

Comment: @amWhy no...it is the hiding it that makes me feel this. Noone will ever read it again :-)

Comment: As Xander Henderson pointed out:  Work on writing a better question that is not unclear, posting it, and answer it.  Then nothing is "censored" or "hidden".  Suggestion: do not repost the question you want to undelete, verbatim, because that would be considered "gaming the system".

Comment: That no one may ever read it again is a risk you run even if the question were undeleted.  I think the world will still orbit the sun, and most all of us will wake up tomorrow, even if they never read your answer.

Comment: @amWhy sure, it's a risk. But there is a difference between "definitely will never be read" and "may never be read". (as for asking the question again, the effort-to-caring ratio isn't great enough...)

Comment: Another suggestion, @user1729.  You won't run into a similar scenario often, if ever, if you restrict your answers to answering clearer questions, and/or hold off answering an unclear question until the OP clarifies what they mean in comments, in there posts, and/or working with the OP in comments to hypothesize what you think they might mean, so you, also are clear what the question is.  If the OP remains clue less, or edits a question with just as confusing edit, as in this case, you're better off not answering at all.

Comment: Well you cared an awful lot to post a self-interested request (after searching for this thread) to ask for it's undeletion and reopening, and wrote four comments up till now.  It wouldn't take you any more time to right a decent clear question, and answer it, than it took you to do all that.

Answer (score -3):

I have to suspect the reason why [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847048/monotonicity-of-ex-mid-y-y-and-ey-mid-x-x) was closed is that it is short.

This is an interesting question.

Answer (score -4):

> **This has gone through two cycles of a deletion/undeletion skirmish.**

While I agree that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319323/221811) is not well-written, and normally should not be on the site, I think that the nature of the (in fact, my) solution is interesting, and something that I think is worth keeping on StackExchange (and I suspect that the people who upvoted an answer to such a poorly-received question would agree with me). It seems a shame to delete the question if it means also deleting the answer. Could someone explain the rationale for deleting both, even if the question is not restored?

---

[Moderator note]

I implied at some point that I would delete and lock this question on September 10th, because I believed that the answerer would then get to keep their rep (as the question became 3 months old on that date). However, the correct rule is that 2 months is enough, but the question needs to spend that much time undeleted. We are still relatively far from that. A fellow moderator expressed the concern that deleting and locking the question now feels a bit harsh. Meanwhile the original poster has edited the question a little. I guess that means we need a round of re-evaluations, so do comment and/or act whichever way you see fit. Sorry about being wishy-washy, Jyrki

[/Mod note]

Comment: I did not vote. But the question  seem quite bad as is, thus it is deleted. The deletion of the answer is "collateral damage." While existence of good answers is taken into account, it is often not weighed that much. What should be done in a case where the question is initially quite bad but there is still something interesting, is to *improve* the question via an edit. This can still be done even while deleted (deleted posts can be edited).

Comment: I'm not going to take on the editing job myself, but it seems to me that if you let $$A={uvt+wsr\over w^2+u^2},\quad B={usr-wvt\over w^2+u^2}$$ then it should be possible to write the integral in a line or two.

Comment: I'm one of the users who voted to delete the question. I did so because I couldn't picture a single scenario where this Q&A would help anyone other than the OP. I believe that in the history of mankind, no one will ever *need* to compute this particular integral by hand; it was probably obtained from the simpler integral you found in your answer, and then applying random substitutions to make it look obscene. I also don't believe that, in the case someone would really need to solve the integral, they would find the Q&A unless they manage to write it exactly like the OP did, a feat in itself.

Comment: I did not vote to delete.  In its current form, the question is really bad and  useless to everyone. The answer is good, but not enough to counter-balance  the horror of the question (I strongly doubt anyone could produce such an answer). Chappers, you already have the joy to deal with this challenge, so just let the horror rest in peace.

Comment: @Najib, if I show you how to factor some particular 200-digit number, you may rightly point out that no one will ever need, or even want, to factor that particular 200-digit number. But someone may find that the method I have given for factoring that particular 200-digit number will enable her to factor some other large number that she really does need (or want) to factor. And she wouldn't have to write my 200-digit number in order to find the Q&A.

Comment: @achille, maybe I don't understand what you mean when you write, "I strongly doubt anyone could produce such an answer," as it is evident that someone has produced exactly that answer.

Comment: @Gerry (Maybe it's because of your particular example, but are there even humans on this planet that want to factor 200-digit numbers by hand anymore? Computers are so much better than us at this.) If the goal of the Q&A is to showcase the particular technique Chappers used (noticing a pattern using trig identities, finding the right substitution), I'm sure a less obscene integral can be used, and there's heavy editing to be done to make the question palatable and findable. I'm not willing to put in such work, but maybe someone is -- as it is, I'm still not convinced the Q&A is useful.

Comment: @Najib, I never said anything about doing it by hand. But even the fastest computers are useless at factoring 200-digit numbers, unless programmed with very clever algorithms. And the algorithm that factors one huge number can be used to factor others. I think the point of this Q&A is that even a really, really ugly integral can sometimes be evaluated if you go at it the right way, and to illustrate that, the uglier the integral, the better.

Comment: I am leaning towards deleting the question unless the question is improved. I believe that if I postpone the decision till September 10, then Chappers gets to keep the rep points. We are reasonably close to that date, so I'm inclined to wait.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: the continuing issue for the site, of course, is the multiple deletion votes by the same individuals. Right now there are 6 deletion votes by distinct individuals compared to 4 undeletion votes by distinct individuals. I want to continue encouraging the moderators to develop a policy about this -- would it truly be the desired outcome for the delete voters to just vote to delete again?

Comment: @CarlMummert: I am aware of that and factor it into my decisions. Formulating an official policy is more difficult. Ideally software could prohibit participation in multiple cycles. Your encouragement is duly noted.

Comment: @CarlMummert Au contraire, the continuing issue for this site, of course, is the thousands of deletions of valuable posts, by the same individuals.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry about the problem my question caused, I only found out about it today. I'll go back and edit it with the form achille hui posted in the comments later. That being said, while it may not be useful to the onlooker, I believe that it still contains value in techniques of solving these integrals.

Comment: Do your best @Vladimir!

Comment: @Vladimir Lenin: the problem with this question, like a certain number of integration questions, is that it has no motivation whatsoever. The question should describe where this integral arose and why its value is of interest.  Why not edit the question to include this information? At least two others requested this information in the comments of the question.

Comment: Regarding the new paragraph: all this squabble over 76 reputation points... (Reputation was, as far as I understand the motivation behind waiting to re-delete the question)

Comment: Why would deleting the question now seem a bit harsh? The same general facts still hold: the question is undeleted only because of multiple voting. It was re-opened for a while because others did not vote to delete because of the plan to delete the question on Sep 10 - the question was lacking only one deletion vote for some time before it was re-opened, so if they had not waited for the planned moderator action, the question would have been re-deleted and ineligible for re-opening.  But the question is now closed again, so it is in the same general state it was in before. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @Carl as a matter of fact a deleted question is eligible for reopening.

Comment: @Carl A question can be reopened while deleted. It  then is open, yet still deleted.

Answer (score -4):

I would like to request for undeleting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339824/how-to-find-the-next-number?noredirect=1#comment2724983_1339824). It was asked yesterday, closed and deleted now. The question might not be up to standard, in the sense that no effort is shown. But I think the OP at least should have more time to improve the question.

Comment: It should be mentioned that there is already a separate discussion about this particular question on meta (with a somewhat cryptic title): [Question closed over a valid Tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20868/question-closed-over-a-valid-tag)

Comment: But the OP already has all the time they want "to improve the question", no?

Comment: @Did : I don't expect others to stay connected to SE "continuously". I expect them to visit, for example, once a day and check all the information. In this case, I doubt if the OP has seen all the response of the meta thread yet (which might be helpful for the OP to improve the question).

Comment: Thus the motivation to reopen in the last sentence of your post here is offtopic?

Comment: @Did: Can you explain more?

Comment: You invoked time as a reason to reopen, I noted that time is NOT a factor, what is there to explain more?

Comment: @Did: Can you explain why it is not a factor? (and that's an undeletion)

Comment: I already did but here we go again: because the OP has all the time they want to improve the question.

Comment: @Did : Okay, so there's not much to discuss then. But think it this way: If someone ask a question on meta for an reopening of a question, and come back and see the question is even deleted. How bad is that as an experience in SE. I just cannot agree that enough time to deal with the question.

Comment: Said "experience" indicates that the call to arms posted on meta has been less effective than improving the question itself would have been (a task which does not interest the OP at all, seemingly). And *this* seems a quite suitable take-home message.

Answer (score -4):

> **Reopened, Reclosed, Deleted**

Some people have hair-triggers when voting to close a question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377205/injections-surjections-bijections/1377225

The poster is pretty thorough about giving his thoughts on the problem.  The fact the he's confused about the topic should not be considered a reason to close the question.

Comment: 1) I don't think this is a very good question (it seems like what the OP put forth was really motivated by an outside source, like from a teacher or some such source), and 2) I think the *real* problem in this case, and my main reason for voting to close, was that OP and *several* other users posted the exact same question in a narrow time window. The same thing occurred with a certain induction question yesterday. I think the hostile reaction(s) / votes to close were primarily due to the fact that there is improper behavior going on in reposting the same question via multiple accounts.

Comment: -1 for "hair-trigger".

Comment: Needs 1 more undelete vote

Answer (score -4):

Request for reopening: [Is there more than one looping sequence in the Collatz conjecture?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420133/is-there-more-than-one-looping-sequence-in-the-collatz-conjecture)

Votes to suspend and then close this question on the grounds that the question was unclear were rendered out of date by edits to the opening 3 sentences already within 2 days of the question being suspended. No voters seem to have checked back to find that the requested edits had in fact been made before the question was then closed.

Comment: Any advice as to how I can put the term 'Closed' into standard sub-head format most welcome, thanks.

Comment: Only the change in status is recorded, not the original status. It makes it easier to browse through the list by creating a visual difference between requests for which nothing has changed (and thus still require action), and those for which something has changed (usually the issue has been resolved). In general, if you want to see how something was formatted, you can click on "edit" on a post and see the source (without committing the edit, of course). I added a link to the question -- is it the right one?

Comment: Okay I'm confused by your latest edit. You want the question reopened, but you want it to remain deleted...?

Comment: My mistake, @NajibIdrissi. Wasn't clear on the distinction between closed and deleted. Thanks - that is the right link you attached.

Comment: There are different states a question can be in. Your question at the moment is closed (meaning no new answers can be given) *and* deleted (it won't show up in the search, only you and users with 10k reputation points can see it, it cannot receive new answers or comments). See the [help] for more information.

Comment: That explanation makes it clearer to me now. Appreciated.

Comment: I did warn you, at your earlier meta question, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21249/what-are-good-ways-to-ask-about-famous-open-problems, "By the way, if your question about a famous open problem is "Would someone please check my proof of Goldbach's Conjecture?" then it's pretty much guaranteed to be closed real fast, whether on m.se or on MO." Will Jagy also warned you, "Trav, that is not going to be a reasonable question. Certainly I always vote to close such things, and i do not read the attempt presented."

Comment: You did warn me, @GerryMyerson, that's true. On the other hand, neither warning covered the reason actually claimed for closing it. If anything, it was closed for _not_ using that phrasing.

Comment: People voting to close a question are presented with a very small least of reasons from which they have to choose. Sometimes the actual reason isn't among the ones on offer.

Comment: I see. So no obligation for reasons on the list to actually apply in a given case then? The list could always be extended so the real reason for closing a question could be one of the reasons on the list.

Comment: No, the list can't always be extended. Look, why don't you take a few months to familiarize yourself with how these sites work, instead of coming on like you know better than people who have been here for years?

Comment: I don't think I came on remotely like that @GerryMyerson. I've been polite to everyone here and thanked them for help & advice.

Answer (score -4):

> **Reopened, deleted by the OP**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606266/show-that-the-operation-x-y%E2%89%94-%E2%88%85-x-y-has-properties-op1-and) has been edited by the OP to clarify its meaning. I think it should be reopened.

Comment: Was there anything that prevented you from improving the question by correctly inserting the image in it, or even better, transcribing the equations in the image in mathjax?

Comment: No, there's nothing preventing me from transcribing the image. Is that a request you're making? My main point is that it's now perfectly clear what the OP is asking, contrary to the reason for closure.

Comment: It's my opinion that before making a request in this thread, one could at least make sure there are no glaring issues with the question one wants to be reopened.

Answer (score -4):

> **Reopened.**

[How to promote explanation of closure in comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22822/how-to-promote-explanation-of-closure-in-comments)

This question appears to have been misunderstood, apparently by people who read the beginning of a posting and decide what they think of it before coming to the part where it actually poses a question.  So I've deleted the beginning of it and put in a cross-reference to another question, of which it was alleged to be an exact duplicate but was not.

Comment: I'm not sure what a post on meta about a post that's still on the front page of meta is supposed to achieve. Can you explain?

Answer (score -4):

> **Reopened**, **marked as duplicate**

[Why is $e$ the number that it is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556943/why-is-e-the-number-that-it-is)

This is one of the best questions posted here and should be re-opened.  If I could post an answer I would mention the following.  It is easy to show that $(d/dx) 2^x = (2^x\cdot\text{constant}) \approx 2^x\cdot 0.69$, or $(d/dx) 10^x =  (10^x\cdot\text{constant}) \approx 10^x \cdot 2.3.$ It is only when the base is $e$ that the constant is $1$, thus: $(d/dx) e^x = (e^x \cdot\text{constant}) = e^x\cdot 1.$ This is similar to the reason why radians are used in calculus: $(d/dx) \sin x = (\text{constant}\cdot\cos x),$ and the "constant" is $1$ only if radians are used.

Comment: This is already given in a way, isn't it? (See par's answer, for example.) Plus, the entire question appears to be  a duplicate. Plus, it is  not explained well as OP does not say what $e$ does mean to them. They ignored a couple of explicit requests for clarification for a long time. Then they said "My question is more along the lines of why e is 2.7182… On an alien world [...], could there be a similar constant that has all the properties of e, but is not 2.7182…?" The answer to this is **obviously** "no"; with some specified properties, okay. But OP doesn't tell what prop "e" has to them.

Answer (score -4):

> **Deleted**

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1873248/53259

This was unilaterally closed based on a misunderstanding as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873248/in-fracac-frac-colorred1c-a-what-does-the-colorred1#comment3838975_1873248). [The screenshot here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873248/in-fracac-frac-colorred1c-a-what-does-the-colorred1#comment3838946_1873248) misleads and errs, because it fails to reveal my editing of the old question that caused the old question to look like the new question.

Comment: To copy Pedro Tamaroff's [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2tVGP.png), this is identical to a question which was closed by five users as unclear, and then deleted by three others. So at least nine users (+me) do not think these are good clear questions.

Comment: @T.Bongers That screenshot misleads and is the problem, because it fails to reveal my editing of the old question that caused the old question to look like the new question. Do you understand this?

Comment: Also, you requested the reopening of the original [in this very thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio/23239#23239). The request was badly received.

Comment: @T.Bongers No: the original old question and the new are NOT identical.

Comment: Regardless of whether they are textually identical, they are essentially the same question modulo some rearrangment of the text - certainly in terms of the vague parts about chestnuts and apples. Regardless of the history (which isn't, strictly speaking, relevant to this request): I do not think this is a clear question and I oppose reopening.

Answer (score -4):

> [**Re-opened**, then **closed** as *missing context*, then **deleted**, then **undeleted**, then **deleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2140225/revisions)

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140225/uniform-minimum-variance-unbiased-estimator-for-square-of-poisson-parameter) was closed as unclear, but it seems impossible to imagine a more clearly expressed question.

(It is also complained in comments below that "context" is insufficient. However, the missing context was supplied in comments under the question, where the original poster makes it clear what difficulties were encountered.)

Comment: I agree, this should have been closed for lack of context instead (although the introduction of the random variable $T$ makes no sense at present).

Comment: @Did The introduction of $T$ appears to be intended as the way to Rao‒Blackwellize a crude unbiased estimator.

Comment: Yeah -- and where is the OP following up on this? Oops, I forgot, they do not follow up on anything, they are just stating the problem they want to see solved for them.

Comment: @Did : The needed context is supplied by the fact that the OP is following up on this and explained in comments under the question what difficulties were encountered.

Comment: Sorry but no. The comment you are referring to merely adds an approach they were given. If the words in the comment were meaning anything to the OP, they would *follow up on them*, one way or another.

Comment: Wasn't this a bit too quick to delete the post? I see that the OP was not on the site since the closure, so they did not have a chance to improve the post. Should not we wait at least [the 5 days](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16820#16821) during which an edit can push the question into review queue? This would be probably better as a general question, but I do not have time or energy at a moment to open a new discussion on meta. @Did What do you think about this? (Sorry for ping you personally, but you are the only of the people who voted on that post who is pingable here.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Since your comment, the OP "came back" and the post was undeleted, but not modified in the slightest. Would a new vote to delete be seen as "a bit too quick" now?

Comment: @Did In my previous comment I hinted at possibility of posting a new separate thread about this issue. Now I noticed that it would be a duplicate of this one: [Are we too trigger-happy about deleting (relatively) new posts?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16725) In any case, thanks for your response both here and in the comments to the linked question.

Answer (score -4):

> **Undeleted**, **Deleted again**, **Undeleted again**, **Locked**, **Unlocked**, **Locked again**, **Merged with [Why do we divide or multiply by 2 when converting binary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262109/why-do-we-divide-or-multiply-by-2-when-converting-binary)**, **Deleted yet again**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492599/why-using-digit-2-for-representing-binary-system

It is not an off topic question. I propose undeleting and opening the qeustion.

Comment: I count three questions. 1) Why do we call binary base 2 instead of base 1, and why do we call decimal base 10 instead of base 9? 2) How was binary first made? 3) Is there any procedure for converting decimal to binary, rather that [sic] the process of converting them to each other? The first question is trivial: we call decimal base 10 because it's based on powers of 10, not powers of 9. The other two questions are incomprehensible. "off-topic" might not be the best reason for keeping the question closed, but then it's hard to tell whether an incomprehensible question is on-topic.

Comment: The comment posted by a mod, apparently to justify the locking, raises problems on its own (at least two major "theoretical" ones, after a cursory reading). If nobody else performs the task, and if I find the time, I might try to explain why. The "lock" comment: "While we value good questions and try to discourage poor questions, what we really want to encourage and help thrive are great answers. This is a cornerstone of the site and the network, and is emphasized in the SO Blog Optimizing for Pearls, not Sand. I've undeleted this question as I think it has a very nice answer. ...

Comment: ... Also consider rereading the suggestions on the deleting privilege. I am not reopening the question, though. – mixedmath♦ 19 hours ago"

Comment: Maybe we could edit the question a bit more; parvin, would you agree with somebody making some suggestions how to phrase the question?

Comment: @quid Which parts do you think are worthy of being saved? (This is not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @Did  one could have for the question post the questions quoted in the highly voted answer plus a little connecting text.

Answer (score -5):

I want to answer this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074870/how-meaningful-is-infty-frac12

Please reopen. I think it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Why the downvote? I have a good answer for this question.

Answer (score -5):

I would like for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219454/mathematical-induction-with-capital-pi) to be undeleted. It was originally unclear what OP meant because what was listed to prove was $\prod_{i=2}^n=\frac{n+1}{2n}$ for all $n\geq 2$, a clearly nonsensical problem. Fortunately, I realized what the OP *meant* was to prove $\prod_{i=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)=\frac{n+1}{2n}$ for all $n\geq 2$. Unfortunately, however, by the time I had finished writing up my solution, the OP had deleted the question. My solution took me a while to write up, and I would like to not have all of my work to go to waste for no reason.

Comment: Now you have an upvote and undeletion vote.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks Bill. And thanks for the link you provided earlier on that irrationality question. I didn't continue the comments because I actually addressed that my provided answer didn't *really* answer OP's question--which is why I didn't modify it so he'd accept. Thanks again for the helpful comments.

Comment: I hazard a guess that the downvoters felt that you were really begging for attention to your answer. Originally the well received answers in this thread (and its congested predecessor) had a more altruistic air - pointing out things that deleters or close-voters had missed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess that's a possibility. Don't see why it deserves downvotes though. I honestly don't care if my answer gets attention but I do find it to be very annoying to take the time to type something up that is comprehensive and well-typeset only to have the post deleted. And the suggestion by now uname pizza to post a question and answer seems like a very poor alternative. *That* begs attention IMO. But now it doesn't really seem to matter. Another negative experience.

Comment: As explained in the body of the post and in [other comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio/20166#comment74434_19783), "Only the change in status is recorded, not the original status. It makes it easier to browse through the list by creating a visual difference between requests for which nothing has changed (and thus still require action), and those for which something has changed (usually the issue has been resolved)."

Comment: You can post your answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/265483, a question that already has 3 known duplicates.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks for the link. Doesn't really matter at this point anymore. OP's loss.

Answer (score -5):

> **Reopened, Reclosed, Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted and undeleted again, Deleted for the third time**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422534/topological-space-that-is-not-sequential-and-not-t-0

This question was closed with a lack of context reason, but it is clear and requires no additional context. I suspect it was closed because an inappropriate inflammatory comment (now deleted), which I flagged, encouraged others to interpret the question as rudely imperative.

**Note (2016-09-02):** An improved form of the question is now at [Example of a topological space which is neither sequential nor $T_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912552/)

Comment: Needs 1 more undelete vote.

Comment: @Bill done, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Sigh, I accidentally clicked Delete when I was aiming for Reopen. Very poor UI design having them so close together, esp. when you cannot retract a delete vote.

Comment: I would like to vote to delete, but it seems that one of the two current deletion votes is unintentional; as such, I will refrain from being the third and consider this comment to "cancel" the accidental vote from @BillDubuque if anyone would like to cast the third.

Comment: @T.Bongers That's quite honorable. Thanks.

Comment: @BillDubuque that's curious. What is your set-up? I get a pop-up to confirm a delete (or reopen) vote? From your description  it appears you do not.

Comment: @quid Does anyone really read the popups? It would help if they were more immediately visually distinguishable (or if deletes were undoable).. But it is a rare event (don't recall it every happening to me before), so I'm not going to worry about it too much.

Comment: @T.Bongers  Bill Dubuque by now voted **twice** to undelete. In case you still care the post be deleted you might actually cast your vote.

Comment: @BillDubuque would I track it  would not have taken me a month to notice. Instead when this became reactivate, I was idly curious who now again undeleted that old thing (and the info is just a click away). But since we are talking about trivia and fun facts, what a coincidence you somehow independently bumped into that thread again.

Comment: @BillDubuque I am voting to delete ("again") because of the double deletion vote, as quid suggested. During the latest round of undeletion, you were the *first* voter - so I doubt that you came across it in the list of active undelete votes. That being said, the cynical part of me is starting to regret my decision to not vote last time....

Comment: I will point out that now there is [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912552/example-of-a-topological-space-which-is-neither-sequential-nor-t-0) asking basically the same thing, but it is probably less likely to get closed and deleted.

Answer (score -5):

I do not understand why this question has been closed and what is unclear with it:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754981/why-is-sum-k-1-infty-n-kn-1-sum-k-1-infty-leftkn-k-1n-right

Comment: Is it really necessary to reopen it just so that it can be closed as "missing context" later? This isn't your first rodeo, you know how these things work.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi what context is needed? I provided motivation in the comment but it is really interesting to me why these seemingly different series coincide.

Comment: Well, there's your problem: why is it in a comment? Work on making a proper question (read the guidelines on how to ask a good question if needed), and then ask here for your question to be reopened. Anything else will lead to what you've experienced: downvotes and probably votes to delete once your question is eligible.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I think it was closed because the closers did not understand what Ramanujan's summation is, not what you are suggesting. In itself it is quite curious coincidence to be interesting in its own.

Answer (score -5):

> **Reopened** and then **Reclosed**, and then **Deleted** by moderator Alexander Gruber

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23336/36639

This question issued some valid and legitimate concerns about the appearance of a new user name as a moderator.  It was by no means  obvious where this moderator came from or even if he is an on Mathematics SE elected moderator, before this got clarified in one of the answers.

So I think that question should not have been closed (unilateraly by another moderator...!).
(BTW Are unilateral closures by moderators not frowned upon on Mathematics SE?)

Please reopen

Comment: The question had been closed for less than two days and had four (?) votes to reopen when this answer was posted; it didn't really need an answer here.

Comment: *Are unilateral closures by moderators not frowned upon on Mathematics SE?* They are not except by very few users. Maybe you would know that if you were an actual participant in this community, instead of just coming to meta to stir things up. (You have half as many posts on meta as you have on main!)

Comment: @Dilation The prior comment is not very accurate. To get a more accurate assessment one can browse the prior threads here on such topics, where you can find many complaints about such unilateral closures, including some by prolific contributors, e.g. [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/unilateral-closure-by-moderator)

Comment: If you are interested, you can work out this mystery for yourself.  It took me a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque I know... :-/. And the fact that Gerry Myerson gets outright insulted by people including the moderator arjafi (!) for doing nothing but issuing legitimate concerns, whereas my (at least 5 times upvoted) comment pointing this out did get deleted, is a definitive deal breaker. I know that on all SE sites that strongly adher to the SE way of living, reasonable people who issue legitimate concerns get insulted and downvoted on a daily basis. But I did not expact this to happen here too ...

Comment: @Gerry The post has now been *deleted* by a moderator vote, which means that ordinary users can no longer vote to undelete. Imo, moderators should not invoke such superpowers when the subject has to do with moderation.

Comment: For the record, the question is deleted since almost **three weeks** (it was deleted on June 6th). Furthermore, the moderator vote was the second vote to delete, not the first. In addition the question had had two user delete votes earlier. That is, the moderator was at least the third user that had had the idea to vote to delete. (Personally, I did not vote on the question at all.) In addition @Gerry had been informed about the deletion then. It is a mystery why this is revisited now.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the question was deleted; it was a reasonable question the content of which was "Does it bother anybody that we have a moderator, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/arjafi, who "prefers to keep an air of mystery about them"? No? OK, never mind."  The asker was a user with 5 years experience on the site and 124k rep, which also suggests that the question might be given more credit.

Comment: @Carl "more credit" than what?  At least three moderators of this site interacted with the question, in addition to numerous users, some of them quite  experienced, too.

Answer (score -5):

**Deleted**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100198/covariance-of-conditionally-independent-random-variables

This question was clumsily expressed but its meaning was clear to me. It was unclear to people not accustomed to this kind of problem, and they closed it. I edited to clarify the question (and left a mathematical error in the question intact).

**PS in response to comments:** I am taken to task for "making assumptions" about the motives of those who closed the question. But I only said it was unclear to them, and they all said that themselves first. It's not an "assumption"; rather it is their own statement. And moreover, I know that those who are accustomed to this kind of question can understand it in the clumsy form in which it is expressed before I edited it.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the question is still in [reopen review queue](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/747796). (Reviews that are already finished are shown in the [timeline](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2100198/timeline), which is why the close review is shown there, but reopen review will only be shown there after the question goes through the review.)

Comment: Please stop routinely making assumptions about users who voted to close questions you want to see reopened. Unless they leave comments explaining their vote (here, they did not), you have no way of knowing their motives, or of knowing that they voted to close because they were ignorant of the subject (as you feel free to state). At first, the question **was not answerable** (for lack of a crucial hypothesis). Then the OP did add a hypothesis, but it was absurd hence the question was still unanswerable. Finally, the revised version mentions the needed, correct, hypothesis, hence one could ...

Comment: ... answer the question, unfortunately it is still severely **lacking of context** (sorry but a (wrong) formula for the covariance of two random variables does not count as context for a question mainly concerned with conditional distributions). For example, even before attacking their question per se, is the OP able to simply compute $E(X)$ from their hypotheses? They do not say, even after all the turmoil, and this lack is an indication in itself.

Answer (score -5):

I would like to reopen a self-deleted post *[What can I conclude about the solution of this linear system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194202)* (question ID: 2194202, [backup on Evernote](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s732/sh/fa599421-fac1-44d2-96f1-4cc669b672c3/56ac7bce4af6a1717115f5a02fe70d4a)) by AlexB since ["that's rude towards the answerer"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062962/how-to-go-about-solving-inverse-transform-of-this-by-hand#comment-4236354), according to our site mod.

Self-deletion of questions with answers of nonnegative score prevents others from answering and benefiting from them.  This is in conflict with the objective of this site.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I agree with the principle. In this case though, the answer lost due to the OP's bad manners is simply the transcript of some CAS instructions hence recovering it does not seem very necessary to me.

Comment: @Did If we focus the discussion on the *question* itself, it's certainly a math question (determine the existence of solution in a linear system), and I believe it can be solved if one can show that the determinant is nonzero. As we allow questions about determinant computations to exist, I see no reason why this question can't. Self-deletion prevents others from attempting this question. This is a loss to the site due to the loss of *original* contents, which is an important contributing factor when it comes to SEO. Moreover, the voting mechanism allows others to judge whether that's useful.

Comment: Did you read my comment? I said that the principle you explain in the question above and that you repeat in your comment is ok. *At the same time*... *in the present case*... I cannot help to note that the first answer posted contains zero mathematics stricto sensu and I cannot help to think that this is not a good sign regarding the possible arrival of mathematically consistent answers, should this question be reopened. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Did If you think that my answer is *not* good, you can downvote me, you can scold me for rubbishing OP (even in a direct manner). At least I know that my post doesn't even worth two cents. But self-deletion without a complaint prevents everyone of us to learn and to be improved. OK. You win the debate by criticising the quality of my answer, but who else? What's the benefit to other users who want to discover math and to the Stack Exchange site? The *question* itself has its mathematical value: *the determinant of a matrix with five diagonals*.  See [this](http://bit.ly/2nLonmg).

Comment: Again, you seem to not be reading what I actually write. To address only one of the straw men you build in your comment (there are several), nobody is preventing anybody to learn anything here. If you (or anybody else) think there is something of value to the site which is hidden in the question (be it a determinant of a matrix with five diagonals, or anything else), you can rephrase it more clearly and, if you think the rephrased question is a worthy addition to the site, post it. In short, the closure of a bad question that received no mathematical answer yet, is not the drama you make.

Comment: Quote from the question above: "Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure). That should be done in a separate linked thread. The goal is to keep this meta thread free of tension, so that everyone feels comfortable posting here. Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community."

Comment: @Did Interesting. You ask me not do *engage in debates*, but you're expressing your view points in your reply. So the counterexample to Euler's conjecture is not mathematics, since it's found by a computer program.  I've explicitly pointed out that this has prevented users to view this question, since even 10k users can't see the determinant of this question, and then you say "nobody is preventing anybody to learn anything here".

Comment: At this level of distorsion of my views, I feel difficult to find a reason to continue. Sorry.

Comment: Finally, this is not a *closure*, but a *self-deletion*.  The contents of a closed question won't disappear, and this won't have any negative impact to the site's SEO, but self-deletion of original contents on this site *will*.  There's a proper closing mechanism for handling this on this site designed by SE.

Comment: In cases where a Question (to which I've posted an Answer, or attempted to do so) has been self-deleted, I consider re-posting the Question myself as a better alternative (than overriding the OP's wishes).  This is general advice, however; I have not looked at the specific Question you are concerned with.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for your advice.  I'll take it next time I encounter this situation.

Answer (score -5):

> **[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2398552/revisions)**

[Are the elements of a set within a set also the elements of the latter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398552/are-the-elements-of-a-set-within-a-set-also-the-elements-of-the-latter/2398716)

I wonder whether any of those who voted to close this question as "unclear what you're asking" did not understand the question, or whether they simply disapprove of the clumsy and imprecise language in which the question was expressed. The latter should not be grounds for closing a question, but rather for including in one's answer something about how to express it better. In the former case, those who don't understand the question might realize what it says if they look at the posted answers, and then they will probably realize that they could have understood it if they had put only a little bit more effort into the matter. In this particular instance it won't take much.

**PS:** I now see that this question was quickly reopened after I posted this.

Answer (score -6):

> **Reopened, reclosed, deleted, undeleted, deleted by a moderator**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107734/finding-a-finite-sequence-such-that-sum-i-1nx-i-1-and-sum-i-1nx-i) was closed as off-topic for missing context or other details. In fact the OP did explain what he’d already attempted, so the relevant context was present from the beginning. It’s perfectly true that he’s missing something that most of us will find blatantly obvious, but that is hardly grounds for closing the question. Please reopen this question.

Comment: This reopening suggestion generated comments that first turned into a debate, but then started devolving towards personal insults. An automatic system flag was raised for the number of comments. I deleted the whole lot, because I couldn't find a break point that would not leave the impression that one of you was given "the last word". I think that the involved users already know how the others feel, so continuing this is pointless. You are welcome to start a discussion in a more appropriate meta thread. There I will promise to let our usual "free-for-all" live its course.

Answer (score -6):

> **Deleted**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1109237/85079

I'm asking about facts that demystify this question and explain the differences in difficulte, thus this is not an 'opinion-based' question'. I don't know if those quotes are true or not. Either way, why or why not? Please apprise me if I can revise my question.

Comment: [Related meta thread.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19314/how-to-improve-whys-applied-math-more-straightforward-than-pure-math)

Comment: Related: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/7247/77

Answer (score -6):

> **Reopened**

Did marked [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526085/probabilistic-proof-for-prod-n-1-p-n-0-considering-the-p-ns-as-para) a duplicate. Why is it a duplicate?

I made a slightly different approach to the same [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433567/prove-s-doteq-sum-n-1-infty-p-n-infty-to-prod-n-1-infty-1-p-n).

Comment: For [some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21950). (For the record, I am *against* the deletion of this meta post, which would only allow the OP to continue to rewrite history, a key part of their approach to this undeletion thread.)

Comment: @Did: That's weird, it seems that all answers to this meta questions should not be deleted.

Comment: @JohnMa Indeed, and some even less than others...

Answer (score -6):

May I request the reopening of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1786854/53259.

It would help to have constructive criticism on why `it was put on hold as unclear what you're asking`, because I do not understand what is unclear.

Answer (score -7):

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100876/2513

The administrator stated that he deletes my answer so to "prtect the answerer from further downvotes". I do not need such protection!

If the answer is dupklicate of the answer to another question, then please mark the **question** as duplicate, not the answer.

Please reopen this, because deletes questions contribute to automatic ban from the site. I would be much better with downvotes.

Comment: If the _exact same answer_ can apply to multiple questions, then that's a pretty good indication that the questions are _duplicates_. Even if you do not have the [close/re-open votes privilege](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you can still flag questions to be closed as duplicates, which places them in the close votes review queue for 3K users to decide on.

Comment: Also, significantly downvoted (undeleted) answers contribute towards being blocked from posting answers. In the future _please_ refrain from posting the same answer to multiple questions.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer deleted answers contribute more.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer also I wonder why my answer was kept in question marked as duplicate but deleted from the original question.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation that "deleted answers count more". In fact, you would probably have to write a metric ton of really crappy answers before you even came close to having your ability to answer limited. So that's pretty much a red herring as far as your appeal is concerned.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer I have already been auto-banned from Super User without any really crappy answers or questions.

Comment: As for why one was kept over another, while I have not spoken to the moderator involved, I would guess because they thought that the one kept was the original. Of course, that is a false assumption since essentially the same answer had been posted by you on [18 Dec 2014](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073101/8348).

Comment: @Arthur Fischer I suggest to undelete the answer and make from it a link to the original one with a brief explanation.

Comment: Obviously the users on SU thought that your questions were not up to par if you reached a question block there. Perhaps the users here don't appreciate your gaming the system by posting the same answer to multiple questions. If you do find yourself blocked from asking/answering, this will likely be the result of your ignoring signals given to you by the community.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer how answering non-duplicate questions is "gaming the sysrtem"? I did not post multiple similar answers in SU.

Comment: I was the handling moderator. I simply kept the older copy of the answer. Admittedly I did not look at the questions. The system, not unnaturally, flagged the newer answer as a duplicate, so that was the one I deleted. The later copy was also flagged by a regular user. If you wish I (or any other moderator) can arrange to keep the more recent copy and delete the earlier copy instead. Last time I looked the currently deleted copy stands at -3 while the other is at -2. Either way, one of the answers will be deleted, so I don't see the point of saving yourself from answering ban.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen thank you for your reply. If it is possible I prefer the answer undeled and one of the answers changed to a link to the already existing answer with a commentary that this answer already addresses the issue.

Answer (score -7):

> **Undeleted**

This [meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12224/242) deserves to be undeleted, not only because it contains interesting policy discussion, but also because it contains one of the richest meta answers ever posted (by Matt Emerton). I am completely baffled by the decision to  delete it.

Since many users do not have sufficient rep to see Matt's answer, I reproduce it below.

---

I would just like to record that I'm disappointed in the way this question was handled.  As zyx notes in a comment under Alex Becker's answer, there are numerous comments in this meta-thread that could have appeared as (at least partial) answers to the question proper.

Even if (in some people's view) the question admits a trivial answer, it wouldn't be the only such question on the site.   Personally, though, I find the question interesting; as someone who works in the area related to Wiles's proof, it's something I think about myself from time to time.

---

Added: To give one concrete example of an answer to the original question:

In the paper of Taylor--Wiles, a certain "non-canonical" projective limit is taken, and it is important to show that it is non-empty (indeed, the whole proof rests on this).  I remember being in the lectures at Harvard when Taylor first explained this (in the Fall of 1994), and audience members (Mazur, Serre, ... ) being shocked --- the whole thing seemed quite unnatural, and the non-emptiness was proved basically by a compactness argument (Tychonoff's theorem, if you like), which (at least naively) uses some form of choice.

This was disturbing enough to people in the field that some serious thought was given to how to eliminate this; in the standard text on the subject (*Modular forms and Fermat's Last Theorem*, ed. by Cornell, Silverman, and Stevens) the chapter dealing with this argument explains how to replace the projective limit and compactness argument by a concrete constructive argument that works at some (construcively determined) finite level of the projective system in play.

This reminds of various discussion Terry Tao has placed on his blog, where he explains how to go from "hard" finitistic analysis (with a lot of $\epsilon$-management) to more soft, infinitary arguments (say by applying non-standard analysis ideas), except here number theorists were going in the reverse direction, in order to convince themselves that the infinitary methods weren't really necessary.

If this kind of fuss seems strange to non-number-theorists, I should explain that for those schooled in number theory/Grothendieckian alg. geom./commutative algebra in the modern style, non-canonical infinitary constructions (that I imagine some analysts, or Ramsey-theorists, and so on, might regard as their
bread-and-butter) run very much against the established cultural view as to why
statements are (or should be) true.  Similarly, elimination of choice simply by "reduction to $L$" doesn't fit very well with number-theoretic culture; people expect more directly structural/conceptual explanations (where the structures and concepts involved should have to do with particular arithmetic objects in play, not general foundational ideas).

[By the way, I think this is an example of material that would have been better posted as an answer to the original question then on this meta-thread.]

Comment: That particular storm seems to have passed now, so I think that this reopening request deserves a fresh look.

Comment: @Jyrki The linked meta thread has actually already been undeleted since then (this request calls for the undeletion of the meta thread).

Answer (score -9):

Please undelete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019837/is-the-statement-the-sun-orbits-the-earth-true-false-or-ambiguous)

I know that the question might not be on par with the quality of the site. I am posting this answer as a genuine request. There are good answers by user Aaron and user Thumbnail.

Thank you.

Comment: One of the answer you are saying is good is literally telling you that your question is not about mathematics. You say yourself that the question might not meet the site's quality standards. Why should it be undeleted? Other users might stumble upon this question and believe it's okay to ask this sort of questions (off-topic, not up to quality standards).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Its just a request. If the community doesn't want to undelete it then thats ok. If other users stumble upon it then thry won't believe what you say because it is already closed and downvoted.

Comment: If you're going to post a request, it would make sense to explain why... And if new users find this question, they will see it downvoted, close (not even sure because it already has a reopen vote), and *answered* and *not deleted*. What's the message here? "Post your question, you will get an answer even if the question is bad and deserves to be downvoted and closed".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm not interested in debating. I posted this request because the question says this is a thread for doing so. If you have any problem then downvote, VTC, or VTD and leave. I told you previously not to communicate with me. _"What is the massage with those 15000 [closed question](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1)?"_ If they can be undeleted then why can't be mine? Now please leave me.

Answer (score -9):

> **Undeleted** then  **Redeleted**, and now **Undeleted again**, and now **Redeleted again**, yet now **Undeleted once more**. And **Redeleted automatically again**, **Mod-deleted**.

Please undelete this question. This was automatically deleted by the system because it has negative votes. I strongly disagree with this feature. Any user can downvote for whatever reason.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183087/integral-closures-of-algebras-of-finite-type-over-the-ring-of-algebraic-integers

#### Moderator note:

I have mod-deleted the question to end the deletion-undeletion ping-pong with [Community♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). It seems unlikely that this question would ever have reached a non-negative score again to prevent the auto-deletion (probably those who wanted the question to stay have already voted on it, and new passers-by upvoting it didn't come). Also, nobody has answered it, which could prevent auto-deletion too (if the answer got a positive score). If you think the question should be on the site, *ask a new version*.

Comment: But, if we undelete it, the system will just delete it *again.* With its silicon brain it can be very stubborn. Better ask a better question on the same subject instead.

Comment: If it is undeleted, an answer or an increase to a nonnegative score would keep it from being autodeleted.

Comment: @quid *Better ask a better question on the same subject instead* I have no idea how to make the question better. It is simple. And I wrote the motivation.

Comment: The question being undelete and you having found two upvotes to score it 0 atm the thing is somewhat moot (at least for a year). The question was not always in the form it is now, so even to repost it essentially in the form as is, would have been an improvement on the process of asking you had the first time. But also the formatting and wording could be polished, and the motivation you give feels kind of forced and not organically integrated.

Comment: @quid  "*the motivation you give feels kind of forced*" Indeed, it was forced. So what's wrong with me writing it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The motivation is not integrated in a good way and is generally not very convincing. It is better than having none at all though. So nothing is wrong with you writing it. It is just not overly good. Thus, the question was not received well. If you'd work on those aspects you might be able to ask questions that are better received.

Comment: @quid "*The motivation is not integrated in a good way and is generally not very convincing*" I intentionally separated the motivation from the question. Integrating motivation into a question obscures the question.
Many users do this mistake.

Comment: @WilliamCurtis there is a difference between separating motivation and question, and having sentences that feel a bit random thrown into the post. But, it goes without saying, you do as you see fit.

Comment: @quid, "The question being undelete and you having found two upvotes to score it 0 atm the thing is somewhat moot (at least for a year)." That "year" only took about three weeks, presumably because in the meantime the question got a downvote.

Comment: @GerryMyerson as I explained on the other question now with emphasis "The question was auto-deleted *when it reached negative score* **again.**" Yes, apparently it got another dv and thus fell under the 30 days script. Also in the comment you  quote I had emphasis the score 0 *at the moment.*

Comment: This is becoming a symbol of the struggle of human vs machine...

Answer (score -9):

> **Reopened, Reclosed, Deleted (by Community)**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617330/should-i-be-worried-that-i-cant-prove-these-theorems-on-my-own-yet

The notice explaining why this was closed says "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise".

I think that is wrong.  **"Specific expertise"** can play a major role here, very likely being the whole basis of all of the answers (as with mine).

Comment: I'm afraid that I feel I must point out that most of your answer in the thread is an explanation of the theorems that the OP can't prove, rather than an answer to the question. Without specific knowledge of where the OP is in terms of his or her mathematical education, answering the question of what they ought to be able to prove on their own is extremely subjective.

Comment: @T.Bongers : "point out" seems to imply that you're simply calling something to my attention that might have escaped my notice.  I think virtually everything in your comment is wrong and does not call to my attention anything that might have escaped my notice.  You say I have no specific knowledge of where the OP is in mathematical education, but the OP has been fairly specific about some of that, and I didn't assume any more than what the OP said.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to offend by my use of "point out." I was simply trying to soften my remark, rather than jump immediately into a statement of my objections; I didn't mean that something had escaped your notice. That being said, I do not agree that the OP has been specific about where they are in their education - real (and numerical) analysis is a broad field that can be studied in many ways at many different levels. Furthermore, even if you disagree with the current closure reason, I think that this *certainly* satisfies the closure reason about "seeking personal advice."

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with personal advice if it's applicable to a large population rather than just the individual user.

Comment: If this is really the case then the question and the answer can easily be rewritten to make it clear it's applicable to a large population. It's like "trivial" statements, if you can't prove it in a few lines it's not trivial.

Answer (score -11):

> **Deleted**

Such a harmless little question, what had it done to anyone to make them angry with it?

They put my question on hold after it has been here since April, what is up with that? You can find the question here... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249798/set-theory-and-1-0-999-dots

They said "put on hold as off-topic", I just want to know what that means.

In the help center it says...

*Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields. We welcome questions about:
Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems.*

And that is exactly what this question is trying to do, **understand the mathematical concepts and theorems of infinity.**

Since infinity is a difficult topic, that is often still in the research stage, would anyone recommend that this question be reopened on the MO site?

Comment: If the best argument you can find for your question to remain open is "it won't make the site crash" and "it slipped through the cracks back in April so now it should remain open forever", then I don't think you quite understand how this website works. In any case, your question was apparently nothing more than a soapbox for you to expose your... peculiar conceptions about limits and sets. The qualifiers "harmless little question" also appear to be at odds with the staggering 12 downvotes it received.

Comment: Does anyone know of a site where this question would be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm pretty sure MO would **not** welcome a question about $1=0.999\dots$.

Comment: *Since infinity is a difficult topic, that is often still in the research stage* The equation $0.999\ldots = 1$ is certainly not at the "research stage" anymore! Nor is the fact that $1$ does not belong to the set $\{0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \dots \}$.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi, If what you say is true, then someone should have been able to link to a lecture, website or a book that covers the question of $\ 1 \in \{\,0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \dots \}$, but nobody does that, they only make assertions that this is the way it is, and everybody knows that.

Comment: The sky is blue. Do you need a link to a lecture, website or book to confirm that?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi, You just confirmed what I said. My question is not in the literature and the answer is not at all obvious, but for some reason everybody thinks it is obvious. Can I ask you who told you that $\ 1 \notin \{\,0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \dots \}$ is the case or how did you figure it out?

Comment: You got 13 different answers to your question. Read them. I don't see the point of rehashing it all out here.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi, I asked you how you figured it out and you bring up the 13 answers in my question. Does that mean that before my question and those 13 answers, you did not know if $\ 1 \in \{\,0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \dots \}$ is true or false?

Comment: Please stop harassing me, thanks.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi, thank you for time and input, I wish you well.

Answer (score -11):

**Deleted, undeleted, redeleted.**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054039/umvu-estimator-for-distribution-function-and-density

Sometimes students post a question that they don't understand, and no actual question about mathematics is present in their own mind. That is a reason why in some kinds of cases, one asks for a demonstration of some effort to answer the question.  Is this such a case? Is there someone who thinks it is? Can someone who thinks it is such a case argue in favor of that proposition? Can someone among those who closed this question answer it? As I said in my posted answer, I don't know a way to get to the bottom line without numerical methods. Does anyone?

Comment: Currently 3 votes to reopen, and 2 to delete.

Comment: Why is nobody who wants this question closed willing to say anything?

Comment: @hardmath : What sort of context do you have in mind? The meaning of the question is perfectly clear, and that's certainly more than can be said for lots of questions posted here.

Comment: Again, I'd be happy to discuss this in chat if you ping me there.

Comment: I voted to close because of lack of context. I don't always expect someone to post actual work, since it might be just musings, I want to see more than just a totally standalone question. Now as with every non-math rule, I note the exception is for questions whose answer is exceptional or useful or insightful or helpful in some way. This one I could have gone either way, but since the answer itself was incomplete, I judged that the use to the future would be closer to tossing around some ideas than a concrete thing with a complete answer that could be referenced for the benefit of others.

Comment: More or less the same reasons as Adam Hughes. I do not plan to justify _all_ my votes, especially when the 30th question of a user looks a "do my work question".

Comment: MichaelHardy: This has happened many times now so let me signal a disturbing fact. You repeatedly see fit to ask, rather stridently, for explanations about standard actions of others, your subtext being that such actions are in fact nefarious and signalling some crucial dysfunctionality of the site, that you wish to modify. But when you receive cogent explanations about said actions, like here, *you stay silent and just move to the next installment of the same scheme*. Sorry to be blunt but, to my eyes (and, possibly, to some others'), such a behaviour is simply ruining your credibility.

Comment: @Did : "Standard" actions are often perfectly justified, but also sometimes knee-jerk reactions. There is currently no way to notify those who close a question that their decision is being discussed. Two such people when I contacted them by email reacted somewhat favorably to the idea that their notifications ought to include that. If they never find out that discussions are happening, then a knee-jerk response never gets any further calibration. Why should there not at least be routine notifications of the sort that occur when someone comments on your posting?

Comment: I do not feel this is addressing the point in my comment at all, but hey, no big deal.

Comment: Now 4 votes to reopen, 1 to delete.