# Editing closed questions to add answers

Tags: discussion, editing, policy, closed-questions

Recently we have seen quite a few instances of users editing questions that are closed to add their answers to the body of the questions themselves.

That is a *clear* subversion of the rules and an *abuse* of the editing powers that come with reputation. Questions that have been closed have been closed —in the immense majority of cases— by votes of the users of this site, and it is doing a disservice to the site to sidestep that decision.

If someone thinks that a question should be reopened, then posting in [the meta thread dedicated to precisely that purpose](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) is a correct way of proceeding. Voting to reopen is of course also good, and going into chat to campaign is quite fine too. Flagging for moderators to reopen questions is rarely ok.

Comment: Can we get links to instances of this? I've never seen it - and I have a rather different take on it if this is done by users who should know better vs. by new users.

Comment: It cannot be done by new users, because new users do not have the power to edit other people's questions.

Comment: I'd rather not add links to examples. I think it is rather obvious that this behaviour is against the rules, irrespective of examples. And there is no need to name names.

Comment: @Meelo: If it is being done by <2K users (without the [edit everywhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege), then the edit has been approved by higher rep users (and the approvers should be temporarily banned from the review queues for this). After gaining 2K rep they no longer need to have edits accepted by others, but it is expected that they edit responsibly.

Comment: You can add an answer to a closed question while it's still closed? That sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @RandomVariable, he seems to be describing people with enough points to edit a question that was not theirs, adding content to the question which amounts to what they might well have posted in an answer, had the question not already been closed. Only editing, no bug as far as software.

Comment: I **am** describing that. :-) Randomvariable, that is why I wrote that the answers are added *to the body of the question itself*.

Comment: Has anything been done to those who did it? I would have thought that this was a clear enough violation of basic decency (maybe that isn't the right phrase...) to warrant a modest ban.

Comment: Two related question: a) What should be the course of action if one notices this? Flag, rollback, both, neither, something else? b) What about full answers given in comments well after closure?

Comment: @quid My ideas: (a) editing an answer into a question should be rolled back, as an invalid edit; (b) nothing to be done there.  Overall, I don't expect this to become a major trend: there is no rep to be gained from edits or comments.

Comment: @Fundamental: depending on the precise nature of the objection against the edits this might or not be reasonable. It seemed the objection raised was that it subverts the moderation process. This is also true for the comments. If the objection is the edits are merely invalid the situation generally becomes more subtle as there is then a line to be drawn between what is allowed as adding context and what counts as "invalid answering."

Comment: @quid I consider an edit invalid if a question ceases to be a question (answer is contained therein, so nothing is being asked anymore). If after an edit a question becomes a better question, that's clearly different.

Comment: @Fundamental So it is just a matter of adding or not "Is this argument correct?" at the end of the edit?

Comment: @quid Okay, there is also a difference between (a) improving the presentation of the question that was asked; and (b) replacing it with another question.  In any case, the issue of edits is always going to remain subjective: they should not deviate "too far" from OP's intent, but how far is too far depends on whom you ask. I had some of my edits rolled back by another user who felt they changed too much of the question; this is normal disagreement about the desirability of a particular edit.

Comment: @quid There are finer points, but I think everyone can agree that adding the whole answer in the question (closed or not, but here the goal was to be able to answer a closed question; the user bragged about it on meta recently), even with a "Is this correct?" to keep up appearances, is too drastic an edit, and an abuse of the system when the goal is to answer a closed question. IMO even adding a half-baked answer is a too drastic change, but I don't expect everyone to agree (some people think it's the only way to add context to a question...).

Comment: I am the proud inventor of this technique. And I don't need to keep up any appearances. I did it to show just one of the **many ways** in which stopping users from getting timely answers if they haven't "begged" enough by adding any sort of messy attempt, makes no sense and is never going to produce any good results for this site. As I have said many times. A collaborative website, is not a classroom. I agree with questions getting closed when they are not questions, or when they are not about math. The closing procedure is the one that has been subverted.

Comment: @Pp..you may disagree allyou want,and you may argue here and elsewhere about closures and what not.What you **may not** do is to override the policies of the site.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I can't argue with that. That is the truth and the whole extend of that truth. I **may not** override the policies of the website.

Comment: But there other truth is: You (plural) **can not** fight against the nature of this website.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi why is it better when a whole answer is added as a comment instead? (To me editing the question even seems *relatively* more defensible by the reasoning I gave, whence my believe that comment-answering  in extreme forms should also be covered by this policy.)

Comment: @quid Because it is new and therefore scary. If the OP is not the only one that (in a collaborative website) can make a question "have context" (in the bizarre meaning some use it here) how are they going to force students to work harder?

Comment: @quid There are fewer constraints on what an edit can be vs. what a comment can contain. As far as I'm concerned, users are free to put whatever they want in comments (and many do put complete answers there), as long as they don't fall into the rude/offensive/too chatty/not constructive categories. With the understanding that comments may be deleted for any reason, of course.

Comment: @Pp.. You may think it is bizarre, you in fact may think anything you want. On the other hand, you surely appreciate that it is inacceptable for you to impose your views on the site. To be honest, there are very few things I care less for than whatever it is you seem to believe «the true nature» of the site is.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I am not imposing anything. Without me already the website works in the way I am describing. I am only showing its most extreme form, to bring attention and make more evident the irrationality of that policy of showing effort.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez To be honest, I care even less what you think and what you do.

Comment: Well, that will result in suspensions and so on. No one appointed you «shower of extreme forms» of anything. As you clearly realize (in fact, you do this on purpuse), that is disruptive of this site, and will not be accepted.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Anyone with a basic knowledge of internet knows that you can suspend an account. You can't suspend a user.

Comment: @Fundamental Alright, I understand *your* point of view. But to me this does not align with OP that puts forward as main objection, at least so my reading, that closed questions are answered. Moreover as you mention deleting such comments, do yo propose to flag them? If so as what?

Comment: @quid I mentioned deletion for completeness of the description of my understanding of commenting. I would not flag a comment-answer. My (well-known) preference is to delete the question itself.

Comment: @quid It's not better (to add full answers in the comments). I'm on mobile right now, but there have been a few meta threads about this issue, and the community has been critical of answering closed questions in the comments every time (I'm still waiting for a certain user to explain to me what could justify adding the answer in the comments instead of waiting for reopening, but as usual it was a fruitless exchange).

Comment: @quid Returning to "What should be the course of action if one notices this", I'd like to mention one more option: put a delete request in [RUCD room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It seems we essentially agree. Possibly you are thinking (also) about this one http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17281/closed-questions-fully-answered-into-the-comments // Fundamental: this is an interesting option.

Comment: @quid Yes, that one in particular. It's also been debated in the comments of many threads, eg. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16734). The same users often brag about breaking the rules in this way and most of the time they are thankfully in the minority.

Comment: I didn't read the comments to this question, so I might be missing on some already given information. What is the problem with editing questions with the intent to make them acceptable? If it is the case that people are making trivial edits to more easily get them reopened, then this should be specified in the question. As it stands, you criticizing all edits, not just some.

Comment: @GitGud, I am criticizing **editing closed questions to add *answers* to the body of the question**, as I hoped would be evident from what I wrote, which is quite not the same as «criticizing all edits»...

Comment: @GitGud: You don't have to read all of the comments, just the first sentence in the body of the question, to see what is being criticized.

Comment: I'd assume Git Gud just understood "the body of the question" as the thread of the question, not the question-post.

Comment: @quid: Thanks, that must be it. But then the implausibility of a moderator posting to complain about all editing of closed questions could encourage one to read the comments at least to Will Jagy's clarification.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez quid is right. I've never seen what you're describing happening.

Comment: @GitGud, you haven't because we have taken care of it and reverted it in all instances.

Comment: @GitGud: I hadn't either at first, but was able to find an example after someone posted above that it is something they do.

Comment: Indeed, if I ever come here and write a post against all editing to closed questions, please have the SE staff ban me from the site.

Comment: I think the comments have reached ridiculous proportions.