# doubt regarding what kind of question can be asked on MSE

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Can I ask a question about book recommendation on MSE? I'm not sure whether that would be against the quality standards of MSE or not.

EDIT: I found the book recommendation tag on MSE with many questions asked under the tag, so I gues it would be okay to ask for book recommendations.

Comment: It depends how you ask it. Simply asking "what is the best book to learn algebra from?" is a bad question (high school algebra, or abstract algebra? Also, any answer will be opinion-based, due to the word "best"). Saying "I've finished the book X and really liked the topic Y; is there a standard text I can move on to now?" would be better.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: Also, it is worth searching to see if your specific question has been asked before. People not searching first is often a factor when a book recommendation question is poorly received.

Comment: You can find some older related discussions here on meta. For example: [How to properly ask a “textbook recommendation” question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29272)

Comment: Asking a *good Question* on Math.SE is not assured by using an existing tag.  Do your best to frame any *book recommendation* request in a way that Readers don't have to guess your background and goals.  Check out some of the previous Questions with that tag to get an idea of what *context* contributes to successful answering.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you ask it. This is true of every type of question*, but it is easy to forget about when asking for a book recommendation.

Simply asking "what is the best book to learn algebra from?" is a bad question (high school algebra, or abstract algebra? Also, any answer will be opinion-based, due to the word "best"). Asking "I've finished the book X and really liked the topic Y; is there a standard text I can move on to now?" would be better.

I link hardmath's suggestion in the comments: look at the tag and try to see what would be required *before* posting. You should look at both good questions and bad questions. For example, if you have enough reputation you can see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3863947/10513) question, which is pretty bad and was closed as a duplicate. However, the linked question there is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46482/10513), which is excellent.

*Just because there is a group theory tag doesn't mean I can dump all my group theory homework here - I'd have to craft my questions nicely.