# What should a $<3000$ user do when a question is good enough to reopen.

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open

What should a $<3000$ user do when a question is good enough to reopen.

Consider a question was bad but it get better by editing now what should a $<3000$ user do when it is good enough to reopen?

Comment: @Asaf KaragilaConsider me what can I do?

Comment: You mean someone with *less than* 3000 points? Because we have an agreed upon symbol for "less than", $<$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila less than 3000 reputation.

Comment: Are you asking about what to do when it is your own question, or when it is someone else's question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question got closed, the first edit will put it in the reopen queue, where users will review it and consider whether or not it should be reopened.

Note that this is a one-shot chance. After the first edit (by yourself, or someone else), the question is put in the reopen review queue, and if it does not get reopened, it will not be put there again. So make that edit count.

After that you can use the [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 01/2015 - ) [current version]](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) thread, in which you can post a short request explaining why you think that the question should be reopened. You can also use the chatroom aimed for such requests, however, it's not clear how many people use that chatroom so it might not be the most effective way.

What you *shouldn't* do, however, is delete and repost your question; and preferably avoid adding to the question itself meta-requests for reopening. Those belong at the comments, at best. The question should be about the question (one exception is when your post is marked as a duplicate, and you wish to explain why it's *not* a duplicate).

If none of that worked, then you have to accept---at some point---that the community has chosen to close your question and move on. What can you do after this? I don't know.

Comment: It is not mine.I could give reopen votes if it was mine.But helpful.

Comment: Then work at getting the rep required for the privilege, @Taha.

Comment: @TahaAkbari As far as edits are concerned, it does not matter whether the post was your. But there are still some further conditions for an edit to push the post into the reopen review queue. For example, it has to be within 5 days of closure. For details see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Then isn't that a loophole? Someone could make a trivial edit, putting it into the reopen queue but giving it a low likelihood of being reopened..

Comment: @user21820 That's why it is advised not to make trivial edits soon after a question was put on hold. That's exactly point of the post I linked above. (I agree that some users might edit a post without knowing that they push it into reopen review queue.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Of course good users (who know of this) won't do that. But users who have not-so-good intention might.

Comment: @user21820 I think that it is done more often by users with good intentions who do not know about said rule. But still, there are many other ways to get a question reopened. I think this does not happen often enough to get worried about it. (In fact, I have made it - unintentionally - a few times. I was editing post and then found out that it was put on hold before I finished my edit.)