# How could I attach a pdf file?

Tags: discussion, support

How could I attach a PDF file through my questions?

Excuse me for this question, but I have much trouble to do this!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: [Can I upload a pdf file along with a question/answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1982)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attaching pdf-files to posts is not supported.

You can only include an image. For details how to do this see [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Of course, you can upload your pdf someplace on the internet and link to it.

However, please note that to the extent possible posts here should be self-contained, and including images should not be used as a quick-and-dirt substitute for typing up a question.

Comment: Dear quid, many thanks for your nice answer!