# Where can I ask about a result?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

It happens that I proved an elementary result about the commutant (or centralizer) of a matrix; the result is elementary but nice and can be useful; the method is also elementary.
my first reaction was "it is known", but I did not find, I asked colleagues , no one knows.
Then I decided to ask on Mathoverflow if the result is known; the question was refused then deleted.
Taking this into account I went to stackexchange, same reaction.
May I ask : what is the good forum to ask colleagues about a new (or not ?) result?
I apologize for my poor English.

Comment: Elementary questions are on-topic for this site, while they are *not* on-topic on MathOverflow. As such, you can probably ask here on MSE. Did you already try that?

Comment: I don't see any questions of yours here since 2015. I don't see any recently closed or deleted questions on matrices. What are you talking about?

Comment: "I went to stackexchange, same reaction"  Which Stack Exchange site are you referring to?

Comment: my question was deleted last days from mathstackexchange and, before put on hold and desappeared from mathoverflow.
the subject: simultaneous trigonalization (or block trigonalization) of the commutant.

Comment: If needed I give more details; I admit that the result is elementary and I admit the proof is elementary. nevertheless it is interesting,taking into account the interest in the question of commutativity and nilpotence etc...
So my question was : is such a result known ? I did not get any answer except reactions insisting that it is not the goof place, ok so what would be the place ?

Comment: You can try editing the question. That should put it in the review queue. Maybe the edited version will receive a better reception than the original, and it will be undeleted and reopened. If it goes through the review queue without being undeleted, then you can use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio to ask for undeletion and reopening (but be sure to link to the question, or no one will know what you're talking about).

Comment: I will add link to Math.SE copy [Simultaneous trigonalizability of the commutant of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2396796) and link to MO copy [Trigonalizability of the commutant of a matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278944/trigonalizability-of-the-commutant-of-a-matrix) of your question. (Since they are deleted, apart from the OP they are only visible [to 10k+ users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).)