# Why do even high reputation users do not pay attention on close votes?

Tags: discussion, closing

Recently, I have seen high reputation users, and top-reviewers (Such as amWhy, Shailesh etc.) voting for closing of questions, just out of the way. [See this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2648960/421580). This is a nice question IMHO. It has a $100 \%$ attempt from OP, and is not at all off-topic. Yet, it was voted by amWhy first, to be off-topic. Seriously? Other respectable users also followed and voted to close the question. Not one or two, every five of them thought that this question should be closed.

The question I linked is closed under the head  : **"This question is missing context or other details"** (At the time of posting this question)

What I understand is, that when users see, say, 3 close vote, they don't bother to read, instead, they close vote assuming those 3 must have read that and might be correct.

Can't we do anything and take a strict action to avoid this scenario in future?

Comment: In case you are not familiar with it, if you want to request users to reopen a question, you can post an answer at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19042/18398

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes, I am familiar with that, but I don't want to. My question is not for this particular question, this is in general. Even I could have voted to reopen that (I haven't yet) but didn't, because if it's reopened, this question won't make much sense.

Comment: This kind of question (yours, here in meta), with that kind of phrasing and assumptions, tends to be very controversial and may also be seen as somewhat rude, since you assume that no attention has been taken when it can be the case that it is just something you disagree with or something wrong you've not seen, and can also be an isolated case (I am quite surprised with no downvotes at the time of writing this comment). That said, I also disagree with the closure of the question (in main), and tried to vote to reopen (it was already reopened).

Comment: Note also that voting to reopen won't make this question senseless: one can see the history of closure and reopening of questions, if they so desire.

Comment: Perhaps a good design change would be to stop showing people what others voted for - only show that people did vote close. That way people really have to have read the full question to see what's wrong with it and what to close it for. As another free plus that comes with that, if people do decide to vote close without having reviewed the question, the chance of them picking the same thing to close it for as the other people that voted to close it is smaller, so their "random" close vote is less worth in that sense.

Comment: @Aloizio Although in this case, since the question hadn’t been edited, one must play with the URL a bit, to see the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2648960/revisions) (in particular, change “questions” to “posts”, keep the post number and not name, and add “/revisions”).

Comment: @pjs36 Didn't know that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It would have been appropriate for @mixedmath to have commented or answered here, in meta before/immediately after they unilaterally reopened the question.  I've rarely, if ever, seen a mod take action without commenting and/or explaining their action.  Why mixedmath did so behind the scenes only, is questionable.

Comment: And Jaideep, of course, it would have been more honest for you to have also shared that you answered the question, and so have invested self-interest in the posting to meta, in an accusatory, victim-like rant, in hopes you MSE answer to the question remains. In any case.  (Note,  I nothing to gain or lose when voting to close or not.)

Comment: @amWhy I don't understand that what do you mean by honest here,in this context. Suppose, I tell that I have answered (though there is no need to do so), will it alter anything? Also, I ain't at all concerned because I answered it. I would have posted on meta, even if it wasn't answered by me. Though, it is still unexplained why was this voted to close as off-topic in the first place.

Comment: You're right, @JaideepKhare - this question absolutely should not have been closed. I understand the original dupe-closure (based on a quick reading of, especially, the first line). This is well written with full context, plenty of work by the asker, and has a concise and direct answer; in short, it's a great question. Maybe there's context that I don't see (quid mentions something about rude comments that aren't there anymore... but that's not a reason to close anyways), so I really strongly disagree with the closure.

Comment: That being said, I think that your title is misleading. I do not believe that this is a case of not paying attention; I strongly suspect that at least some of the users fully intended to close this question after reading it. In that case, it would be a case where five users have standards that lie somewhat outside community norms, not a case of misunderstanding.

Comment: @user296602 "Is your mom proud of you now?"; "Do you understand english language?" are two of the deleted comments.

Comment: @quid I see, thanks. That probably did encourage several of the close voters here - I am certainly more inclined to vote for closure on a borderline case if I see the asker behaving badly, so it makes more sense to me now.

Comment: Dear all who seem to be of opinion that i was being rude. Firstly my questiin was very clear, and after it got closed or close vote only then i added that comment. Also, it wasnt meant to be rude, i just happen to have a weird humour sense. I was just surprised how even after mentioning every detail i could think it got close vote. I apologise if I must for the comments.

Comment: But mind you, none of my comments came before the close votes.

Comment: @KingTut you misrepresent the situation. Possibly inadvertently. I have no time right now but I can restore the full timeline. You lashed out right away on the first **duplicate** vote [actually flag] (not off-topic). Had you just explained why it is not a duplicate instead, nothing of all this would likely have happened.

Comment: @José Sorry, but I think you're **again** close-voting wrong question. (*Again*, because you too were one of the close-voters to the closure of linked question)

Comment: "*Again*, because you too..." warrants unnecessary conversation and may be taken offensively. I'd recommend you explain *why* the question shouldn't be closed as a dupe of that over trying to cause a scenario.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Don't be sorry. You are right; this question was *not* a duplicate and I've retractad my closing vote. But about the other question... I'm confused. Are you sure that I voted to close it? I don't remember having ever seen it and, yes, the OP made an effort. If I did vote to close it, it was an error.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2648960/timeline#history_8eb7004e-7e09-4944-b6ad-5fab4d287d37). Indeed you did vote to close it, though one cannot discern for what reason.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you. Then there was an error of judgement from me.

Comment: "Can't we do anything and take a strict action to avoid this scenario in future?" No, avoidance is not possible and indeed not something I'd be looking forward to. Those who think the post should be closed, for whatever reason, just or not, should have their right to vote to close, and if the reason is indeed not just, then it should follow by popular opinion the question should remain open, and hence they shall have their right to vote to reopen.

Comment: @Simply I added "Again because..." because José has voted for too many close votes till date. May be, he doesn't remember voting for this. BTW, I added "Sorry", in advance, to avoid any offense.

Comment: "I added "Again because..." because José has voted for too many close votes till date." That's a fairly generalized implication, and I'll have you know I have almost the amount of close votes José Carlos Santos has in total (close votes, delete votes, and other votes). Does that mean my close votes are always or often wrongly placed? I honestly did not think your line of reasoning would be so negative.

Comment: @Simply I think there is some confusion. José voted for closure of that question. He also voted to close as duplicate this meta-question. That's why I added Again to remind that he was one of the close-voters for the linked question, and he is probably committing the same mistake to wrongly close-voters this meta-question. I don't see anything offensive here . Is there any problem with this comment?

Comment: I have been quite irregular user on meta and even on the main site for the past 6 months and there is a huge reason behind it. I made some attempts like Jaideep earlier and saw myself being criticized and rebuked (what I like about MSE is that people here often say much more in very few words) and disappointed by all that I stopped making efforts as I thought I am either too immature to deal with the things going on or too mature so as to leave this all as my intention of welfare of community wasn't accepted

Comment: ....Furthermore coming to the question I would like to say that yes!! You have prevailages and badges but it doesn't mean that you can do whatever you want. I know that you can't know how much efforts OP has put in the question (in real life) but closing certainly isn't the way to deal with such things. I have seen questions closed as off topic and unclear in less than 10 minutes which in my opinion were well written and well explained but I don't know what these [users] have in mind while closing these questions.

Comment: "...because José has voted for too many close votes till date." The wording implies that José has done wrong because he has voted too many times and that José should cease voting because of this. I personally, would take that offensively.

Comment: @Simply No no no I think you got that wrong. I wrote "...too many vote" in order to indicate that since he has voted for many questions' closure, may be, this slips out, and he doesn't remember voting for this. This is not at all offensive. It is indeed a very light compliment, because voting for closure is something the site needs, and is good to do.

Comment: @KingTut  It's really sad that you deny your rudeness in this case, and distort the time line.  You are quick to lash out at folks, often, as I remember, while not being entirely honest of your hand in your own undoing.  As we see by your comment today to Jaideep, you were yet again trying to manipulate a user (Jaideep in this case) to try to trigger them to reactively come here (in an effort to save their answer) to fight for you.  Why did you not post on meta?  You've clearly spoken up and attacked users before.  Why manipulate a user trying to help you to speak for you?

Comment: @JaideepKhare well, glad to clear that up $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Jaideep, you've not voted enough (up or down, close or reopen).  Please don't blame folks for exercising their rights to weigh in on matters, and no, it is not the case, as one commentor claimed, that  "five users have standards that lie somewhat outside community norms."  Too many folks are hell-bent on gaining rep, contribute nothing in a rational manner to votes, to community moderation, but are quick to turn on those that aren't so "self-interested".

Comment: I do not vote **enough** because I can't. I use my phone to access MSE and ask/answer questions. I don't own a laptop/PC of my own, and therefore, am unable to access close-vote review-queues. I occasionally vote to close from the options given below to the question itself. This doesn't  mean that I don't know how and when to close-vote @amWhy . And, it's not my duty to close vote it's my **right to** close-vote. Though, I still don't understamd that how am I possibly blaming top close-voters

Comment: Yes it is your right to close-vote, and reopen-vote, downvote and upvote.  It is also other users right to do so, so you need to be more respectful of your peers who have the same rights as you do.  Typically, you're setting yourself for disengagement in an issue if you disrespect others, by attacking them, when you insist you are right and they (whoever those that voted in ways you don't like) are wrong.  Your post was written in an argumentative posture, and you never did, ask sincerely, what "their" reasons were.  When you want to have an honest and respectful conversation, let me know.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry if I have disrespected you in any way. But here are my some points 1. I am not insisting that I am right 2. It's not that someone voted in a way **I** didn't like, it's not personal. It's wrong, that's why I posted on meta. 3. Last line of my second comment from the top, I asked you for reason for close-voting, you haven't responded yet.

Comment: That's my point, Jaideep, 2: "It's wrong".  You never gave a reason.  Why should I discuss this with you when from the start you are asserting others are wrong and you are right?  Your last point? this site expects from all askers and answerers to "be nice."  When an asker is rude and offensive, that's wrong, first and foremost.  There is no rule on this site that allows askers to ask a question, and also to be very rude and insulting in doing so.  So even if you think the questions is "okay", the rudeness and insults are not okay.

Comment: @amWhy So if the main-OP isn't being nice, the right thing to do is, flag comments as offensive, or flag for a mod to look into it. Is rudeness of OP the reason for your close-vote? You haven't answered explicitly yet.

Comment: When a user fails to be kind (is only "not being nice"), regarding their question or answer, the site does not require that we accept "oh well, yeah they're rude, andinsulting, but the question is okay", or that we don't vote to close a questions asked in a rather rude manner.  Just because you think a question should be judged apart from the rudeness of an asker or answerer, that's not the way things work here. And it's not the way things "should work".  There are expectations of every user on this site; if one fails to act accordingly, they should be ready to pay the price.

Comment: @amWhy For the reason of it being wrong, is the very reason it stands opened right now - It's not at all off-topic and therefore should be closed. If there are other problems with the post or OP, we have other methods to deal too.

Comment: That is a terrible argument. It was closed by 5 users and then reopened by 2. How does that make the closing in any objective way wrong?

Comment: @Tobias Not that it's opened by 2 only, but it has been viewed 65 times since this meta question was posted, most of them are above 3k (eligible to close-vote), some are mods, some are the very same users who voted to close, and **is still open**, without even a single close-vote.

Comment: @amWhy pitied over me, or the mod "actually" had the knowledge of whether the question should be closed or not, because they have knowledge of this level Mathematics too. I guarantee that it would have remained open.

Comment: You're clearly not here, and never intended to have a discussion here, Jaideep, but merely acted here in bad faith.  How are you related to King Tut, by the way?

Comment: How can a mod "know" that a question should not be closed? How can you have accumulated so much reputation without learning anything about how the site is supposed to function and how the standards are meant to be upheld?

Comment: @amWhy Just giving my opinion every where, and wandering here and there in chatrooms, pretending to be the most ideal and intelligent and correct person on Earth, and...close voting for off-topic, due to rudeness of OP, just out of rage, doesn't make me eligible to accuse other users who seem-to-be-inactive, (though may be, they read Meta posts, and vote up-and-down, instead of commenting). Got my point? And for your second question, he is just a question-poster for me, who asked for help, whom I responded. I don't know who he/she is, where do they live and all nonsense background.

Comment: Please don't keep attacking me here, Jaideep.  Others have commented to you with very important and highly valid points, which I doubt you can answer with any credibility.   Again, you seem to be very well acquainted with King Tut, the asker of the question you answered.  In any case, this will likely be explored.

Comment: @amWhy Look, I have no affection to my (previously) single voted answer, because, a reputation of +25 is a joke in front of ~16.9k. You really think I spent time on posting this question so that my single voted answer doesn't get deleted along with the removal of question? If you think so, let me know you that you're into wrong path. I came here to ask you and others, the reason of close-vote, which is *obviously* wrong to have done(other actions are available for dealing with rudity)

Comment: You might get somewhere if you stopped acting like the original close votes were in some objective way wrong, when you clearly have no argument for this.

Comment: And I repeat, @amWhy I don't know who King Tut is **at all**. Swear to God.

Comment: **Everybody** please slow down. Maybe give the discussion a short break.

Comment: @Tobias Just answer this question of mine : Is the question linked, missing any context details? Is this do-my-homework type of question?

Comment: @JaideepKhare  I am very sorry if you aren't at all related to the account of King Tut.  My apologies in that case.

Comment: @amWhy It's OK. No problem. ^_^

Comment: I confess that I was (a little) rude to the person *Robert Z*. This was triggered (I am not justifying it) by the vote to close as duplicate. I sincerely apologise for this behaviour to @RobertZ.

Comment: @quid I request you to restore or post the whole sequence of events. I can't remember exactly what happened and I cannot see any comments unlike you. Posting things in parts can be very misleading. Thank you.

Comment: @amwhy please don't get personal. I was not manipulating anyone. I was rude to one person called *Robert Z* so I apologised. End of story. If you still wish to publish fictional stories and give wings to your imagination then I think this is not the right platform.

Comment: One question, I think I deleted my rude remarks to Robert some time after he voted, so how could possibly other close voters see it (regarding the comments here which talk of  close voters teaching me manners by closing the question)

Comment: @amWhy Did you see my edit to the post? I think it's better now. BTW, I am open to suggestion for improvisation of the post.

Comment: @Jaideep Khare: I don't see full context in the current version of the post  at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2648960/630  . "My brother gave me this random problem" is not very compelling to me, and the link to math.SE makes the question look like a duplicate at best. What is the motivation of the question? Where did the formula arise? That is the sort of context that is missing, in my opinion.

Comment: @Jaideep Khare: for the updated version of this meta question, I would agree with this comment by Hurkyl: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28039/is-it-ok-to-close-a-question-as-off-topic-if-the-op-is-not-being-nice-to-other-u#comment114542_28040  .   It's also important to keep in mind that the options in the "close" dialog are limited, and the wording is not very good. There is an option to close for a free-form reason that can be filled in, but sometimes editors just select one of the default reasons even if it is not perfectly accurate.

Comment: Jaideep No, it is not an edit, and no it is not better.  It is an entirely different question than you originally asked.  What you should have done is delete this, and posted you "new question" which users are forced to see here now, as a separate question. You've rendered comments and answers a tad confusing, because most of them all refer to your question that you've now replaced.  Hence it is rude to commenters and answerers, and any user that wasted their time on your your question.  Please see my answer for more details.

Comment: This question should be reverted to its Edit 2 version, if only by respect to the two users who posted an answer before the subsequent massive edit.

Comment: I have rolled this back since the edits substantially changed the question to a practically new one, which invalidates all of the existing comments and answers. New questions should be posted in new posts, not by editing previous posts! Including the case when the new question is what was originally meant, but something substantially different was originally posted. To the OP: [here is the source to the post before I rolled it back in case you wish to repost it in a new post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/67c31d2e-4a14-46ee-998c-84ea6afa0855/view-source)

Comment: "Why do even high reputation users do not pay attention on close votes?" Two basic remarks. 1. The title, using the present simple, thus indicating either the repetition of an act or a general truth, is pure slander of any high rep user downvoting anything on the site. 2. The question, pretending to address a general problem, is a farce since, o surprise, the only post linked to, which is obviously the main (the only?) topic of interest to the OP, is a question answered by the OP themselves.

Comment: No you should not delete this yourself, Jaideep, since you claim that you plan to repost your "non-edit" to this question (which has since been rolled back by another user), and in that case, then this should remain for historical reasons relating to the motivation that prompted you to ask that "new" post you plan to ask here.  I will delete my question now, because this was addressing your attempt to render original comments and answers posted here.  Hurkyl has taken care of my concerns addressed in my answer, so it no longer is needed here.

Comment: @amWhy and others, [This is the re-post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28047/421580) with content related to this post.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a rough timeline of events:

February 13th:

- 14.34 asked and answered at 14:41 and 14:44, among other by Jaideep Khare
- 14:46 flagged as dupe (creates auto-comment) by Alex
- 14:48 @Alex Is your mom proud of you now? – King Tut
- 15:35 a mod deleted the comment above (based on a flag).
- 15:56 @Alex - Do you understand english language?
- 18:51 Dupe closed by Robert Z (goldbadge) from queue (see the ticket review report https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/954919 ; there had been one leave open vote at around 16h); this auto-deletes the auto-comment.

February 14th:

- 10:04 Robert Z how is this duplicate?  – King Tut
- 10:23 @RobertZ this ain't a duplicate. Can you please check again. – Jaideep Khare and vote to reopen. [Prompted by a comment of King Tut on answer]
- 10:41 @JaideepKhare What's the difference between the two questions? – Robert Z (self-deleted at 10:46)
- 10:48 @JaideepKhare I see the point now... – Robert Z and vote to reopen (goldbadge)

February 15th:

- 17:55 vote to close 'off-topic, missing context' by amWhy
- Review 3 close, 3 leave open, see https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/956077

February 16th:

- 14:35 self-delete of King Tut's comments.
- 16:54 mod delete of other comments (based on flags)

February 17th:

- 02:42 final vote to close.

Long break.

March 6th:

- 17:30 King Tut signals the closer on Jaideep's answer: Jaideep look they again closed this question  – King Tut
- 18:05 Jaideep acknowledges the request: @King They are gonna regret this. I'll take this to meta ASAP. – Jaideep Khare

March 10th:

- 14:00 and the minutes afterwards, this meta question by Jaideep, self-delete of the March 6th comment, plus comment notifying King Tut about the meta post.

Since this was point of discussion. During all close votes but the last off-topîc vote one of the rude comments was present. (Here 'all' refers to those being  the subject of discussion not those that occurred now.)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me was the comment about english language deleted that day or when was it deleted

Comment: @KingTut This is rather fascinating, in a way: first, you stick to a narrative, rather adamantly, then, when said narrative is exploded by **facts** provided by a mod (who had to take on their time to collect them), you instantly turn to a new narrative, also destined to switch the topic of the conversation from **your acts** to whatever you hope will allow to put them under the rug? Wow.

Comment: @Did All I can say is that my memory is not good. You see, had had he put this earlier, all fuss could have been avoided. Thanks.

Comment: @did no I didn't turn to a new narrative, yesterday I asked quid to restore it and I am thankful to him. So this suspicion started building up since then. You see I asked him/her to restore because I didn't even remember anything. See **this meta questiin is not created by me and not did I plan to anything of that sort**, I didn't even remember bad comments were written for **Alex** and not **Robert**!

Comment: @KingTut as indicated in the timeline you self-deleted that comment on the 16th around 14h. Here are the exact details "@Alex - Do you understand english language? – King Tut Feb 13 at 15:56 deleted by King Tut **Feb 16 at 14:35**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: My memory is not very good then. I said whatever I remembered.

Comment: @KingTut "You see, had had he put this earlier, all fuss could have been avoided" Sorry, but **have you no shame?**

Comment: @KingTut, initially quid tried to spare you from "outing" the exact nature of your conduct (what you said exactly), and summarized with a description of "rude comments".  You challenged it, so in a comment below their post, they responded to your denial/challenge by writing exactly what those rude comments were.  Now you're asserting that "You see, had had (sic) [quid] put this earlier, all fuss could have been avoided."  So you blame this "fuss" on quid, who initially tried to help you save face?  Again, Did's last comment is entirely spot on.

Comment: @amwhy fuss was unknowingly created by me, not him/her. My face is perfectly alright btw, remarkably, despite extensive mudslinging from your side.

Comment: "They are going to regret this"? Jesus F. Christ.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "F." indeed.

Comment: @Asad and did: I did not say that btw.

Comment: @KingTut: (1) Who is "Asad"? (2) Did anyone claim that *you* said that? Please don't insult my reading skills. (3) "The lady doth protest too much, methinks".

Comment: @asaf sorry it's a typo, since d and f are neighbors on keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

Before addressing the question itself, I must say the way you phrase your question seems adversarial and unwilling to debate. Specifically, your explicit question is:

> Can't we do anything and take a strict action to avoid this scenario
>   in future?

Avoid what? The fact that users closed a question? Why? This could only be because you think they *wrongly* closed a question, and thus it would be civil to let them have a voice before. You left little space for that. The title suffers from a similar problem. The appropriate question, hidden behind your post, is: "Why was this question closed? I believe it was unjustly closed, (and here is why). Do you agree? Why/why not?", or something of the sort.

I disagree with the other answer that was given, which is why I am giving this one. I believe that the major reason (in that it is the decisive factor)  to why the question was closed was due to disruptiveness of (main) OP. There is not a rule I'm aware of which formally allows a question to be closed under that basis. However, the circumstances are extraneous: (main) OP was blatantly rude. quid mentions some examples [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28039/why-do-even-high-reputation-users-do-not-pay-attention-on-close-votes/28040?noredirect=1#comment114464_28039). There is a rule of thumb for the site in general which I hold with greater value than close-vote reasons, which I think the site as an entity does so as well since it is number 2 in the "Our model" page (preceded only by the overwhelmingly important technicality of how to format mathematics), which is: [Be nice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

I think the question is clear enough. I think voting to close may have been an honest attempt from the close-voters to keep the site sanitized from disruptiveness, seeing that this was the only thing that they directly had power to do in order to "contain" a disruptive user. This may be effective and well-intentioned, but I honestly don't know if this is appropriate or not. It seems a straight-from-the-book "the ends justify the means" kind of argument. However, if there were no other means to deal with this, I think I would end up agreeing with closing.

My take on the issue, after some thought, is: I disagree with the closure of the question, since I believe there are more appropriate ways to handle this. I believe that it is the job of moderators to sanitize the site of rude content, so I think the appropriate action would be to flag those comments and leave it be (maybe comment something to add to the voices trying to make sense out of the person, but that would be inviting yourself to headaches). Then, it would be left to them what to be done about the whole situation, question and all (I would consider suspension a fair treatment in this case, for example).

PS: If any of the close-voters disagree with what I said was the major reason for the votes, feel free to point it out.

Comment: I want to add that I too didn't know about the rude comments by OP at the time of posting meta-question. Those were deleted either quickly or I came later, or I didn't see the comments after answering. I understand that rude behavior isn't acceptable at all in this community, but close-voting isn't the correct way to do so IMHO. Since, I being unaware of rude comments , was really kind of annoyed when I saw that the question is closed, without any comment indicating the reason of closure rom those 5 close-voters, I thought to take it to meta.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Sorry for assuming you did know about the comments. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Did you see my edit to the post? Does it seem better? I am open to suggestions for improv ing the question.

Comment: Nor is there a rule that I'm  aware of that formally prohibits a question to be closed under the basis that an asker has behaved badly (insultive, rude).  The number one item of the SE Model is "Be nice."  There's  no place on the SE network for rude comments, insulting and offensive comments, and the like.

Comment: @amWhy Fair point. But there are specific guidelines for closing a question, and the asker behaving badly is not one of them. I don't want rude askers, as you can see from my answer and behaviour in general. But I want clarity and consistency, in part precisely not to give rude people an argument that they can use. As I said in a comment, if we want to close questions because of that, that is a decision we can make as a community. But let's be explicit about it (just like we are regarding homework-esque question).

Comment: Besides, what problem do you see in flagging the comment and leaving this to the moderators, as I suggest?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I agree that rude users should usually be flagged and left to the moderators. In egregious cases, I have voted to close questions purely because the asker was being extremely rude (and without seeing the comments, I don't have any idea whether this rises to that level). However, I would never vote to close such a question as missing-context, because it's not; I would use a custom close reason with an auto-generated comment.

Comment: @user296602 That seems sensible to me, too (closing with a custom reason).

Comment: So KingTut and Jaideep should be spared from their misdeeds/misrepresentations/, lack of memory, faulty memory, but we should verbally whip a user whose only mistake might be to have chosen the wrong reason to vote to close?  How selective folks are to how should be called out, and who should be spared doing so, because, oh, misrepresentations, rudeness, all that from only some folks is considered only human?  Quite the double standard going on this site, methinks.

Comment: How is flagging a comment (with me explicitly saying that suspension might be appropriate) sparing anyone? The fact that someone should be punished doesn't mean that they should be punished by you, and even less using ways of "punishment" (quotes because  I don't think closing is punishment) which were not devised for the "crime".

Comment: And I can't understand how you interpret this answer as being double standards towards favoring KingTut/Jaideep. I explicitly say that one of them should be suspended, and that the meta post of the other is troubling, while saying that your actions may have been an honest attempt to sanitize the site (although through the wrong means). How can someone *possibly* interpret this as you said is beyond me. If anything, I would expect the exactly opposite accusation, which would be equally wrong, but at least would be more sensible.

Comment: It's not a problem for you do disagree.  The problem is judging others who disagree with you, and building a straw man argument against them.  I never used the words punishment, nor crime. You used them with scare-quotes, so I do not think it is relevant to my comment here, nor do I downvote a post to "punish" a user.  So please don't put words in *my* mouth.  Please, I know we disagree.  Please, let's just agree to disagree. Cheers!

Comment: I am not putting words in your mouth. You explictly say "There are expectations of every user on this site; if one fails to act accordingly, *they should be ready to pay the price*" (emphasis mine). Am I incorrect in treating this as punishment for wrongdoing?

Answer (score 4):

The question is presented not as clear as it should be presented. This lead to considerable confusion and an unnecessary duplicate close-reopen.

Instead of clarifying the question via an edit or explaining the issue main-OP  wrote rude comments (that got deleted); meta-OP was not rude but not overly helpful either.

The question is still not as clear as it could be. Maybe it is not bad enough for it to be closed, but it is far from good. *And* the main-OP had been made aware of the problem but chose to do nothing about it, except for writing rude comments.

Comment: Does OP means to be me, or the Original Poster of the linked question?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify this; sorry for the confusion. I meant the poster in main. You were not rude in any way. But you still could have been more helpful.

Comment: Just edited the post to indicate the last use "OP" was referring to the main MSE OP of the question that is linked to in this meta question.

Comment: What is unclear about the question? He is not realizing that it is possible that a solution to that equation does not exist, and that this is exactly what he is indirectly proving, coupled with a common confusion between implication and biconditional. It may be a "low quality" question by some standards, but I really don't understand what is unclear.

Comment: And if the glaring problem is that it is unclear, then this doesn't justify it being closed for being off-topic.

Comment: You may as well add my name beside op to make things crystal clear

Comment: @AloizioMacedo one thing that is not clear is that the link leads to questions on this site that solves the almost same but not quite identical question obtaining the same solution that OP believes to have found. If one follows the link one can find this out but this should not be necessary. Thus it is poorly presented. The solutions is also poorly written. The third line in the displayed appeared in an unmotivated way, making it harder to see what OP is doing. In brief, the entire post is written in a terribly convoluted way. It could have half the length and be more clearer.

Comment: Either way, two users, one of them a gold-badged holder in the relevant tag thought it was a duplicated of the question linked to in the post. Even after being prompted to do so, it took this gold-badge holder two attempts to realize that the questions are actually not dupes. That's just not a clearly presented question. Yes, it is comprehensible (with effort), but that's not the same as it being clear. Unclear is not the same as incomprehensible.  Re the link: I only realized on my third visit to the post that the link in OP went to the supposed duplicate.

Comment: Moreover, the comments by OP where excessively unhelpful. All this likely would have been avoided if only OP had answered in a moderately reasonably way to the comments they received. There is a huge share of the problem on OP's side.  @AloizioMacedo

Comment: The rude comments can indicate childish behaviour of OP, but do not relate to judgement of the question. With respect to your points, I think you are exaggerating the issue. For example: "the entire argument post is written in a terribly convoluted way". This way of writing is pretty common among 'new' students of mathematics. It is bad (not terribly convoluted, imo), but rather understandable. For example, the third line being displayed in an unmotivated way would be simply solved by a mere "If we compute the integral, we have (...)". Similar observations hold for your other complaints.

Comment: @KingTut your comment shows that you have a hard time to discern what is relevant. It is not relevant that King Tut wrote the comment. It is relevant that it was the user that posted the question on main. That this was King Tut will not be known to most readers. Thus to say King Tut would be unclear.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo again the question was initially voted to close as **a duplicate.** The post was misunderstood. Why would OP not address the confusion but instead insult the confused other user?

Comment: To be clear, the main problem is not that there were rude comments but that OP refused to clarify the question even when it is *empirically established* that it is prone to be misunderstood. This is one of the things I often find annoying in these discussions. The lack of consideration for those that misunderstood something that maybe they also could have understood.

Comment: My point is: comments pointing out that the question could be improved are reasonable. Saying that the question is unclear and terribly convoluted is an exaggeration, and also incoherent with the close-reason(s) of the question.  And the initial vote as duplicate (which I also disagree with, but find it more understandable) is not the matter of discussion of this meta post. It may be relevant if you intend to use as an argument that *because it was misunderstood, it is unclear*, an argument which I don't agree with.

Comment: I understand that a bad question with OP being irresponsive to improve it can be hard to handle. But, by itself, ignoring comments and all, the question stands "clear enough" for me (although... bad). But, considering the fact that OP is actively refusing to improve the question, I honestly don't know what is the proper course of action. But I don't believe that closing the question as off-topic is the best one.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo the "terribly convoluted" is to be seen in opposition to the assertion that we are discussing a "great question." There is some hyperbole to this for rhetorical effect. Please note what I wrote in my answer post on the subject. "Maybe it is not bad enough for it to be closed, but it is far from good" which is quite close to 'stands "clear enough" for me (although... bad)'.  Indeed, the argument I am making is that  "because it was misunderstood, it is unclear." My working definition of unclear here is "susceptible to be misunderstood by competent readers" what is yours?

Comment: I don't have an explicit definition, but I think yours is good. However, I don't think that "being misunderstood by <10 competent readers" implies "susceptible to be misunderstood by competent readers", and neither that "being closed for being off-topic" implies the question is unclear, which is also a specific close reason for closing if that were the case.

Comment: Not only that, but the way I see it (correct me if I am wrong), the only people for whom we have evidence that misunderstood the question are you (and I think you understood, but think it could be improved) and the closer for being duplicate (I believe it was a sole gold medal), which could have just seen the similarity of the titles for that assessment. I don't think that the people who voted to close for being *off-topic* count as evidence, so I don't agree with your assertion that it was *empirically established* to be unclear.

Comment: With those things in mind, I can't shake off the feeling that the closure was most likely (maybe unconscious) retaliation for rudeness and unresponsiveness. While I agree that there should be some sort of response to that, I don't think this is the best one.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo no there were two dupe votes. The goldbage user then was asked by meta-OP to reconsider. They first replied that they do not see how it's not a dupe to then several minutes later say that they now see it and proceded to reopen. As for me, I thought the link went to another site where the problem was taken from. A key point: main-OP was active between the first dupe vote and the goldbadge vote. They insulted the first voter, twice several hours appart. But did say nothing to clarify why it is not a dupe. Only later it was closed as dupe by the goldbadge.

Comment: @quid Thanks for clarifying (off-topic: is there any way that I could see that info? When I click the link by pjs36, it only gives one gold badge in the revision history responsible for closing, but two for reopening). I also thought the link went to another site, but I think that is rather irrelevant to classifying the question as unclear. Still, that leaves 3 (arguably 2, if we take you out) who categorically misunderstood the question (and maybe due to a rapid reading of the title, as I said. This is conjectural but pertinent). So I still think your claim is too strong.

Comment: Aloizio  Do you have an on-topic point to make?  Finally?

Comment: If you are being sarcastic, this answer thinks that the amalgamation of being an unclear question+unresponsiveness from the OP in main is the reason for it being closed. I disagree, and spent ~10 comments explaining **directly** why I disagree. Can you point out what comment, exactly, is off-topic? Suggesting that I (and quid, indirectly) am wasting my time with such a petty comment is rather rude and childish, and brings absolutely nothing to the discussion. If you are not being sarcastic, I sincerely don't understand the purpose of the comment.

Comment: Then maybe you're finely done?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo two dupe votes was not exact, sorry. The first was a flag, which generates the same comment and since **now** that user has around 4500 I assumed it was a voted. (But then they had not.) There is no direct way (maybe even no way) how you could have now found  about the flag.

Comment: @amWhy  If *you have an on-topic point to make* and are willing to, I'll be glad to discuss this with you. If you are not willing to for whatever reason (you think I won't understand/you think this is not worth it/you don't like me etc), that is fine. But if the only thing you want to do is keep with these pointless and mindless retorts, please consider the irony of your attitude with respect to what you were accusing me of. I won't respond anymore, if you follow this last path.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: While closing questions that shouldn't be closed out of retaliation is wrong, you should keep in mind that questions often fall into a grey area where both leaving open and voting to close are reasonable actions. Reader who habitually prefer to overlook the problems that posts have and leave them open can easily be persuaded to change their minds by an offensive poster.

Comment: @Hurkyl I agree. This is not what I am contesting. I am contesting the fact that this answer claims that **being unclear** is the reason, coupled with unreasonableness, for the question to have been closed, which is essentially what the meta question wants to know. That a question which was explicitly closed as off-topic is being said to have been closed as it did because it is unclear is something I can't understand. If this answer claimed that the question was closed because it was bad and the user was unresponsive, that would a little vague but more accurate imo.

Comment: And that which I just mentioned is a factual evidence that it was not closed because it was unclear, in contrast to what quid presents as factual evidence (which, as I argued, I think is not at all sufficient). But also from a subjective point of view I can't understand what is unclear in the question. The points raised by quid tell me that it is badly written, not unclear. If we want to close questions because an asker is disruptive and not willing to cooperate, that is fine. But I think we should be precise as to why, exactly, we are doing so, and I think this answer fails to do that.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo generally, "off-topic, missing context" is a near synonym of "unclear." On other sites they routinely close PSQs as "unclear." (This is not to say this here is a PSQ just to get the idea across.) Both are basically saying that the question is not presented sufficiently well.

Comment: In view of your second comment, indeed, the main reason we even have that off-topic reason to begin with is that on this site (in contrast to other sites) some insist that unclear ought to mean incomprehensible. But this is just not true. There are various points in the question that are not explained well. The subject is not clearly presented, viz it is unclear (while arguably not incomprehensible).

Comment: Please give a comprehensive list of expression which offend people here. I am not sarcastic here I really need a guide.

Comment: @KingTut stick to providing factual information. There is no need to be chatty to begin with.

Comment: @quid I think your point of view makes me understand what you meant better. I don't think unclear ought to mean incomprehensible. I think "unclear what you are asking" ought to mean that I can't discern the question that you have, and I don't see how this is a near synonym of "off-topic, missing context". I understand there is a correlation, but that's about it. E.g., I recently voted to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674549/tensor-products-universal-property-and-a-particular-identification) as being unclear. It definitely was not off-topic/missing context.

Comment: I think it is relevant to point out that two out of the five close voters of the closure in this discussion said something about their reasons in the comments: none of them about the question being unclear in any way (not a single mention). One of them admitted implicitly to not having payed proper attention to the question (and also that being a PSQ or not would be a more relevant factor), and the other was quite explicit in that rudeness was the main factor of his close reason. Whether this should be encouraged or not is debatable, but it surely points to my objection being pertinent.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo synonym was not the best word, it's more a special case (or a syn in the SE sense). It should also be recalled that it says "missing context or other details" and a description of the link target and why it is not a dupe are such missing details. On the rest, I am a moderator not a mind-reader. I never pretended to know what the voters thought. I answered this question as it essentially was a call for "strict action"  to avoid "wrong" closures. So, I explained why there is, in my opinion, no reason for any actions against this closure as it is justifiable.

Comment: @quid I also disagree with it being a special case (my example proves that o-t is not a special case of unclear, and PSQ's prove that unclear is not a special case of o-t). I understand that your intention was not to guess (although, I feel that saying that this is mind-reading is a little facetious in face of the situation, which has a lot of context) why it was closed, but this meta post is clearly intended to put the reason to why it was closed under investigation. Almost any 'newbie' question can be put under sufficient scrutiny as to justify closure. This misses the point, I think.

Comment: The point being that such 'sufficient' scrutiny would not be applied if the user had not been disruptive, which is essentially what Hurkyl is saying, if I understood it correctly. And the question is: is applying different scrutiny to a question, based on rudeness on comments, correct? Why is closing more appropriate than my suggestion of flagging, for instance? The user should undoubtedly be penalized in some way. But not in *any* way. Instead, in an appropriate way. Conflating punishments is a bad step to take, imho.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo what example are you talking about? The one you mentioned is IYO unclear yet not off-topic, missing context. How can this show that "off-topic, missing context" is not a special case of unclear? And what about PSQs? As I told you they are closed on other sites as "unclear" and here as "off-topic, missing context." On the mind-reading. First, note the alliteration. Second, José said they do not know why they voted to close and do not even recall they did so. But somehow I should magically know their motivation.

Comment: I screwed up the ordering. I intended to mean that my example shows a case where the post is (IMO, yes) unclear but not off-topic/missing context, and PSQs frequently show examples where posts are off-topic/missing context but not unclear. I mentioned PSQs, but I could also search for other examples. Being PSQ is not relevant here: the relevance is in asserting that those things are semantically quite dinstict, despite how other sites may use them practically, and that there are plenty of examples where one can verify this.

Comment: And, as I said, I don't think that we should attempt to or should guess/magically know anything. If you are under that impression, I am sorry. I understand that this post and its offsprings may be overwhelming to deal with (don't think that I didn't see you having to address lack of etiquette in the midst of this discussion and elsewhere. It is just that I, not being a moderator, have the privilege of being able to ignore it when it is not directed to me, and I prefer to do so for the preservation of my mental health.)

Comment: But, instead of being a non-attempt at guessing/magically knowing, I think that you answer dismisses the attempt of investigating the real reasons for closure in view of the context that we have. And, if I am correct about the reasons (which, honestly, is not about guessing but really about context), there is a *very* important issue at hand. Again, conflating punishments is a bad step to take.

Comment: You can very well brush aside my inquiry, saying that there is no way to adamantly, certainly and without a single doubt guarantee that the reason for closure is so and so. This is all very true, but all very dismissive of a possibility of a severe problem with respect to judgements. Even if only a possibility and not applicable in this case, this (again, conflating punishments for different 'crimes', sorry for being repetitive) should at least be given the proper attention (imo, be explicitly frowned upon). You gave none in your answer.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo no they are not quite distinct. Please read the **full** "unclear" reason. It also asks for more details. This is the crucial point, and this is near-identical. But, of course there are nuances, if not we would not have the other reason. Either way, the current question could be closed both as "unclear" and "missing context." The point you raise is valid. If you want to discuss it, start such a discussion. It's a subtle problem. It is of course not allowed to start closing questions out of spite.

Comment: It is however consensus that, say, new users  could be treated in a more charitable way than regular users. Thus, the principle that not all questions are treated completely equally is widely accepted. And so that it is not forgotten, OP was not only rude but unresponsive. Do you see a problem with taking whether a user is responsive or not into account @AloizioMacedo?

Comment: On more point @AloizioMacedo: "I think that you answer dismisses the attempt of investigating the real reasons for closure in view of the context that we have." I stressed that they were rude comments, which can be taken as implying that this possibly did play a role. To sum it up: the question is not all that good, in addition OP was unhelpful and rude, so it got closed. I do not see the merit in trying to gauge to what exact extent it was the quality of the Q and to what it was the rudeness, or maybe the unresponsiveness. As you agree, it's not that good a Q.

Comment: The full "unclear" reason reads as "additional details **to highlight exactly what you need**", concluding with "As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.". In my understanding, the additionals detail are clearly meant to improve the discerning of the question, not for being (directly, recall that I say that there is indeed a correlation) contextualization. We could just as well put "add aditional details" in the "too broad" close reason, followed with "so your question becomes more specific", and this wouldn't make it near-identical to the rest.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo This is pretty much the same (only broader) as: "Please improve the question by providing additional context, [...] This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the existence of such principle. But these are distinct situations. On one of them, the "proper" course of action would be to close the question, but we give the OP chance to learn how the platform works, at least in a basic level. So, in this situation, we are withholding **proper** course of action. In the other (the one under discussion in this meta post), we are applying **improper** course of action (if, indeed, the reasons are as I said). These are very distinct things,  it is not only a matter of treating questions differently.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo there is nothing improper about closing this question.

Comment: (Answering the "one more point"): I think that what you are saying can be then interpreted to mean that your answer have explained why it was closed, in a formal sense of causality. It doesn't address if this is proper behaviour or not, which is relevant.

Comment: (Answering the last comment): I think it is improper to close a question for a reason which is not valid to close a question for, objectively speaking (that is why I said "if, indeed, the reasons are as I said"). Please, note that this can be quite similar to the "downvote without reason" case, where we can't effectively know that a downvote was done due to retalliation or some other nonsensical reason. This doesn't mean that it is right to do so, and I believe this behaviour should be properly, explicitly and thoroughly addressed.

Comment: However, even worse than in the "downvote without reason case", where there are few guidelines and explanations to why an answer/question should be upvoted/downvoted and it is more relegated to personal reasons, there are explicit guidelines to why a question should be closed. Stomping over them is what I am saying is improper.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo "there are explicit guidelines to why a question should be closed" Indeed. And according to these guidelines it is alright to close this question. This is the point.  "Stomping over them is what I am saying is improper." As said, I am not sure anything was stomped over.  Yes. in a way it is not great to learn there is a user that cannot recall that they closed a question. But then they contribute a lot and the volume is high, and we are discussing something that happened almost a month ago.I am not sure what you expect me to do. Maybe they had a valid reason then but forgot now.

Comment: Tangentially please note Carl Mummert's comment for a user that agrees that closing as ot,mc is the proper action.

Comment: I think you are taking the guidelines binarily. It is not an issue of good/bad, I think there is no such thing. It is an issue of "good enough/bad enough" (which is in the same spirit of Hurkyl's comment about the grey area). That these thresholds can change accordingly to behaviour that is unrelated to them is, in a way, stomping over the guidelines. More accurately, it is stomping over the independence that such criteria (as they are phrased) have with respect to behaviour.

Comment: Carl Mummert's argument seems to point that it is "bad enough", independently from rudeness. I disagree strongly. Of course, my opinion, but I think I would be able to gather enough evidence from a quick look at the main site for (recent) questions to show that this is inconsistent with what the community empirically feels is bad enough, rudeness aside.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Is it alright to first leave a comment to ask for clarification and some time later if it is not given vote to close? Or *must* I vote right away to avoid that my vote depends on the *behavior* of OP.

Comment: The *decision* of whether to cast a vote or not can depend on the behaviour of OP if your vote, by itself, is proper. That meaning: if someone voted to close this question because it was unclear in their eyes (*independently* of behaviour of OP), that is completely ok. The *reason* of your vote depending on the behaviour of OP is improper. To put it simply: decision of voting can be behavioural-dependent, simply because you can't force someone to act. The reason for such a vote, I don't think so, because things must be consistent and very carefully delimited.

Comment: Unless, of course, as I told amWhy under my answer, we collectively agree that it is OK to do so.

Comment: To illustrate the concept on this case: if those 5 voters thought the question was missing context, but were waiting for a response and got rudeness instead, I see no problem. This is quite a different situation from the voters seeing the rudeness and voting to close because of it.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo but we'd need mind-readers not moderators! If I want to control and enforce what you propose I *must* know what the voters *thought* when they cast their vote. This is not possible. The best I can do is see if it seems plausible to me that voters have thought that the question is unclear. For the current question, this is the case. Thus, it passes my supervision of the community-moderation process.

Comment: You are correct. If you want to control and enforce this in every possible case, you would have to be a mind-reader. However, you can disencourage this behaviour, or at least recognize its possibility/plausibility, particularly due to the context of this whole situation and also comments suggesting strongly that this was the case. The fact that it simply wasn't mentioned at all is what worries me, given the ethical implications it can have. Not being able to control/enforce is not reason enough to ignore.

Comment: @aloizio and quid and others: Are you guys ignoring me? You are missing a major issue. I write under meta question here: *One question, I think I (or someone else maybe) deleted my rude remarks to Robert some time after he voted, so how could possibly other close voters see it*. Do you see? Question was closed on Feb 13 reopened on 14. Comments were gone possibly by then (I asked quid to post the full sequence of events).**And** it is closed on **Feb 17** again. I think rude comments is just a pretext to cover. how can they see deleted comments? Or can they? Refer revision link by pjs36.

Comment: @KingTut I don't think that it is consistent with other comments on this (meta) post that your comments (on main) were not available to be seen for the voters of the closure under question here. If this is true, this changes the context of this question dramatically (yet again). However, "pretext to cover" what? If rude comments were unavailable to be seen, then this would imply that there was effectively nothing morally worthy of questioning. At most, a lack of judgement or disagreement on what is unclear/off-topic. But this whole situation would be perhaps much simpler (certainly different).

Comment: @KingTut see the timeline.

Comment: @Aloizio only after quid chose to say about rude comments that got deleted, the whole narrative of this situation changed. He said he can restore the whole timeline but didnt. I again request quid to restore the timeline. I am pretty sure the comments were gone atleast by 14 or 15.

Comment: @KingTut why do you say you are pretty sure they were gone at a time when the timeline was up that said explicitly that they were not deleted by 14th or 15th. (This info is also in the first revision.)

Comment: @quid earlier you hadn't  put the timeline, and I am on mobile, so I recalled whatever I could about the date. But after putting this comment, I immediately saw that you already had put timeline just minutes ago..

Comment: @KingTut that's  a bit surprising since your comment is right below the one where I pinged you to tell you that I posted the timeline.

Comment: @quid yes true but exactly that happened. My mobile phone is small screen maybe that's why. Half screen is occupied by keyboard, and other parts were mostly occupied by the big text box full of message.