# Editing for On hold-question

Tags: discussion

On hold question is between open and closed. So if we add a suitble editing, then it can be reopen. If not, it may be closed in five days.

Here I have a question : Other people can edit ? In site system (not rule, just machine), it seems that it is possible. Usually, on hold question contains small material. That is, here editing means adding material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that anyone who has accumulated enough points to edit posts can edit questions that are on hold. But usually what's missing from an on-hold question is something that can only be supplied by the person who posted the question.

Comment: "accumulated enough points" means 20000 points. If one get 20000 points, then he has a previlege including "expanded editing". Am I right ?

Comment: what can be done except editing a question    that is "on hold"? or what can happen after the edit of such Q. has been made?

Comment: @Jne, if the post is edited to the satisfaction of enough people, those people will vote to reopen it, and all will live happily ever after. An alternative to editing is to post here, to meta, to try to explain why the post should not have been closed – there is a special thread here on meta, devoted to requests for reopening and/or undeleting. Another option is to go to the CRUDE chatroom, and plead for reopening there. And, HK, I don't think it takes 20000 points to edit other people's questions. Somewhere on site there's a list of privileges, and how many points each one requires.

Comment: Yes, it's only 2000 points to edit. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: do you just post it on meta or there's a special tag for it or something like that?

Comment: @Jne, as I wrote, there's a special thread devoted to asking for reopening/undeleting. I'll try to find it for you (though I bet you could find it for yourself, if you gave it a try).

Comment: @Jne, here it is: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio But do read what's there before you post anything to it.